# How to pass composite function list to SortBy?

Tags: functions, sorting

In order to sort alphanumeric-as-string data of the form `{"T3", "T14", "T1", "E2"}`, so that `"T14"` comes after `"T3"`, `SortBy` requires the tiebreaker function list:

```
{StringTake[#, 1] &, ToExpression@StringDrop[#, 1] &}
```

Which works as intended when this expression is inserted literally in `SortBy`. However, defining a utility function

`mySort[x_String]:={StringTake[x, 1] , ToExpression@StringDrop[x, 1]}`

doesn't work since the output is a list of expressions rather than a list of functions.

The alternative - to define a function via

```
mySort := {StringTake[#, 1] &, ToExpression@StringDrop[#, 1] &}
```

only works when the list to be sorted is 1-dimensional (as above) but not with lists of the form `data2={"T3"->a, "T14"->b, "T1"->c, "E2"->d}` where it is necessary to use `SortBy[data2,mySort[#[[1]]]&]`.

Any alternatives that will work for general expressions?

Comment: I edited the previous typo, but it results in "T14" before "T3". Do you have the opposite?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Forget my previous comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this question admits an elegant solution. Here is my attempt: define a special wrapper:

```
ClearAll[sortFun];
sortFun /: SortBy[expr_, sortFun[funs_List, partFun_]] :=
   SortBy[expr, Map[Composition[#, partFun] &, funs]];
```

Now,

```
mySort := {StringTake[#, 1] &, ToExpression@StringDrop[#, 1] &}
```

and

```
SortBy[{"T3","T14","T1","E2"}, sortFun[mySort, Identity]]

(*   {E2,T1,T3,T14}  *)
```

while

```
SortBy[{"T3"->a,"T14"->b,"T1"->c,"E2"->d}, sortFun[mySort, First]]

(*  {E2->d,T1->c,T3->a,T14->b} *)
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps more elegantly

```
ClearAll[sortFun];
sortFun /: SortBy[expr_, sortFun[funs_List, partFun_]] :=
   SortBy[expr, Thread[Composition[funs, partFun]]];
```

and just for fun, another version:

```
ClearAll[sortFun];
sortFun /: call : SortBy[expr_, sortFun[funs_List, partFun_]] :=
   Block[{sortFun = Thread[Composition[##]] &}, call];
```

Comment: Superior to mine, +1

Comment: @Rojo Thanks :) We seem to be thinking very similarly :)

Comment: @Leonid, you're a wizard, but I would not call this solution elegant despite your elegant code. Who wants to pass around sortFun and all that. This is something WRI should tackle.

Comment: @alancalvitti I actually don't find carrying `sortFun` around a big burden. It is a very general wrapper, and it minimally changes the syntax. One can use some shorter name if `sortFun` is too long. One could also add rules to `SortBy`, but I'd rather not do it.

Comment: sortFun[mySort, Identity] and sortFun[mySort, First] burn/spill highly important syntactic sugar. If the 1st can be somehow massaged into just sortFun, and the 2nd into sortFun[[1]], that would be elegant...But I'll accept your answer & +1 it.

Comment: @alancalvitti Thanks for the accept. As for elegance, it seems that we have somewhat different perceptions on that (which is just fine, this is a very subjective matter). I feel that the first solution in the edit is the  most elegant, and will be hard-pressed to see anything simpler than that.

Comment: Simpler from the user perspective is related to usability. Can you imagine an implementation of SortBy that recognizes List of Functions and maps Parts to Slot accordingly? Perhaps that's what you meant by the Rule approach.

Comment: @alancalvitti This will then be either a more narrow, point solution (since functions can also be represented as symbols, composite heads with sub-values, etc), or will be really complex and would require compile stage to be efficient. I do not exclude that this is possible, but I think that my solution captures the mathematical essence of the problem, which is, function's composition. And when possible, I value mathematical clarity over what may look like a better usability, because a real usability is in supporting the right abstractions.

Comment: There's no question that you've solved the mathematical essence of the problem. But the solution does not preserve the transparent syntax SortBy displays for simple (ie, no tiebreaker) sort functions - that's all I meant by my earlier comments. Why don't we use assembly language or R? They're Turing complete, so they all capture the mathematics.

Comment: Quite nice! ${}$

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I used the opportunity to use `Composition` in a place where it seems natural (which is what you also suggested in that comment).