# Unexpected result {".a", "co", ".m"} from Sort[{".m", ".a", "co"}]

Tags: string-manipulation, sorting

I came across the following situation:

Evaluating

```
Sort[{".m", ".a", "co"}]
```

Results in

```
{".a", "co", ".m"}
```

I wondering: What was the criterion that *Mathematica* use to output this? According to the documentation:

> ...Sort orders strings as in a dictionary, with uppercase...

After reading this, I expect a dictionary sort like this:

```
{".a", ".m", "co"}
```

Or

```
{"co", ".a", ".m"}
```

Can anyone explain me what was the criterion used by *Mathematica* to perform this sort?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As noted in the popup for that tag, please do not add [tag:bugs] until what you say has been verified by other people.

Comment: @PedroR What do you mean by the ""Pythonic" way to workaround the translation"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/Misc/Chicago/CHIIndexingComplete.pdf), para. 18.57/18.58, punctation marks are ignored.

> **18.57**
>
> *The letter-by-letter system.* In the letter-by-letter system, alphabetizing continues up to the first parenthesis or comma; it
>   then starts again after the punctuation point. Word spaces and all
>   other punctuation marks are ignored. Both open and hyphenated
>   compounds such as New York or self-pity are treated as single words.
>   The order of precedence is one word, word followed by a parenthesis,
>   and word followed by a comma, number, or letters. The index to this
>   manual, in accordance with Chicago’s traditional preference, is
>   arranged letter by letter.

I won't say it's a definitive answer, but it supports Mathematica's behavior to a certain extent.

Answer (score 7):

> Sort orders strings as in a dictionary, with uppercase versions of letters coming after lowercase ones.Sort places ordinary letters first, followed in order by script, Gothic, double - struck, Greek, and Hebrew.Mathematical operators appear in order of decreasing precedence.
>
> Sort[list, p] applies the function p to pairs of elements in list to determine whether they are in order.The default function p is OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &.
>
> OrderedQ[h[Subscript[e, 1], Subscript[e, 2], [Ellipsis]]] gives True if the Subscript[e, i] are in canonical order, and False otherwise.

## Some Test

---

### Just one `Sort` without function

---

Let' s see the CharacterCode of sampleList1

1. ```
   (*Input 1 ==< *)
   sampleList1 = {compute, Tes, ., , Etz, .a, .m, a, z, T, .T, wha, {}; 
   ToCharacterCode[sampleList1]
   ```
2. ```
   (*
   Output 1 ==>
   {{99,111,109,112,117,116,101},{84,101,115},{46},{},{69,116,122},{46,97},{46,109},{97},{122  
   },{84},{46,84},{119,104,97},{123}}
   *)
   ```
3. ```
   (*Input 2 ==< *)
   Sort[sampleList1]
   ```
4. ```
   (*
   Output 2 ==>
   {,{,.,.a,a,compute,Etz,.m,.T,T,Tes,wha,z}
   *)
   ```
5. ```
   (*Input 3 ==< *)
   ToCharacterCode[%]
   ```
6. ```
   (*
   Output 3 ==>
   {{},{123},{46},{46,97},{97},{99,111,109,112,117,116,101},{69,116,122},{46,109},{46,84},{84  
   },{84,101,115},{119,104,97},{122}}
   *)
   ```
7. ```
   (*Input 4 ==< *)
   Total /@ %
   ```
8. ```
   (*
   Output 4 ==>
   {0,123,46,143,97,765,307,155,130,84,300,320,122}
   *)
   ```

#### My thoughts

---

I do not know whether the default order of `Sort` is related with `CharacterCode`.

I guess *Mathematica* treats some characters orderless and skips some characters in sorting strings with `Sort`.

I think some characters are treated as trivial elements, and are put before the alphabet.

Though there maybe one order table for all characters which`I`don't know.

#### My opinion

---

Firstly, you should show what's the correct answer for a variety lists, as @JonathanShock mentioned in the comment.

Otherwise, each time you come up one result differ from *Python*, then ask why *Mathematica* does not work like *Python*.

I think that is  ....

The important thing is how to get the results as expected.

### `Sort` with one function

---

1. ```
   (*Input 5 ==< *)
   Sort[sampleList1, ToCharacterCode[#1] & ]
   ```
2. ```
   (*
   Output 5 ==>
   {compute,Tes,.,,Etz,.a,.m,a,z,T,.T,wha,{}
   *)
   ```
3. ```
   (*Input 6 ==< *)
   ToCharacterCode[%]
   ```
4. ```
   (*
   Output 6 ==>
   {{99,111,109,112,117,116,101},{84,101,115},{46},{},{69,116,122},{46,97},{46,109},{97},{122  
   },{84},{46,84},{119,104,97},{123}}
   *)
   ```
5. ```
   (*Input 7 ==< *)
   Total /@ %
   ```
6. ```
   (*
   Output 7 ==>
   {765,300,46,0,307,143,155,97,122,84,130,320,123}
   *)
   ```
7. ```
   (*Input 8 ==< *)
   First /@ %%
   ```
8. ```
   (*
   Output 8 ==>
   {99,84,46,First[{}],69,46,46,97,122,84,46,119,123}
   *)
   ```

Still does not work well, of course, it maybe wrong, for`Total`is not the correct criteria of order.

The following is what you expected?  note the`StringLength`of characters.

1. ```
   (*Input 9 ==< *)
   FromCharacterCode[Sort[ToCharacterCode[sampleList1]]]
   ```
2. ```
   (*
   Output 9 ==>
   {,.,T,a,z,{,.T,.a,.m,Etz,Tes,wha,compute}
   *)
   ```
3. ```
   (*Input 10 ==< *)
   Sort[ToCharacterCode[sampleList1]]
   ```
4. ```
   (*
   Output 10 ==>
   {{},{46},{84},{97},{122},{123},{46,84},{46,97},{46,109},{69,116,122},{84,101,115},{119,104  
   ,97},{99,111,109,112,117,116,101}}
   *)
   ```
5. ```
   (*Input 11 ==< *)
   First /@ %
   ```
6. ```
   (*
   Output 11 ==>
   {First[{}],46,84,97,122,123,46,46,46,69,84,119,99}
   *)
   ```

*update*

Note: `totalList` here is neither ascending nor descending.

1. ```
   (*Input 12 ==< *)
   totalList = Total /@ %%
   ```
2. ```
   (*
   Output 12 ==>
   {0,46,84,97,122,123,130,143,155,307,300,320,765}
   *)
   ```
3. ```
   (*Input 13 ==< *)
   Transpose[{totalList, Sort[totalList]}]
   ```
4. ```
   (*
   Output 13 ==>
   {{0,0},{46,46},{84,84},{97,97},{122,122},{123,123},{130,130},{143,143},{155,155},{307,300}  
   ,{300,307},{320,320},{765,765}}
   *)
   ```

The above is the same to that use `SortBy`

1. ```
   (*Input 14 ==< *)
   SortBy[sampleList1, ToCharacterCode]
   ```
2. ```
   (*
   Output 14 ==>
   {,.,T,a,z,{,.T,.a,.m,Etz,Tes,wha,compute}
   *)
   ```

*update*

As@MichaelE2  mentioned in the comment,

Note that `SortBy[sampleList1, ToCharacterCode]` effectively orders them by length first. - Michael E2

one method in Rojo's comment

1. ```
   (*Input 15 ==< *)
   yourSort = Max[StringLength[#1]] /. len_ :> SortBy[#1, PadRight[ToCharacterCode[#1], len] & ] & ;
   ```

#### My conclusion

---

So the conclusion maybe the canonical order in *Mathematica* is different from that in *Python*.

Comment: Dictionary order is correctly used in: Evaluating Sort[{"a", ".", "m", "c"}] result in {".", "a", "c", "m"}. It's skip some characters? The answer is no! Every element is a string and should be treated as in dictionary order. WMath should not ignore any characters. Segundo a documentação: "...Sort orders strings as in a dictionary, with uppercase...". I'm thing this is a bug.

Comment: @PedroR I think some characters are in different orders in different encodings. And we can use a sort function in Sort or SortBy to get any result.

Comment: @PedroR How to compare the order of `{` and `.` ? See one example in my edit.

Comment: @PedroR, when you say the right and wrong answer, you mean by the criterion which you wish to apply `SortBy`.

Comment: @PedroR If you wanna do that translation. Use one function is easy to done. SortBy[lista,ToCharacterCode[#]&]

Comment: @PedroR I got no clue how Python does it. Is this what you want `yourSort = 
 Max@StringLength@# /. 
   len_ :> SortBy[#, ToCharacterCode@#~PadRight~len &] &`?

Comment: It seems from this discussion that precisely what PedroR considers to be the correct ordering for a variety of lists should be added to the question.

Comment: @Silvia thanks, welcome to give me suggestions.

Comment: Note that `SortBy[sampleList1, ToCharacterCode]` effectively orders them by length first.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ha, indeed, So `Total/@%` is meaningless. I'll edit. One reason why I edit so frequently is I'm practising editing. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since there is perhaps an implicit question of how to get a sort more along the lines you expect, as I proposed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9840/sorting-a-list-with-secondary-criterion#comment28674_9846) you might  use:

```
asciisort = #[[Ordering @ PadRight @ ToCharacterCode @ #]] &;

asciisort @ {".m", ".ast", "co"}
```

> ```
> {".ast", ".m", "co"}
> ```

Or with the default character-wise order:

```
charsort = #[[Ordering @ PadRight @ Characters @ #]] &;

charsort @ {".m", ".ast", "co"}
```

> ```
> {".ast", ".m", "co"}
> ```

If you are comfortable with shorter strings being ordered first you can also use:

```
SortBy[{".ast", ".m", "co"}, Characters]
```

> ```
> {".m", "co", ".ast"}
> ```

Comment: Or you could call it a Unicode sort.

Comment: @Michael Good point.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean this?

```
 In[11]:= AlphabeticSort[{".m", ".a", "co"}]

 Out[11]= {".a", ".m", "co"}
```

Comment: +1 for the usage of a built-in !

Answer (score 1):

```
sortby[list : {__String}] := 
StringJoin /@ SortBy[First@GroupBy[Characters@list, First], 
ToCharacterCode[#[[2]]] &] ~ Join ~
Sort[StringJoin /@ DeleteCases[Characters@list, {".", __}]]


sortby@{".m", ".at", "monday", ".limp", "dart"}
(* {".at", ".limp", ".m", "dart", "monday"} *)
```

**I think the better way is what @yode mentioned**

```
AlphabeticSort[{".m", ".at", "monday", ".limp", "dart"}]
(* {".at", ".limp", ".m", "dart", "monday"} *)
```