# Sorting a list into "all possible ways" - sorting with incomplete information

Tags: algorithm, sorting

**Familiar example of sorting objects**

> I have a list of $n$ "vectors" $\{x^{(1)},...,x^{(n)}\}$ of form $
>  x^{(i)}=\sum_{j=1}^m c_j^{(i)}x_j,i=1\dots n$, where $c_j^{(i)}$ are
>    nonnegative coefficients of the vector $x^{(i)}$, and components $x_j$
>    are shared among them, and take some nonnegative values.
>
> For example, we could have: $$  x^{(1)}=10x_1+2x_2\\
>  x^{(2)}=10x_1+3x_2+x_3\\ x^{(3)}=5x_1+2x_2 $$
>
> I say that $x^{(a)}\ge x^{(b)}$ iff $x^{(a)} - x^{(b)}\ge 0$.
>
> Since components $x_j$ are nonnegative, we have that $x^{(a)}\ge
>  x^{(b)}$ if $c_j^{(a)}\ge c_j^{(b)}$ for every $j=1,\dots,m$. In this
>    example, we can have a $\ge$ relation between all the "vectors", even
>    thought $x_j$ are unknown.
>
> Now we have defined the objects, and the comparator function, and our
>    set of objects is comparable. Now, the above example can be easily
>    sorted: $x^{(2)}\ge x^{(1)} \ge x^{(3)}$.
>
> So desired result would be: $\{x^{(2)},x^{(1)},x^{(3)}\}$.
>
> I noticed `SortBy` and `Sort` work for examples like this one.

**Generalized sort with incomplete information**

> But a valid input can be the following example as well:
>
> $$  x^{(1)}=10x_1+2x_2+x_3\\ x^{(2)}=10x_1+3x_2\\ x^{(3)}=5x_1+2x_2 $$
>
> Here $x^{(2)}\ge x^{(3)}$ and $x^{(1)}\ge x^{(3)}$, and $x^{(3)}$ is
>    clearly the smallest, but we can't compare $x^{(2)},x^{(1)}$
>    definitely. Which is larger, depends on components $x_2,x_3$. To
>    resolve this, we take:
>
> $$ x^{(2)}-x^{(1)}=x_2-x_3. $$
>
> Now, we can see that $x^{(2)}\ge x^{(1)}$ iff $x_2\ge x_3 \text{
>  (c1)}$. Depending on this $\text{(c1)}$ condition, we can either have:
>    $\{x^{(2)},x^{(1)},x^{(3)}\}$ or $\{x^{(1)},x^{(2)},x^{(3)}\}$ as the
>    desired output.
>
> But $x_j$ are "components" (unknown variables), thus in this second
>    example, the desired output should contain all possible sortings and
>    conditions under which they are valid. That is, more precisely, in
>    this example, the desired output is:
>
> $\{ \{\{x^{(2)},x^{(1)},x^{(3)}\},\{x_2\ge
>  x_3\}\},\{\{x^{(1)},x^{(2)},x^{(3)}\},\{x_2\lt x_3\}\} \}$
>
> A list of two sortings each with one condition under which they are
>   valid.
>
> The `SortBy` and `Sort` output one of the sortings (just the sorted list of "vectors") for these cases -
>    but I need all of them along with the conditions.
>
> The first example, under this generalized scenario, would then be:
>
> $\{\{\{x^{(2)},x^{(1)},x^{(3)}\},\{\}\}\}$
>
> A list with one possible sorting with no conditions (under all values
>   for $x_j$'s).
>
> Where "sorting" is a list pair of sorted elements and conditions under
>   which the sorting is valid, as you can see in both examples.

> How can I do this in mathematica?
>
> Create a function that given input `v={v[1], v[2], ..., v[n]}` outputs
>   the sortings: `{s[1],s[2],...}`, where sortings have form
>   `s[i]={{'sorted elements of v'},{'conditions'}}`?

I was mentioning `SortBy`, and one naive solution that is probably possible, is to `SortBy` the list of vectors into $m!$ ways, by going over all permutations of attributes $x_j$ as [criterions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9840/49840) - Then eliminate the duplicate sortings, and finally extract the conditions from the remaining sortings. But this is extremely slow for large $m$ and does a lot of unecessary work (if the case is similar to example 1, then all of the $m!$ outputed sorted lists will be the same, and we will eliminate all but one...).

> How can I implement my own sort that can do this reliably and always "sort" those vectors given $x_j$ are unknown? It will need to find such conditions or perhaps multiple cases of multiple conditions?

(To format the above two examples as code?)

```
Clear[x, v, w];
v = {10 x[1] + 2 x[2], 10 x[1] + 3 x[2] + x[3], 5 x[1] + 2 x[2]};
w = {10 x[1] + 2 x[2] + x[3], 10 x[1] + 3 x[2], 5 x[1] + 2 x[2]};
```

Then if the solution to our problem is function `f[v_] := ...`, then again:

First example `F[v]` should return:

```
 {{{10 x[1] + 3 x[2] + x[3],10 x[1] + 2 x[2],5 x[1] + 2 x[2]},{}}}
```

And `f[w]` should have two sortings:

```
f[w][[1]]={{10 x[1] + 2 x[2] + x[3], 10 x[1] + 3 x[2], 5 x[1] + 2 x[2]},{x[2]>=x[3]}}

f[w][[2]]={{10 x[1] + 3 x[2], 10 x[1] + 2 x[2] + x[3], 5 x[1] + 2 x[2]},{x[2]<x[3]}}
```

Motivation:

> I have a problem that I split into subproblems, and reduced each
>   subproblem to such a list of "vectors". The subproblems can then be
>   solved by solving a system of equalities that are constructed from the
>   the sortings, that need to be solved assuming the condition under
>   which the sorting is valid, and to have a complete set of solutions,
>   all sortings are necessary to be considered.
>
> This is a very very lengthy process if done by hand (a very large
>   number of systems of equations arise from sortings - and the "vectors" form which I need to derive sortings can get messy), so I'm trying
>   create an algorithm to do it in Mathematica, and this question above
>   is the step where I'm currently stuck at.

Comment: Very well written and interesting question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We identify each polynomial with its coefficient list. We use `` Internal`ListMin `` on the coefficient array of input list with `FixedPointList` to identify layers in the partial ordering we seek. Then for each layer with multiple elements we use `Reduce` to find the condition for each possible permutation of the elements.

```
ClearAll[coeffArray, paretoLayers, addCondition]

coeffArray = Normal @ Last @ CoefficientArrays[#] &

paretoLayers = Complement @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &[Most@
   FixedPointList[DeleteCases[#, Alternatives @@ Internal`ListMin[#]] &, #]] &;

addCondition[v_] := If[Length[#] == 1, {#, {}}, 
    Piecewise[{#, Reduce[LessEqual @@ (#.v), v, Reals]} & /@ Permutations[#]]] &;

 addCondition2[v_] := If[Length[#] == 1, {{#, {}}},
    {#, Reduce[LessEqual @@ (#.v), v, Reals]} & /@ Permutations[#]] &;

conditionalSorts[v_] := {Join @@ #[[1]], And @@ #[[2]]} & /@ 
  (Transpose /@ Tuples[addCondition2[Variables[v]] /@ 
       paretoLayers@coeffArray[v]] /. {} -> True)
```

***Examples:***

```
v = {10 x[1] + 2 x[2], 10 x[1] + 3 x[2] + x[3], 5 x[1] + 2 x[2]};
paretoLayers @ coeffArray[v]
```

> {{{5, 2, 0}}, {{10, 2, 0}}, {{10, 3, 1}}}

```
addCondition[Variables[v]] /@ paretoLayers@coeffArray[v]
```

> {{{{5, 2, 0}}, {}}, {{{10, 2, 0}}, {}}, {{{10, 3, 1}}, {}}}

```
conditionalSorts[v]
```

> {{{{5, 2, 0}, {10, 2, 0}, {10, 3, 1}}, True}}

```
w = {10 x[1] + 2 x[2] + x[3], 10 x[1] + 3 x[2], 5 x[1] + 2 x[2]};
paretoLayers @ coeffArray[w]
```

> {{{5, 2, 0}}, {{10, 2, 1}, {10, 3, 0}}}

```
addCondition[Variables[w]] /@ paretoLayers @ coeffArray[w]
```

> [image]

To have a just a list of `{orderedlist, condition}` pairs use `addCondition2`:

```
addCondition2[Variables[w]] /@ paretoLayers@coeffArray[w]
```

> `{{{{{5, 2, 0}}, {}}}, {{{{10, 2, 1}, {10, 3, 0}}, 
>      x[2] <= x[3]}, {{{10, 3, 0}, {10, 2, 1}}, x[2] >= x[3]}}}`

Display each layer as a column:

```
Column /@ %
```

[image]

```
Column @ conditionalSorts[w]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
z = RandomInteger[5, {5, 3}].Array[x, 3]
```

> `{4 x[1] + 2 x[2] + 4 x[3], x[2], 2 x[2], 3 x[2] + 5 x[3], 2 x[1] + 3 x[3]}`

```
addCondition[Variables[z]] /@ paretoLayers @ coeffArray[z]
```

> [image]

```
addCondition2[Variables[z]] /@ paretoLayers@coeffArray[z]
```

> `{{{{{0, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 3}}, 
>      x[2] >= 1/3 (-2 x[1] + x[3])}, {{{2, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
>      x[2] <= 1/3 (-2 x[1] + x[3])}}, {{{{0, 2, 0}}, {}}}, {{{{0, 3, 
>        5}, {4, 2, 4}}, x[2] <= 4 x[1] - x[3]}, {{{4, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 5}}, 
>      x[2] >= 4 x[1] - x[3]}}}`

```
Column /@ %
```

[image]

```
Column @ conditionalSorts[z]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using `Reduce` directly if the input list is not too long:

```
ClearAll[AllOrderings]

allOrderings[a_] := {#, Reduce[LessEqual @@ #, Variables[a], Reals] }& /@  
  Permutations[a];
```

***Examples:***

```
allOrderings[v] // FullSimplify // Column
```

[image]

```
allOrderings[w] // FullSimplify // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, appreciate your response! Would you mind giving me advice on how to iterate this output (under your ***Examples***) in *mathematica*-ish way? My goal here is to have `{v,c}` in each iteration, where `v` is the original list of "vectors" (or just a list of their coefficient tuples to be consistent with your example outputs), but sorted, under condition(s) `c`. I noticed conventional programming *does not look or work* best in mathematica and that's the reason for asking this.

Comment: @Vepir, thank you for the accept. Great question btw. I added  `addCondition2` which gives such a list.

Comment: Thank you for following the follow up question - but what I meant to ask by my comment is for example:  taking your first `addCondition2` example output: 
`out = {{{{{5, 2, 0}}, {}}}, {{{{10, 2, 1}, {10, 3, 0}}, x[2] <= x[3]}, {{{10, 3, 0}, {10, 2, 1}}, x[2] >= x[3]}}};`, 
I wanted to *extract and iterate (handle)* all `{v,c}` pairs from it - here I wanted to do `"for e in out"` such that `e` is
`{ { {5, 2, 0},{10, 2, 1}, {10, 3, 0} },{x[2] <= x[3]} }` in first iteration and `{ { {5, 2, 0},{10, 3, 0}, {10, 2, 1} },{x[2] >= x[3]} }` in second iteration. - *to group all "vectors", conditions*

Comment: I think your update *"Using `Reduce` directly if the input list is not too long"* is more of what I wanted to use, but perhaps I forgot to mention that there, it seems that more than needed amount of cases and condtitions is produced (Perhaps because its not taking into consideration that conditions are *nonnegative* as stated in the problem)?

Comment: @Vepir, I added `conditionalSorts` that reorganizes the output in the desired form. Re many conditions in the output of `Reduce` you are right; need to add the condition that all variables positive. Try if changing `Reals` to `PositiveReals` makes the desired difference.

Comment: I appreciate your update. Just FYI: some sortings produced by `conditionalSorts` are equivalent (which is more noticeable when applying something like `FullSimplify`), where for example we can have two sortings with corresponding conditions that simplify to `o[1]==o[2]`,`o[1]==o[2]` making those two sortings the same after substitution. (Example input:  `{a[2]+o[1],5 a[2]+4 o[1],10 a[2]+7 o[1]+o[2],10 a[2]+6 o[1]+2 o[2],5 a[2]+3 o[1]+o[2]}` would give four sortings, out of which two are equivalent, giving three unique sortings after elimination)