# Retaining and reusing a one-to-one mapping from a sort

Tags: sorting

Imagine I sort the elements of an array $Q$ by some means.  Perhaps I sort strictly by the elements in the first column, perhaps I use SortBy[...] to sequentially sort by the elements in successive columns, etc.  Here, regardless of what I do, the result of this sort will be some one-to-one mapping from items in $Q$ to some items in the sorted array, $Q^*$.

Can I somehow retain or reuse this particular one-to-one mapping function on some other array with the same dimensions as $Q$?  Very specifically, I mean that if we move element $q_i \in Q$ at position $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ in $Q$ to some new position $(b_1, b_2, ...)$ in $Q^*$, then we corresponding move the same element $h_i \in H$ from $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ in $H$ to $(b_1, b_2, ...)$ in $H^*$.  And we do this regardless of the identity of $h_i$, i.e. we're not repeating the sort.

---

To provide a specific example of where I'm getting in trouble, I'd like to sort the following list by the first column, then the second (with this priority):

```
data = {{4, 5}, {6, 1}, {11, 87}, {24, 52}, {90, 4}, {4, 4}};

 In[...]:= SortBy[data, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &]
 Out[...]:= {{4, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 1}, {11, 87}, {24, 52}, {90, 4}}
```

However:

```
  In[...]:= Ordering[SortBy[data, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &]]
  Out[...]:= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

What I wanted from Ordering[...] was:

```
  Out[...]:= {6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

How can I make the above work?

Comment: Yes you can. Have a look at [Ordering](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html) function.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin How can I make the "Ordering" function work for a SortBy function where we sort by column 1, then 2, etc.?

Comment: You most certainly can do this, just the ordering function would become more complex,and this can possibly degrade the efficiency. Another option is to construct a list with positions like `Transpose[{lst,Range[Length[lst]]}]`,where `lst` is the original list, and use `SortBy` on this one, changing all your sorting functions as `f`-> `First@f[#]&`. Then, after a list is sorted, extract positions of elements of the original list in a sorted list as `sorted[[All,2]]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, here is my stab at it. As I mentioned in comments, I can see two ways to solve this.

### Ordering - based solution (and a by-product: compilable `SortBy`)

One way is to use `Ordering`, but the problem here is that `SortBy` when used with a list of functions performs in a way where each function serves as a tie-breaker for ties resulting from application of a previous function to a pair of list elements. Should we have a built-in `OrderingBy` function, and that would be easy. But `Ordering` requires a single sorting function, just like `Sort`.

#### Generating a comparison function

The solution I will use here is to generate a possibly complex single comparison function from a list of functions used in `SortBy`. Here is a possible code for it:

```
Clear[generateSortingFunction];
generateSortingFunction[funcs__] :=
   Module[{sortFGenerator},
     sortFGenerator[funcs] //. {
        sortFGenerator[f_, funs___] :> 
           (With[{fst = f[#1], sec  = f[#2]},
               If[OrderedQ[{fst, sec}],
                  If[OrderedQ[{sec, fst}],
                     sortFGenerator[funs][##],
                     True
                  ],
                  False
               ]] &),
        sortFGenerator[][__] :> True}
   ];
```

Assuming that a list of functions in your example is `{#[[1]]&,#[[2]]&}`, we will have then:

```
sf = generateSortingFunction[#[[1]]&,#[[2]]&]
```

> ```
> With[{fst$=(#1[[1]]&)[#1],sec$=(#1[[1]]&) [#2]},
>    If[OrderedQ[{fst$,sec$}],
>      If[OrderedQ[{sec$,fst$}],
>         (With[{fst$=(#1[[2]]&)[#1],sec$=(#1[[2]]&)[#2]},
>             If[OrderedQ[{fst$,sec$}],
>                If[OrderedQ[{sec$,fst$}],True,True],
>                False]
>             ]&)[##1],
>         True],
>      False]]&
> ```

This is admittedly a mess, but the reason I decided to go with the code generation is that such generated pure functions can be compiled, which in this case can be checked by 
executing e.g.

```
cf = 
   Compile[{{fst, _Integer, 1}, {sec, _Integer, 1}},
      sf[fst, sec], 
      CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
   ]
```

To some extent, this works around `SortBy` not being compilable, since `Sort` with this comparison function can be compiled and effectively would work as `SortBy`.

#### Implementing `orderingBy`

With the above construct, we can now implement our own version of `orderingBy`, as follows:

```
ClearAll[orderingBy];
orderingBy[lst_, funs_List] :=
   Ordering[lst, All, generateSortingFunction[funs]];
```

Now, for your example, we have:

```
orderingBy[data,{#[[1]]&,#[[2]]&}]

(* {6,1,2,3,4,5} *)
```

### Using `SortBy`

The second option is to use `SortBy` itself, but on a more complex list where positions will be added to elements. I will use here the code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7127/how-to-pass-composite-function-list-to-sortby/7128#7128), which allows to elegantly compose functions passed to `SortBy`. I will reproduce this here for completeness:

```
ClearAll[sortFun];
sortFun /: SortBy[expr_, sortFun[funs_List, partFun_]] := 
   SortBy[expr, Map[Composition[#, partFun] &, funs]];
```

with this, the implementation ot `orderingBy` function is straight-forward: "dress" original list with element positions, reorder it by `SortBy`, and extract positions from reordered list:

```
ClearAll[orderingByAlt]
orderingByAlt[lst_, funs_List] :=
   SortBy[
       Transpose[{#, Range[Length[#]]}] &@lst, 
       sortFun[funs, First]
   ][[All, 2]]
```

which of course gives the same result:

```
orderingByAlt[data, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &}]

(* {6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}  *)
```

### Remarks

Which of the two approaches to pick is largely a matter of taste. The second one seems more economical, since we reused higher-level abstraction (`SortBy`). However, if for example one would want to compile the code, then the first approach seems preferable, since it generates compilable code.

Answer (score 12):

Using Szabolcs's clever [inversion method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/121) we can write a more concise and efficient form than the standard decorate-and-sort:

```
orderingBy[lst_, sfuns_List] :=
  SortBy[
    Range @ Length @ lst,
    Cases[sfuns, f_ :> (f @ lst[[#]] &)]
  ]
```

*Update*: additional definitions to handle [default tie-break](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116650/121) and provide an operator form:

```
orderingBy[lst_, sfn_] := orderingBy[lst, {sfn, Identity}]

orderingBy[fns_][lst_] := orderingBy[lst, fns]
```

Now:

```
data = {{4, 5}, {6, 1}, {11, 87}, {24, 52}, {90, 4}, {4, 4}};

orderingBy[data, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &}]
```

> ```
>  {6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

This proves to be an order of magnitude faster than Leonid's `orderingByAlt`:

```
data = RandomInteger[10000, {500000, 2}];

orderingByAlt[data, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &}] // Timing // First (* Leonid's function *)

orderingBy[data, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &}]    // Timing // First (* my function *)
```

> ```
> 2.0444
>
> 0.226
> ```

Comment: +1. This is nice. I was surprised that Szabolcs's solution was so fast, and here is another nice application of it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Odering` (assuming that `ref` and `set` are of same length):

```
set[[Ordering@Ordering@ref]]
```

or a more complicated, less efficient way is:

```
pos = Range@Length@set;
set[[pos /. Thread[Ordering@ref -> pos]]]
```

> ```
> {"E", "A", "D", "C", "B"}
> ```

An even more complicated way:

```
ref = {"e", "a", "d", "c", "b"};
set = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

order = Position[Sort@ref, #, 1][[1, 1]] & /@ ref
```

> ```
> {5, 1, 4, 3, 2}
> ```

```
set[[order]]
```

> ```
> {"E", "A", "D", "C", "B"}
> ```

Comment: Istvan, the way you compute `order` is really not efficient. Efficent way would be `Ordering[Ordering[ref]]`, and that's all there is to it here, really (so you don't need your longer code using rules either) .

Comment: @Leonid Well, I hoped you will make it yourself an answer :) Efficiency is definitely not my table, and my mind halts before entering a recursive loop (second `Ordering`)... Thanks anyway, edited in.

Comment: If I wanted to make this a separate answer, I would have done so at the start :). I think it would be better to start with `order = Ordering@Ordering@ref`, replacing the slower `Position`- based code, since people tend to pay more attention to things at the begining of the post. But this is up to you, of course.

Comment: @Leonid It felt like stealing your line. Now moved up for better understanding.

Comment: Well, I left that comment specifically for you to use it should you wish to do so. I posted another answer because it became clear that the OP wants `SortBy`-like behavior with a list of comparison functions, and it was more than just using `Ordering`.

Answer (score 1):

Since V 12.0 there is `OrderingBy` which simplifies the solution considerably:

```
data = {{4, 5}, {6, 1}, {11, 87}, {24, 52}, {90, 4}, {4, 4}};

OrderingBy[data, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &]
```

{6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}