# Looking for a way to insert multiple elements into multiple positions simultaneously in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional, insert

I would like to take the following data:

```
insertValues = {r, x};
insertPositions = {{1}, {5}};
originalList = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
```

and generate output that looks like this:

```
{r,a,b,c,d,x,e,f,g}
```

*Mathematica*'s `Insert` command seems limited in that it does not allow you to insert multiple elements simultaneously into different positions in a list.

I wrote an ugly `While[]` loop to accomplish this, and it works, but seems inappropriate for Mathematica's functional approach to coding.  Is there a "simpler" way to accomplish this goal with a functional approach?  Thank you.

```
insertValues = {r, x};
insertPositions = {{1}, {5}};
originalList = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};

loopCounter = 0; 
posCounter = 0; 
final = originalList;
While[loopCounter < Length[insertValues],
  final = 
   Insert[final, insertValues[[loopCounter + 1]], 
          (insertpositions[[loopCounter + 1]] + posCounter)]; 
  loopCounter++; 
  posCounter++
];
```

Comment: Please don't post simultaneously [in several forums](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/99418?p_p_auth=is07FAPg). Perhaps that will save you a few hours, but you should consider other people's time too

Comment: @belisarius I see not reason to not post on many sites :) but only if there is information about this on both sites.

Comment: I also see no reason why users shouldn't post on multiple forums.  There is no guarantee the best answer will be found on one forum vs another. Nor is there a guarantee that the same users spend time on both forums.  Nor is it required that someone spend time answering the same question multiple times on multiple sites.

Comment: Adding information on cross-posting is considered polite and beneficial: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/368/131 (cc @belisarius)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### New developments

[rasher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher) posted a new answer with clean and well performing code that caused me to look again at this problem.  (It well deserves your vote.)  I see now that there are good ways to approach this problem that haven't yet been fully developed.  Fundamentally rasher's code operates by `Sort`, but I don't think even he realized this as `Riffle` et al are superfluous.  We merely need `Ordering` and `Part` applied to joined lists of the correct order:

```
oInsert[list_, val_, pos_] :=
  Join[val, list][[ Ordering @ Join[pos, Range @ Length @ list] ]]
```

In a way rasher solved the problem *twice*: `Riffle` and `sa[[ps]] = reps` already place the elements in the proper order; one merely needs to get rid of the zeros.  We could use `DeleteCases` but pattern based methods are slow.  Instead I reimplemented the `Riffle` operation in terms of `SparseArray`, but to make it efficient I had to be clever and unfortunately here that (so far) implies less clean code.

```
saInsert[list_, val_, pos_] :=
  With[{no = Length[list], ni = Length[val]},
    SparseArray[
      Automatic, {2, no + 1}, 0,
      {1, {{0, ni, no + ni}, pos ~Join~ Range[no] ~Partition~ 1}, val ~Join~ list}
    ]\[Transpose]["NonzeroValues"]
  ]
```

This ugly bit of code manually constructs a two row `SparseArray`, the upper row being the insertion elements and the lower being the original list.  It then transposes them, and extracts the `"NonzeroValues"`.  (Despite the name these are actually the non-background values; this code still works correctly with zeros.)

Rudimentary test of both new methods:

```
oInsert[{a, b, c, d, e}, {W, X, Y, Z}, {1, 2, 4, 6}]

saInsert[{a, b, c, d, e}, {W, X, Y, Z}, {1, 2, 4, 6}]
```

> ```
> {W, a, X, b, c, Y, d, e, Z}
>
> {W, a, X, b, c, Y, d, e, Z}
> ```

I shall add timings for these functions later, but to summarize my early findings:

- `multiInsert2` is still the fastest for a limited number of insertions into a long list
- `saInsert` is superior to all other methods posted so far for a greater number of insertions into a packed list
- `oInsert` is competitive with `saInsert` and `rashernator` on unpacked lists.  It is faster than `rashernator` on packed lists.

---

### Original Method

If your list is a vector (has no sub-lists) this is perhaps the simplest way, and likely competitively fast:

```
m = origlist;

m[[{1, 5}]] = {{r, x}, m[[{1, 5}]]}\[Transpose]

Flatten[m]
```

> ```
> {r, a, b, c, d, x, e, f, g}
> ```

Edit: Ray Koopman points out that this method, by itself, does not handle an edge case in `Insert` where the position is one greater than the length of the list, i.e. `Insert[{1,2,3}, x, 4]`.  This is accounted for in the function below by padding the list as required.

If your list is not a vector (as defined above) we could use a different head for the inserted elements and then replace it with `Sequence` to effect a flatten.  Here is a function that handles both cases, selecting between the methods for best performance:

```
multiInsert[list_List, val_, pos_] /; Length@val == Length@pos :=
  Module[{m = list, f, pad},
    pad[x_] /; Max@pos == Length@list + 1 := AppendTo[m, x];
    If[VectorQ[val] && VectorQ[list],
      pad[{ }]; m[[pos]] = Transpose @ {val, m[[pos]]}; Flatten[m],
      pad[f[]]; m[[pos]] = MapThread[f, {val, m[[pos]]}]; m /. f -> Sequence
    ]
  ]
```

Input is a little different from yours:

```
multiInsert[Range@15, {a, b, c}, {3, 7, 13}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, a, 3, 4, 5, 6, b, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, c, 13, 14, 15}
> ```

### Preallocate Method

Nasser proposed a method of preallocating the array.  This idea was promising if it could be optimized because a packed array could be preserved throughout the process theoretically reducing memory and computation time.  His implementation was limited in performance because it used a tag that necessitated unpacking and because searching for that tag using `Position` is slow.  Here is an implementation that directly calculates the runs of original values rather than tagging and finding them afterward.

```
multiInsert2[list_, val_, pos_] /; Length@val == Length@pos :=
  Module[{new, start, end, offset, n1, n2},
    {n1, n2} = Length /@ {list, val};
    new    = ConstantArray[0, n1 + n2];
    start  = Prepend[pos, 1];
    end    = Append[pos - 1, n1];
    offset = Range[0, n2];
    MapThread[
      new[[# ;; #2]] = list[[#3 ;; #4]]; &,
      {offset + start, offset + end, start, end}
    ];
    new[[pos + Range[0, n2 - 1]]] = val;
    new
  ]
```

This function appear to be best for a moderate number of insertions into a long list.  (See below)

### Notes and timings

Ray Koopman posted a very elegant method, which on reflection I've seen before though I cannot remember where.  I voted for that method but there is reason to use the longer forms that belisarius and I proposed: speed on long lists.  Every `Insert` operation reallocates the array which takes time proportional to the length of the list.  As such, a method using `Fold` will slow down considerably when doing many insertions into a very long list.  I will call Ray Koopman's code `foldInsert`:

```
foldInsert[list_, val_, pos_] /; Length@val == Length@pos :=
 Fold[
  Insert[#1, #2[[2]], #2[[1]]] &,
  list,
  Reverse @ Sort @ Transpose @ {pos, val}
 ]
```

And using this timing code for the three functions `multiInsert`, `multiInsert2`, `foldInsert`:

```
timeAvg = 
  Function[func,
    Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}],
    HoldFirst];

time[n_Integer, k_Integer, rand_: RandomInteger] :=
 Module[{start, vals, pos},
  start = Range@n;
  vals = rand[9, k];
  pos = Sort @ RandomSample[start, k];
  timeAvg @ #[start, vals, pos] & /@ {multiInsert, multiInsert2, foldInsert}
]
```

With 3500 insertions into a length 5000 list:

```
time[5000, 3500]
```

> {0.0017968, 0.007368, 0.01372}

With five insertions into a length 500,000 list:

```
time[500000, 5]
```

> {0.02432, 0.0006736, 0.001448}

With 7500 insertions into the length 500,000 list:

```
time[500000, 7500]
```

> {0.03244, 0.01812, 5.038}

All timings above were performing with integer into integer insertions.  If inserting reals unpacking is necessary.  Here are a few timings for that situation:

```
time[150000, 50, RandomReal]
time[150000, 500, RandomReal]
time[150000, 5000, RandomReal]
```

> {0.01372, 0.005488, 0.0624}
>
> {0.01308, 0.007368, 0.592}
>
> {0.01684, 0.01748, 8.658}

Comment: Thank you for your swift response.  I don't understand the end code "\[Transpose]".  What does "\" stand for that I might look it up in the documentation?

Comment: @Todd `\[Transpose]` is the long form of the transpose symbol entered with [Esc] `tr` [Esc].

Comment: `multiInsert` fails if `Last@pos == Length@list+1`, which both `multiInsert2` and `foldInsert` handle as `Insert` would by effectively `Append`ing `Last@val` to `list`.

Comment: @Ray Thanks for the bug report; let me see if I can fix it cleanly.  I must admit I never knew one could use that input with `Insert`.

Answer (score 17):

Building on Kuba's answer: If you insert in reverse order then the positions don't need to be incremented.

```
Fold[Insert[#1,#2[[2]],#2[[1]]]&, origlist,  
     Reverse@Sort@Transpose@{insertpositions,insertvalues}]
```

If a value is to be inserted in several positions then it must be appear in `insertvalues` once for each position. Elements of `insertvalues` may themselves be lists.

Answer (score 10):

Probably also:

```
pInsert[origList_, repList_] := 
      Function[{l}, ReplacePart[
                      l, 
                      Thread[Rule[#[[1]], Sequence[#[[2]], l[[#[[1]]]]]] &/@ repList]]]@origList

pInsert[{a, b, c, d, e}, {{2, {x, y}}, {5, z}}]
```

> {a, {x, y}, b, c, d, z, e}

Comment: Oops, looks like I forgot to plan for an insert of a list into a vector.  I'll fix that and then compare these methods.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't think this way is particularly fast or robust, but feel free to nuke it

Comment: Nuke it?  Not sure I understand.  Anyway, your method appears to be faster than mine on long lists with few insertions (50,000 / 50) while mine is faster with many insertions. (+1)

Comment: Another code equivalent to the above solution: `pInsert=Function[{lst,rep},ReplacePart[lst,Apply[Function[{r1,r2},r1->Sequence[r2,lst[[r1]]]],rep,{1}]]];`

Answer (score 9):

If there are no multiple positions for each `insertelement` we can do something like:

```
i = 0;
Insert[origlist, "mark", insertpositions] /. "mark" :> (++i; insertvalues[[i]])

(*insertposition should be sorted*)
```

if, there are it can be exteded easily, by making duplicates in `insertelements` or to make different `"marks"` for them.

Comment: Your code works also with for example        `origlist = {1, {2, 3}, 4};
insertpositions = {{1}, {2, 3}};
insertvalues = {x, y}`.     It gives : {x, 1, {2, 3, y}, 4}).This is interesting.

Comment: @andre this case you've provided is exactly the same as OP's. two values -> two positions, and even though levels are not `1`, `Inser` works with them.

Comment: What is interesting is precisely that levels are 1 for x and 2 for y. This is not compatible with other answers.

Comment: @andre I'm not sure if I understand :) that's good, right? Fortunatelly OP has provided `insertpositions` in form accepted by `Inser`, thats because he was trying to use it.

Comment: Yes that's good :) I was looking for a generalization of `Insert[]` compatible with multi-insertion and multi-level.

Comment: It is somewhat faster and IMHO cleaner to use `Unevaluated` for this purpose:  `Module[{i = 1}, Insert[list, Unevaluated[val[[i++]]], List /@ pos]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was thinking and thinking, what `List/@` does... :) well it is redundant with OP's data. Very nice simplification. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7):

What a neat question and set of answers. Wish I'd been here when it was new, but here's my belated entry:

```
rashernator[list_, reps_, pos_] :=
     Module[{sa = Riffle[list, 0, {1, -1, 2}], ps = pos*2 - 1},
     sa[[ps]] = reps;
     sa[[Sort[Join[ps, Range[2, 2*Length@list, 2]]]]]]
```

About 20X faster than rest on large lists/larger replacement lists (e.g. on 50K list with 35K replacements, it's ~20X and ~50X as fast as the neat answers by Mr. Wizard, much more than that on the other answers I tested).

Seems to take over when the size of replacement list goes above 0.5 to 1%.

+1 to OP and answerers!

Comment: This is great!  Very fast and much cleaner than my code.  Don't I feel silly now!  Initial tests show that my `multiInsert2` is some 20X to 30X faster than yours in the case of a limited number of insertions into a long packed list, e.g. `time[5*^6, 1*^3]`, so it does have a place, but yours appears to be faster in more cases.  I shall study this further.  Nice work!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks for kind words! Yep, as I noted, somewhere around the 1% density it takes over. The two methods combined make a wicked good utility function.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  Your code in a way solves the problem twice!

Comment: @mr: lol, I did exactly that (well, almost exactly, as in the two-row sparse idea). It performed worse in my tests. Another interesting benchmark anomaly. Thanks for looking at it, tweaking it, etc. Glad you found it interesting! Edit- just tested yours - it *is* faster - the method you contruct array is better. Nice work, wish I could +1 you again...

Comment: How does my `saInsert` perform for you?  How were you constructing your `SparseArray`?  As I said I had to resort to manual assembly for best performance, but even without that it was about as fast as `rashernator`.  Also how does `oInsert` perform for you?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: re: saIinsert, see prior comment. oInsert actually seems slightly superior. And it's super-clean code to boot. I'll go poke at code and reply later with what I did with SA, but other reason I dropped it - can't (trivially) use it to insert non-scalar values.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: As promised: I created two-row SA with `{ConstantArray...,list}`, inserted into first, pulled via `NonzeroValues`. Probably unneeded `ConstantArray` explains perf. but as I said, dropped it since inserting non-vectors needs hand-waving. Anyway, that and the OP were the two I came up with in a ten-minute late-night cigar think, pretty happy with OP. Looking at it after the fact simply using ordering against joined would have been logical conclusion. Nice if future MM had native multi-insert. I <3 `Ordering`: used it a while back to make dupe finder that smokes canonical `GatherBy`.

Comment: I wish I could be that effective in ten minutes; it usually takes me much longer work through even simple problems where I am not merely regurgitating past experience.  When you say "dupe finder" I presume you mean the function to incrementally number repeating elements?  I remember that one and it is good.  You're right about the limitation of `SparseArray`; I'll have to note that in my answer.  ps: you made [the wall](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/989/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Nope, I meant the `GatherBy[Range@Length@list,list[[#]]&]` method used often for positions of same ele/dupes/etc. and for quickly getting lists of positions of multiple targets from a larger list - can be done up to order of magnitude faster via `Ordering`. As far a effectiveness - I've learned much from your answers re: looking at a problem from as many angles as possible.

Comment: If your solution is *general* you *need* to post it as an answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/121).  If you are doing something like Michael used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32016/121) I don't believe it is a replacement for `GatherBy`, but I'd love to be proven wrong.  Please, do tell! :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: will do, and I'll search for the "fast way to find multiple positions" question and post the related method there. I suppose you as mod can see where I've posted new, if so I'd very much like your feedback on them. Will be later - off to get a bite.

Comment: Enjoy your food!  I look forward to reading your posts.  FYI: anyone can see your non-deleted posts by looking at [this page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher?tab=answers&sort=newest) of your profile.

Answer (score 2):

I have not looked at all the answers to see if one is similar to this. But this is the typical way to do these things in Matlab.  This assumes the input is vector or one level list. It works by allocating vector of the size needed to contains everything.

**Update**

This is slight update. This version is a little faster than what I had before but still not as fast as Mr.Wizard's. Instead of using Position and marker, used `Complement`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
insertvalues = {r, x};
insertpositions = {1, 5};
origlist = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};

  insertMultiNasser[to_List, from_List, pos_List] /; Length@from == Length@pos := 
   Module[{b, npos, o},
   b = Table[0, {Length[from] + Length[to]}];
   npos = pos + Range[0, Length[from] - 1];
   b[[npos]] = from;
   o = Complement[Range[Length[b]], npos];
   ReplacePart[b, Thread[o -> to]]
   ];
```

to call

```
insertMulti[origlist, insertvalues, insertpositions]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### timings

MrWizard is at worst 10 times faster. So no cigar for me.  Here are the timings (first number is above function, second number is MrWizard's multiInsert above.

```
time[50000, 35000]
{0.081121, 0.01148167}

time[5000, 350]
{0.00761285, 0.000349442}

time[500000, 3500]
{0.811205, 0.0355682}

time[50000, 45000]
{0.084241, 0.0137281}
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of `NaN` here.  Anyway, I await your timings.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I needed a special symbol that will not occur in the original input. i.e. needed a special marker. In Matlab nan is used since for valid input, it should not contain a nan in it. If you suggest a different one I could use it, but this is how it is done in Matlab ;) the marker is any value that is not present in the `insertvalues` list. That is all.

Comment: In that case I recommend using an additional symbol in the Module, e.g. `mark`.  Also, you can simplify (and speed) your `Position` call with e.g. `Position[bb, mark]`.  Oh, one more thing: `ConstantArray` will be much faster than `Table`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard good point. I was working in global context first and I did not think of it that when I move things to Module context, then any symbol there will go the job. WIll update now. Working on timings now also...

Comment: I'm looking forward to this one.  I think in certain circumstances it should be very good (once optimized).

Comment: I've run some timings of my own and it's not as fast as I'd like.  I think the problem is that `Position` is slow to find all the originals in a long list.  However, this is inspiring me write what I hope will be a faster pre-allocated method, so +1 for that.

Comment: Nasser, I have added my preallocate method to my answer above.