# How to insert / merge a list into another list?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Background: I am working on a 2D geometry algorithm where I need to insert a list of 2D points into another list of 2D points. Somewhat to my surprise I found no Mathematica function capable of doing this. My requirement is for a function that when provided for example:

```
 {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}}
```

and

```
 {{100,100}, {200,200}}
```

returns

```
{{1,1},{2,2}, {100,100}, {200,200},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}}
```

I looked at various Mathematica functions where Insert seemed the candidate to use, now

```
 Insert[{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}},{{100,100}, {200,200}},3]
```

returns

```
 {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {{100, 100}, {200, 200}}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}
```

note the extra braces around

```
 {100, 100}, {200, 200}
```

Inspired by this [question/answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30647/looking-for-a-way-to-insert-multiple-elements-into-multiple-positions-simultaneo) I created insertM.

```
 insertM[list_, values_, at_] := Module[{i = 0},
   Insert[list, "mark", Array[{at} &, Length[values]]] /. "mark" :> (++i; values[[i]])]
```

which gives

```
 insertM[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}, {{100, 100}, {200, 200}}, 3]
 {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {100, 100}, {200, 200}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}
```

Although insertM does the job, I have this ' there must be a better way ' feeling.

Now my question(s): Is there a Mathematica function that performs my requirement? If not, **is there a better function then insertM to do this?** In better I rank beautiful code (short, functional) highest unless it is significantly slower than a less beautiful alternative.

Comment: I made an error, but have edited it, sorry.

Comment: If you really want fast inserts, you should not use lists. The choice of the appropriate data structure to use would depend on other things you want to do with this collection of points. Quadtree comes to mind.

Comment: The trivial scheme way to do it would compose append with take and drop (e.g. Append[Take[xs, n], vs, Drop[xs, n]]).

Comment: Looks like this would almost work, but for Append behaving differently.

Comment: Instead use Join

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few options:

```
insertSequence1[x_, y_, n_] := Insert[x, Unevaluated[Sequence @@ y], n]

insertSequence2[x_, y_, n_] := Fold[Insert[##, n] &, x, Reverse@y]

insertSequence3[x_, y_, n_] := Insert[x, y, n] ~FlattenAt~ n

x = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}};
y = {{100, 100}, {200, 200}};

insertSequence1[x, y, 3]
insertSequence2[x, y, 3]
insertSequence3[x, y, 3]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {100, 100}, {200, 200}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}
>
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {100, 100}, {200, 200}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}
>
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {100, 100}, {200, 200}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}

Comment: I did not know about the function FlattenAt, I like the third option. ( Imagine I hadn't asked the question. )

Answer (score 7):

Just for variety:

```
l1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}};
l2 = {{100, 100}, {200, 200}};
```

Just using `Join`:

```
f[x_, y_, n_] := Join[x[[1 ;; n - 1]], y, x[[n ;; -1]]]
```

So,

```
f[l1, l2, 3]
```

yields:

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {100, 100}, {200, 200}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}

Comment: It is much faster than my previous ( but more beautiful ) choice:
insertSeqA[x_, y_, n_] := FlattenAt[Insert[x, y, n], n];
insertSeqB[x_, y_, n_] := Join[x[[1 ;; n - 1]], y, x[[n ;; -1]]]
Timing[insertSeqA[Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {1000, 1000}], 1], 
   Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {100, 100}], 1], 1000];]
Timing[insertSeqB[Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {1000, 1000}], 1], 
   Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {100, 100}], 1], 1000];]

Answer (score 3):

Since V 13.1 there is `Splice` which simplifies @Simon Wood's `insertSequence3` to

```
dt = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}};
in = {{100, 100}, {200, 200}};

Insert[dt, Splice[in], 3]
```

{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {100, 100}, {200, 200}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

```
☺ = (♯ = #; ♯[[#2]] = ## &[#[[#2]], ## & @@ #3]; ♯) &;

☺[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}, 2, {{100, 100}, {200, 200}}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {100, 100}, {200, 200}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}