# Insert at specific resulting positions in multidimensional list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an initial "multidimensional" list (that is, a list that is not a vector):

```
list0 = {{1},{2,3,4},{3,4},{5}};
```

and I want to insert elements `x,y,z` at specific positions `{1,1}`, `{2,3}`, `{4,2}`, to obtain the resulting list:

```
{{x,1},{2,3,y,4},{3,4},{5,z}}
```

That is, the list of positions `{1,1}`, `{2,3}`, `{4,2}` gives the positions *in the resulting list*.

What's a clean way to do this?

This is a generalization of [Insert at specific resulting positions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67306/534), which is a one-dimensional version of this question.

Comment: @Kuba Typo. Fixed.

Comment: What when positions are {2,2} and {2,3} for example, should it behave like `Insert` so: `... {2, x, 3, y, 4}...` or rather `{2, x, y, 3, 4}`? Where the latter is maybe intuitive but not consistent with `Insert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `insertF` in the answer to your linked question also works for the multidimensional case:

```
insertF = Fold[Insert[#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, #,  SortBy[Transpose[{#2, #3}], Last]] &;

list0 = {{1},{2,3,4},{3,4},{5}};
parts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}};
insertF[list0, {x, y, z}, parts]
(* {{x, 1}, {2, 3, y, 4}, {3, 4}, {5, z}} *)

list0 = {{1},{2,3,4},{3,4},{5}};    
parts2 = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}};
insertF[list0, {x, y,  z}, parts2]
(* {{1}, {2,x,y,3,4}, {3,4}, {5,z}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
inserttt[where_, what_, whereExactly_] := (
    # = 0;
    Insert[where, Unevaluated[what[[++#]]], whereExactly]
    ) & @ Unique["whatever"]

 inserttt[{{1}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {5}}, 
          {x, y, z},
          {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}}]
```

> ```
>  {{1}, {2, x, 3, y, 4}, {3, 4}, {5, z}}
> ```

---

#### old, incorrect, failing with `{{2,2}, {2,3}..` cases:

I find your description not consistent with code samples, but here is what I've understood:

```
inserttt[where_, what_, whereExactly_] := ReplacePart[
                                           Insert[where, "", whereExactly],
                                           Thread[whereExactly -> what]
                                           ]


inserttt[{{1}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {5}}, 
         {x, y, z}, 
         {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}}]
```

> ```
> {{x, 1}, {2, 3, y, 4}, {3, 4}, {5, z}}
> ```

Comment: That doesn't work as I want. The position of `y` in `{{1}, {2, x, 3, y, 4}, {3, 4}, {5, z}}` is `{2,4}`, but I want it to be `{2,3}`. The output I expect from `inserttt[{{1}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {5}}, {x, y, z}, {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}}]` is `{{1},{2,x,y,3,4},{3,4},{5,z}}`

Comment: @becko I understand. I will try to fix it later. Now it is at least consistent with Insert.