# Insert at specific resulting positions? (Another option)

Tags: list-manipulation

I found the answer in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67306/insert-at-specific-resulting-positions/67309#67309) very interesting to do what I need, but I would like something where I could provide a `list to be modified`, a `list with values` that will be added and a `list with the positions` of the values to be added.

Something to get this result:

```
listaInicial = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
listaModificadora = {a, b, c, d, e};
listaPosições = {2, 6, 7, 8, 13};
Fold[Insert[#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, listaInicial, {{a, 2}, {b, 6}, {c,
    7}, {d, 8}, {e, 13}}]
```

> {0,a,1,2,3,b,c,d,4,5,6,7,e}

P.S:I think it should be very obvious, but I am still suffering with Slot function. One day I will be able to understand this function with a lot of training.

Comment: I studied how it behaves the `Riffle` function, but it does not help much. This function follows a fixed sequence: `Riffle[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {x, y}, {5, -1, 2}]`. >{1,2,3,4,x,5,y,6,x,7,y,8,x,9,y}

Comment: seems a near exact duplicate, though this version got several new perhaps better answers.

Comment: From the beginning it is presenting that refers to a post. But the solutions in the old post were not according to my needs.

Comment: I needed three inputs that were not displayed in the old post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start applying `Transpose` function:

```
listaInicial = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
listaModificadora = {a, b, c, d, e};
listaPosições = {2, 6, 7, 8, 13};
Fold[Insert[#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, listaInicial, 
 Transpose[{listaModificadora, listaPosições}]]
```

> {0,a,1,2,3,b,c,d,4,5,6,7,e}

Or

```
InsertValuePosition[list_, values_, positions_] := 
 Fold[Insert[#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, list, 
  Transpose[{values, positions}]]

InsertValuePosition[listaInicial,listaModificadora,listaPosições]
```

> {0,a,1,2,3,b,c,d,4,5,6,7,e}

Answer (score 4):

Here is somewhat obscure one-liner.

```
data = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
new = {a, b, c, d, e};
where = {2, 6, 7, 8, 13};

(RightComposition @@ Thread[Insert[new, where]]) @ data
```

> `{0, a, 1, 2, 3, b, c, d, 4, 5, 6, 7, e}`

Answer (score 2):

[LMC's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129297/22013) is much in the spirit of Mathematica. Since you don't like slots (while you should - they make lots of things easier) I provide a straightforward `Do` loop:

```
lst1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
lst2 = {a, b, c, d, e};
lst3 = {2, 6, 7, 8, 13};

lst = lst1;
Do[
 lst = Insert[lst, lst2[[i]], lst3[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[lst2]}
 ]
lst
```

> {0, a, 1, 2, 3, b, c, d, 4, 5, 6, 7, e}

Answer (score 2):

```
listaInicial = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
listaModificadora = {a, b, c, d, e};
listaPos = {2, 6, 7, 8, 13};
listIpos = 
 Complement[Range@Length@Join[listaInicial, listaModificadora], 
  listaPos]

Normal@SparseArray[listIpos~Join~listaPos -> 
               listaInicial~Join~listaModificadora]
```

> {0, a, 1, 2, 3, b, c, d, 4, 5, 6, 7, e}

or

```
out = ConstantArray[0, Length@Join[listaInicial, listaModificadora]];
out[[listaPos]] = listaModificadora;
out[[listIpos]] = listaInicial;
out
```

> {0, a, 1, 2, 3, b, c, d, 4, 5, 6, 7, e}