# Rearranging elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
oldList = {"a-1", "b", "c", "a-2", "d", "e", "f", "a-3", "w"}
```

and would like to get the following list:

```
newList = {{a-1,b}, {a-1,c}, {a-2,d}, {a-2,e}, {a-2,f}, {a-3,w}}
```

I see that there was a similar but not identical question was posed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30647/looking-for-a-way-to-insert-multiple-elements-into-multiple-positions-simultaneo) four years ago.  I started by using `StringMatchQ` and `Position` to find the position of the elements that contain "-" and then `Complement` to find which elements need to have the terms containing "-" affixed to them.  But `Insert` doesn't seem to be very flexible and I'd like to avoid a bunch of `For` loops.

Comment: Don't you think you could modify answers to your previous questions to apply them here?

Answer (score 7):

```
Join @@ (Thread[{#, {##2}}] & @@@ Split[oldList, StringFreeQ[#2, "a"] &])
```

> {{"a-1", "b"}, {"a-1", "c"}, {"a-2", "d"}, {"a-2", "e"}, {"a-2", "f"}, {"a-3", "w"}}

Also,

```
Flatten[Thread[{#, {##2}}] & @@@ Split[oldList, StringFreeQ[#2, "a"] &], 1]
```

> {{"a-1", "b"}, {"a-1", "c"}, {"a-2", "d"}, {"a-2", "e"}, {"a-2", "f"}, {"a-3", "w"}}

Comment: My mistake, I should have made it clear that oldList is a list of strings.  Both of your solutions lead to `{{"a-1", "b"}, {"a-1", "c"}, {"a-1", "a-2"}, {"a-1", "d"}, {"a-1", 
  "e"}, {"a-1", "f"}, {"a-1", "a-3"}, {"a-1", "h"}, {"a-1", 
  "w"}, {"a-1", "z"}}`

Comment: @Suite401, please see the updated version.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks /@you, kglr, swish.

Comment: And one final generalization question, and i'll let go of this issue;

Comment: I will post it as a new question, and please tell me what the best way to handle these situations, so as not to annoy people.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Flatten[
  SequenceCases[oldList,
      {left:_Plus,right:Except[_Plus]..}:>Thread[{left,{right}}]]
, 1]
```