# How to insert elements at different locations of a given list

Tags: list-manipulation

Say a list is given as

```
list = {a, b, c, d, r, m, n};
```

Suppose I want to insert 2 and 3 at position 3 and 7, respectively.

`Insert[list, 2, 3]` puts 2 at position 3, but `Insert[list, {{2, 3}, {3, 7}}]` does nothing.

How is it possible?

Comment: Dirty trick: `Block[{k = 0}, Insert[{a, b, c, d, r, m, n}, Unevaluated[{2, 3}[[++k]]], {{3}, {7}}]]`

Comment: @J.M. Wow, that one is _really_ dirty. I had to read it several times to understand it half way at least...

Comment: @Henrik, I didn't want to post it as an answer lest it be thought of as an endorsement. ;D

Comment: related: [Looking for a way to insert multiple elements into multiple positions simultaneously in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30647/106)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look what I found after spelunking:

```
GroupTheory`PermutationGroups`Private`FoldInsert[
 {a, b, c, d, r, m, n},
 {2, 3}, {3, 7}
 ]
```

> {a, b, 2, c, d, r, 3, m, n}

Well, it is not entirely correct for it does not revert the order of insertion... =/

Comment: Wow! $\phantom{}$

Comment: I wonder if this [package](http://gtpack.org) has similar functions.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ That package appears to be very new. Good to know! (... although I won't find it applicable to my own work...)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, it is accompanied with a book published just about two months ago.

Answer (score 7):

How about this

```
myInsert[list_, valuePosList_] := Fold[Insert[#, Sequence @@ #2] &, 
                                       list, 
                                       SortBy[valuePosList, -Last[#] &]
                                      ]

myInsert[list, {{2, 3}, {3, 7}}]
```

> ```
> {a, b, 2, c, d, r, m, 3, n}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
insertList[list_, valuePosList_] := ReplacePart[
  list,
  Apply[
   Rule[#2, Sequence[#1, list[[#2]]]] &,
   valuePosList
   , {1}
   ]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]