# Efficient way of identifying the indices of first occurrences

Tags: performance-tuning

It seems to me like identifying the first occurrence of unique elements should take about the same amount of time as it takes to delete duplicates. My data sets are much larger than this (`a` is 10-20k and `b` is 1-10k).

```
With[{a = 1000, b = 10}, list = RandomInteger[a, b a]];
Timing[uniques = DeleteDuplicates@list;]
Timing[firstOccurrenceIndices = Position[list, #, 1, 1] & /@ uniques // Flatten;]
```

> {0.000116, Null}
>
> {0.653104, Null}

Any ideas?

Comment: **Very** closely related: [How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/121)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a faster way:

```
Clear[f]
Timing[MapIndexed[If[Not@IntegerQ@f[#1], f[#1] = First[#2]] &, list];]
```

Now `f[elem]` will tell you the position of the first occurrence of `elem`.  On my machine this is approximately 8-10 times faster than your approach for a list of 10000 elements.

The timing for `a=5000, b=100` is 1.3 s on my machine.

---

In general I expect your solution to have complexity $O(a^2 b)$ while mine should be $O(ab \ln a)$, in terms of $a,b$ as used in your question and $b>1$.  I haven't measured it though. For larger lists the speedup will be more significant though.

---

An alternative:

```
dt = Dispatch@Thread[list -> Range@Length[list]];
```

This takes 1.07 s on my machine for the same list as above.

Now to get the first index of `elem` just do `elem /. dt`.

---

Another **much faster** alternative:

```
firstOccurrenceIndices = GatherBy[Range@Length[list], list[[#]] &][[All, 1]];
```

This takes 0.04 s on my machine.

---

In the [Raspberry Pi version](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/) (which is a beta of v10) the function [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) will provide a direct solution to this problem

Comment: I should mention that my elements are strings, rather than integers. Not sure if that affects your solution.

Comment: @TimothyWofford It doesn't.  The values of `f` are positions which are integers but you could replace `IntegerQ` by `ValueQ` here.

Comment: I see, so to get my list of first indices I guess I follow this with `firstIndices=DeleteDuplicates@(f/@list)`

Comment: @TimothyWofford it's more efficient to do `f/@DeleteDuplicates[list]` instead

Comment: `GatherBy[...]` is still about 100 times slower than `DeleteDuplicates`, so there is still a little room for improvement (just in case anyone needs a challenge). But it is excellent for my data sets. Thanks.

Comment: hahahah... I was about to add an answer using that method, starting my post with: "Poor Szabolcs seems to be suffering from senility (like me), as he has forgotten [his own method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/121)..."

Comment: @TimothyWofford I made a small change for another 2x speedup.  The problem is that if we write this in Mathematica, we can't really compete with the low level implementation that `DeleteDuplicates` has.  For example, `list[[#]]&` above has to be evaluated using Mathematica's (relatively slow) main evaluator `Length[list]` times.  The result is trivial and it's really unnecessary to do this.  But we're forced to do it since we're programming in Mathematica ...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Indeed, I think I'm getting old :D  I found the new-in-10 `PositionIndex` which as of today seems to be actually slower than the GatherBy approach ...

Answer (score 3):

An approach using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
f[list_]:=Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[First@#2, #1] &, 
    list], _, #1 -> First@#2 &][[2]]
```

For:

```
list=With[{a = 5000, b = 100}, list = RandomInteger[a, b a]];
```

then

```
f[list]//Timing
```

takes 0.9375 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Of the non-`GatherBy` methods, the fastest are those that use the same approach as Leonid Shifrin's [`positionOfDuplicates`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21352). In v5.2 I use

```
posi[list_] := Sort@Part[Range[Length@list][[#]],
  Most@FoldList[Plus,1,Length/@Split@list[[#]]]]& @ Ordering@list
```

which gives the position of the initial instance of each value in `list`, in the order in which they occur. (If `Sort` is omitted then the positions are ordered by the values in `list`, which is sometimes more convenient.)

Answer (score 3):

Prompted by some conversation in comments elswhere, my method.

```
Module[{o},
   If[OrderedQ[#], Most@Accumulate@Prepend[Tally[#][[All, 2]], 1],
    o = Ordering[#];
    o[[Most@Prepend[Accumulate[Tally[#[[o]]][[All, 2]]] + 1, 1]]]]] &[targetListHere]
```

Can clobber `GatherBy` method by over an order of magnitude (e.g. on `RandomInteger[1*^6,1*^5]` my tests showed ~11X faster). On the same test size with a sorted list, this was around ~30X faster than `GatherBy`. Much more frugal RAM use compared to GB also...

Of course, taking advantage of the structure of your data (non-negative integers of a fairly limited range) this and all the other posted methods can be clobbered performance-wise with

```
findFirstOccurPos[list_] := 
 Module[{z = ConstantArray[0, Max[list] + 1]},
  z[[Reverse@(list + 1)]] = Range@Length@list;
  (Length@list + 1) - SparseArray[z]["NonzeroValues"]]
```

Taking further advantage of the structure and random distribution of your example, we can boost performance another 5-6X with selective list "snooping" that short-circuits the process:

```
findFirstOccurPosSC[list_] := 
 Module[{lens = Ceiling[Length@list/{100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1}], 
   z = ConstantArray[0, Max[list] + 1], 
   need = Length@DeleteDuplicates@list, result, l},
  Catch[Do[l = list[[;; curlen]];
    z[[Reverse@(l + 1)]] = Range@curlen;
    result = (curlen + 1) - SparseArray[z]["NonzeroValues"];
    If[Length@result == need, Throw[result]];
    , {curlen, lens}]; result]]
```

This will be in general ~30X faster than using `GatherBy` on large lists.