# Find positions of duplicates that are neighbours

Tags: list-manipulation

Assuming the following list {1,2,3,3,5,6,3} I would like to get the position of values that are next to each other and are duplicates. That is, the output should be {3,4}.

Thank you for any help.

Cheers,
Vaclav

Answer (score 12):

The following should be a fast and robust solution:

```
ClearAll@neighbouringDuplicates
neighbouringDuplicates[list_] := 
    Select[SplitBy[Range@Length[list], list[[#]] &], Length@# > 1 &]

neighbouringDuplicates@{1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3}
(* {{3, 4}} *)

neighbouringDuplicates@{1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5}
(* {{3, 4}, {9, 10}} *)
```

This is an example of the ["transform by" pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25101/5) that Szabolcs also used [in a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/5) to great effect.

Comment: \rm-rf For me, your answer is a good and valid answer

Answer (score 5):

Another straightforward solution:

```
DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[{#, # + 1} & /@ Position[Differences[{1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3}], 0]]

(* Out: {3,4} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Plenty fast (as in orders of magnitude faster than using split). Since question is a bit ambiguous, I treat anything beyond a pair as multiple pairs, e.g., in `{1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6}`, the `2,2,2` is treated as a pair of duplicates. Output is strictly *pair* positions.

```
test = {1, 1, 5, 6, 9, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5}

With[{pl = PadLeft[#, Length[#] + 1, Min[#] - 1]}, 
   Replace[Pick[Range[Length[#]], Differences[pl], 0], 
   a_ :> {a - 1, a}, 1]] &[test]

(* {{1, 2}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {11, 12}} *)
```

Some timings (caveat - on netbook, cigar lounging):

```
test = RandomInteger[1000000, 5000000];

r1 = neighbouringDuplicates@test; // Timing // First

r4 = With[{pl = PadLeft[#, Length[#] + 1, Min[#] - 1]}, 
       Replace[Pick[Range[Length[#]], Differences[pl], 0], 
        a_ :> {a - 1, a}, 1]] &[test]; // Timing // First

r1 == r4

(* 
116.641948
0.358802
True
*)
```

So about 300X slower using split here.

Comment: rasher, would you give me comparative timings for the method I just posted, both with `Union` and `Transpose`? (+1 by the way)

Comment: Pick[Transpose[{Most[#], Rest[#]}] &[Range[Length[#]]], 
   Differences[#], 0] &[test]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Pretty much a wash testing on the lounge-machine with lists up to 10^7 in length. My mess is usually 5-10% less time, but frankly that's in the noise for MM timing trust IMHO. I suppose mine working on arbitrary element types is a plus.

Comment: @Coolwater: Clean, pretty quick (~3rd fastest in simple tests), but spits out noise of `{}` in results. Nice though!

Comment: Thanks for confirmation; I'm glad to know `Pick` is now performing as it should. (You already have my +1.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yep, `Pick` is pretty darn efficient. And, votes from the master always appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pretty straightforward way:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5}; 
tf = Position[Table[list[[i]] == list[[i - 1]], {i, 2, Length[list]}], True]
```

Or one can avoid the `Table` using the equivalent

```
Position[Equal[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Partition[list, 2, 1], True]
```

Both of these give a list of the positions where all the pairs begin. You can change this to the exact form you are looking for by

```
Riffle[Flatten[tf], Flatten[tf] + 1]
{3, 4, 9, 10}
```

If there are triples, then it is somewhat unclear what the desired output is. As Nasser points out, this can be fixed by applying `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: This does not work for `list = {1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2};` it gives `{3, 4, 4, 5}` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wqbzj.png)

Comment: The pairs are at 3,4 and 4,5... so it does do what the OP asked for.

Comment: Well, ok, but the positions should be `{3,4,5}` and not `{3,4,4,5}` I would think. I think all what you need to do is just remove duplicate positions from last list. Good answer any way :)

Comment: The second example can be reduced to `Position[Partition[list, 2, 1], {x_, x_}]` :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is Pickett's method but using `SparseArray` Properties as a faster alternative to `Position`.

```
fn = Union[#, # + 1] &@
       SparseArray[Unitize @ Differences @ #, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"] &;

fn @ {1, 1, 5, 6, 9, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12}
> ```

If position pairs with duplicates are acceptable (rasher's format), we can save a bit more time by using `Transpose[{#, # + 1}]` in place of `Union[#, # + 1]`.

This (with `Transpose`) tests about an order of magnitude faster than rasher's method in version 7, but `Pick` was optimized in v8.  It (with `Union`) tests two orders of magnitude faster than `neighbouringDuplicates`.

Answer (score 1):

In versions 10.1+, you can use [SequencePosition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html)

```
neighborPositions = SequencePosition[#, {a_, a_}]&;
```

**Examples:**

```
l1 = {1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3} ;
l2 = {1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5};


{#, posF @ #} & /@ {l1, l2} // Grid[Prepend[#, {"list", "positions"}], Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

**Note:** See [Performance problems in new Sequence functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83325/121)