# Find equal elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Consider the following code to produce the sequence $x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}$ where $x_i=11\cdots1$ ($i$ digits 1). Is there an easier way to do this?

```
n = 7
X = Table[Sum[10^i, {i, 0, k - 1}], {k, 1, n + 1}]
R = Table[Mod[X[[k]], n], {k, 1, n + 1}]
X 
R
```

Also, the code defines the list `R` of remainders on division of $x_i$ by $n$. The output of `R` is `{1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 4}`.

**I'd like to do the following:** determine the indexes producing the first two equal elements of `R` (for example, since `R[[1]]=R[[7]]` I'd like to do some math with `X[[1]]` and `X[[7]]`).

Comment: Why are you using `SetDelayed[]`?

Comment: @belisarius, sorry. I have no idea what you are talking.

Comment: Why are you using `:=` instead of `=`?

Comment: Is it not the way to define something?! To store on a variable.

Comment: Then read this Q&A http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r = {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 4};

sol = Select[GatherBy[Range[Length@r], r[[#]] &], Length@# > 1 &, 1][[1,;;2]]
(* {1,7} *)
```

(Credit: [@Szabolcs's answer in this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/125))

or

```
sol2 = ## & @@@ Position[r, (Select[Gather[r], Length@# > 1 &, 1][[1, 1]]), 1, 2]
```

or

```
sol3 = ReplaceList[r, {a___, b : PatternSequence[i_, ___, i_], ___} :> 
                       Sequence[1 + Length[{a}], Length[{a}] + Length[{b}]], 1]
```

**Update:**

```
f[n_] := Module[{x = Table[Sum[10^i, {i, 0, k - 1}], {k, 1, n + 1}],  r, sol},
       r = Mod[x, n]; 
       sol =Select[GatherBy[Range[Length@r], r[[#]] &], Length@# > 1 &, 1][[1,;;2]]; 
       {x, r, sol, x[[sol[[2]]]] - x[[sol[[1]]]]}]

f[7]
(* {{1,11,111,1111,11111,111111,1111111,11111111},
    {1,4,6,5,2,0,1,4},
    {1,7},
    1111110} *)
```

Comment: Very short code. Is it possible to save the result on `sol` for example, so I could use simply `sol[[1]]` to make use of `1`?

Comment: @Sigur, with the updated version `sol[[1]]` gives `1` instead of `{1}`.

Comment: Please, could you try with `n=2`? I'm getting error *Part specification 1[[-1]] is longer than depth of object. >>*.

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thanks so much. With your help I can illustrate the fact that any natural $n$ has a multiple written using only 1 or 0.

Comment: @Sigur, my pleasure...

Comment: How to put the whole code inside a function so I can call it as `f[3]` or `f[23]` to see the results?

Comment: @Sigur, what would you like `f` to return - `{x,r,sol}` or just `sol` or ...?

Comment: Yes, 4 objects: `{x,r,sol,x[[sol[[2]]]] - x[[sol[[1]]]]`.

Comment: @Sigur, pls see the update.

Answer (score 3):

```
n = 7;

{X, R} = Table[(10^x - 1)/9, {x, 1, n+1}] // {#, Mod[#, n]} &;

X

R

matchPairs = Subsets[Range@Length@R, {2}][[First@Position[Subsets[R, {2}], {x_, x_}]]]

(*

{1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 111111, 1111111, 11111111}
{1, 4, 6, 5, 2,0, 1, 4}

{{1,7}}

*)
```

Just take `First@matchPairs` to get first only of any pairs of indices that have same value for remainder.

BTW - bad idea to use uppercase symbols/initials - you can clash with built-ins...

Comment: Nice! In this case, to use the number `1` from the output `{{1,7}}` I have to use `matchPairs[[1,1]]`, right? Is it possible to save so that I simply use it as `matchPairs[[1]]`?

Comment: @Sigur: As I said, just add `First@` in front of the `Subsets...`, and you'll get the first match only, whereby you can address them as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 4};

pos = FirstCase[{a_, b_, ___} :> {a, b}] @ PositionIndex @ # &;

pos @ list
```

{1, 7}

```
pos @ {0, 0}
```

{1, 2}

```
pos @ {1, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

{2, 3}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Catch`, `Throw` and `Do`:

```
r = {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 4};

Catch[Do[Do[If[#[[i]] === #[[j]], Throw[{i, j}]];, {j, i + 1, 
Length[#]}];, {i, 1, Length[#] - 1}]] &@r

(*{1, 7}*)
```