# How discretize a region placing vertices on a specific non-uniform grid

Tags: regions, mesh, finite-element-method

Given a **generic** region, for *example*:

```
Ω = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   2 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 2 x y - 2 <= 0 ∧ x^2 + y^2 > .1, {x, y}];
```

and a non-uniform grid, for example:

```
Ωb = RegionBounds[Ω];
{xg, yg} = 
  N@Map[bound \[Function] 
     Range[bound[[1]], 
      bound[[2]], (bound[[2]] - bound[[1]])/20], Ωb];
{xg, yg} = 
  Map[g \[Function] {g[[1]], 
     Sequence @@ (g[[2 ;; -2]] RandomReal[{1 - .04, 1 + .04}, 
         Length[g] - 2]), g[[-1]]}, {xg, yg}];
```

which, together, can be shown with:

```
Ωg = 
  RegionPlot[Ω, AspectRatio -> Automatic];

gg = Graphics[{LightGray,
    Table[
     Line[{{x, Ωb[[2, 1]]}, {x, Ωb[[2, 
         2]]}}], {x, xg}],
    Table[
     Line[{{Ωb[[1, 1]], y}, {Ωb[[1, 2]], 
        y}}], {y, yg}]
    }];

Show[gg, Ωg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm searching a way to discretize the region to a `MeshRegion` or `ElementMesh` in such a way that all vertices (`MeshCoordinates` or incidents) are placed on at least one gridline.

At present I'm working on a routine that discretize the region with `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` with a reasonable `MaxCellMeasure`. Then I'm trying to split all `Line` mesh cells crossing any gridline into two or more `Line` such that at least one end is on a gridline. Then I plan to delete vertices not on a grid line and properly reconnect the sourronding vertices.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is the only way I could think to, but it appear difficult, because there are many branches tho examine.

A more elegant and simple approach would be helpful. For example, there is a way to use `ToElementMesh` and `ToBoundaryMesh` to accomplish this task? In the end, the routine should work with thousand of vertices and hundred of gridlines in a reasonable time.

Comment: (1) Do you want the internal mesh coordinates to lie on the gridlines or just the boundary coordinates?  (2) How **generic**?  The example has nice algebraic boundaries without singular points.

Comment: @MichaelE2 As of my self-answer, I finally found a way, not simple, not elegant, not fast, but it works, more or less. (1) I'm only interested to mesh the boundary in this way. (2) The region can have corners like a square, but it's not "pathological"; can be a derived region or a ParametricRegion; generally it's something for which RegionQ gives True; I cannot count on having a representation as inequalties.

Answer (score 12):

```
regplt =   RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega], AspectRatio -> Automatic];

ContourPlot[{2 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 2 x y - 2, x^2 + y^2 - .1}, {x, -1.25, 1.25}, {y, -1.25, 1.25},
Contours -> {{0}}, BaseStyle -> Thick,
GridLines -> {xg, yg}, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {xg, yg},
MeshStyle -> {Directive[{Red, PointSize[.01]}],
Directive[{Green, PointSize[.01]}]},
ImageSize -> 400, Prolog -> regplt[[1]]]
```

[image]

**Update:**

> ...  *if I have a Region and not its implicit description*

you can recover the implicit description of the region using:

```
Region`RegionProperty[\[CapitalOmega], {x, y},"ImplicitDescription"]
```

or

```
Region`RegionProperty[ \[CapitalOmega], {x, y},"FastDescription"][[1, 2]]
```

to get

```
-2+2 x^2+2 x y+3 y^2 <= 0 && x^2+y^2 > 0.1
```

Comment: +1 for some interesting tricks I wasn't aware of.

Comment: However: 1) This can be turned into a BoundaryMeshRegion extracting from the Graphics the boundaries? maybe... 2) mesh points are enough accurate? I suppose they are only accurate for Graphics purposes 3) most important... I cannot apply this if I have a Region and not its implicit description...

Comment: another interesting undocumeted trick... does it works for any Region that can also be discretized?

Comment: @unlikely, please see the answers by [Silvia](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39202/125), [m_ goldberg](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39196/1250),[belisarius](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39204/125), and [Simon](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39237/125) to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39184/125) and the q/a linked there.

Comment: I think the `"ImplicitDescription"` has floated up to the top level in `RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]`.  (Or `Simplify[RegionMember[reg, {x, y}], (x | y) \[Element] Reals]` if you want exactly the same expression.)

Comment: @kguler I don't think we can easily "extract" Line segments in the proper order from the Graphics object to build a BoundaryMeshRegion. If I'm wonrg, can you provide a complete answer from a Region to a BoundaryMeshRegion?

Comment: @unlikely, i am afraid you might be right:)

Answer (score 7):

This is the same idea as [unlikely's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/16267/unlikely), which has same following drawback.  The discretization of the region makes the boundary piecewise linear and thereby reduces the accuracy.  The points found on the grid are points on the linear approximations of the boundary.  This causes the boundary to contract further (on the concave side), thereby further reducing the accuracy.  Ideally, a root-finding procedure should be applied to adjust the points found in this method toward the boundary of the region.  Given that the regions are generic, it seemed difficult to hit on a good generic algorithm.  When the equation of the boundary is known, `FindRoot` is the obvious choice.  In other cases, it or something else might be efficient.  In any case, I left that adjustment to be done.

The idea is simple.  For each boundary line/curve/path, find the grid lines crossed by each segment and solve for the intersections.  Do this in order, so that the boundary element of the region can be constructed.   The intersections are simple linear equations that can be conveniently solved with `Rescale`.

```
snaptogrid[reg_, xg_, yg_] :=
 Module[{ptslists, coords, tpos, 
    xsgn, xgCrossings, xt,   ysgn, ygCrossings, yt},

  ptslists = Function[{component},
     coords = Part[
       MeshCoordinates[component],
       Append[#[[All, 1]], #[[-1, 2]]] &[MeshCells[component, 1] /. Line -> Identity]];
     DeleteDuplicates @
      Flatten[
        Table[
         tpos = t + {0, 1};
         xsgn = Evaluate@UnitStep[-Apply[Times, # - coords[[tpos, 1]]]] &;
         xgCrossings = Extract[xg, SparseArray[xsgn@xg]["NonzeroPositions"]];
         xt = Rescale[xgCrossings, coords[[tpos, 1]], tpos];     (* x grid crossing times *)
         ysgn = Evaluate@UnitStep[-Apply[Times, # - coords[[tpos, 2]]]] &;
         ygCrossings = Extract[yg, SparseArray[ysgn@yg]["NonzeroPositions"]];
         yt = Rescale[ygCrossings, coords[[tpos, 2]], tpos];     (* y grid crossing times *)

         Function[{t}, Rescale[t, tpos, #] & /@ Transpose@coords[[tpos]]] /@ 
          Sort@Flatten[{xt, yt}],                (* convert crossing times to coordinates *)

         {t, Length[coords] - 1}],
       1]
     ] /@ ConnectedMeshComponents[RegionBoundary[reg]];
  BoundaryMeshRegion[
   Flatten[ptslists, 1],
   Sequence @@
    (Line /@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@
      (Internal`PartitionRagged[Range@Total[#], #] &[Length /@ ptslists]))
   ]
  ]
```

OP's example:

```
bΩ = snaptogrid[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ω], xg, yg]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.237352, Null} *)

Show[
 bΩ, gg,
 Graphics[{Red, Point[MeshCoordinates[bΩ]]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: For alternatives to `` Internal`ParititionRagged ``, see [Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size)

Comment: Interesting, "compact" routine, I had to study many tricks you used to have an idea of how it works. However, on my tests with `MaxCellMeasure->0.2/200` and `Length[xg] == Length[yg] == 200` I get an `AbsoluteTiming` of about 5 sec, while a sligtly revised version of mine (avoiding `NSolve`) requires about 0.3 sec.. Maybe it's because you check every boundary element against possible intersections with every gridline?

Comment: @unlikely That's a good guess. There would be a lot unnecessary testing.

Answer (score 6):

### MOST RECENT UPDATE

I sligtly revised the code, mainly to avoid `NSolve` to compute lines intersections and to directly get intersection in the proper order, if possible.

This first helper function, with a binary search algorithm, give the gridline index to wich all coordinates `vals` given belong, or a half-odd if not on gridline; `sameTest` allow to configure the accuracy of the check.

```
BinPositions[vals_, brakes_, sameTest_] :=
 Map[val \[Function] 
   Catch@Module[{lo = 1, mid, hi = Length[brakes], el, res},
     While[lo <= hi, Which[
       TrueQ@sameTest[val, el = brakes[[mid = Floor[(lo + hi)/2]]]], 
       Throw[mid],
       el > val, hi = mid - 1,
       True, lo = mid + 1]];
     lo - 1/2],
  vals]
```

This second helper function, based on some output of the previous functions, gives the indices of the crossed gridlines. Maybe we can do better.

```
NearestIntegersBetween = {m, n} \[Function] 
   With[{\[Delta] = n - m, p = IntegerQ[m]}, Which[
     \[Delta] > 1 || \[Delta] == 1 && p, {Ceiling[m], Floor[n]},
     \[Delta] > 0, {Floor[m] + 1},
     \[Delta] == 0 && p, {m, n},
     -\[Delta] > 1 || -\[Delta] == 1 && p, {Floor[m], Ceiling[n]},
     -\[Delta] > 0, {Floor[n] + 1},
     True, {}
     ]];
```

This third helper function compute the intersections of a line segment with the crossed gridlines, in the order of the segment.

```
SegmentGridIntersections =
  {x1, y1, x2, y2, xl, yl} \[Function] 
   Module[{m11 = y2 - y1, m12 = x1 - x2, v1 = x1 y2 - x2 y1},
    Which[
     Length@xl == 0,
     {(v1 - m12*yl)/m11, yl}\[Transpose],

     Length@yl == 0,
     {xl, (v1 - m11*xl)/m12}\[Transpose],

     True, Join[
        {(v1 - m12*yl)/m11, 
          yl}\[Transpose], {xl, (v1 - m11*xl)/m12}\[Transpose]
        ] // Sort // If[x1 <= x2, #, Reverse@#] &
     ]
    ];
```

This last helper function process a single contour of a MeshRegion:

```
AdjustPolygonToGrid[vertices_, grids_, sameTest_] :=
  Module[{positions, lines},
   positions = MapThread[BinPositions[#1, #2, SameTest -> sameTest] &, {vertices\[Transpose], grids}]\[Transpose];
   lines = Apply[NearestIntegersBetween,Transpose[Partition[positions, 2, 1], {1, 3, 2}], {2}];
   lines = MapThread[Extract, {grids, Map[List, lines\[Transpose], {2}]}]\[Transpose];
   MapThread[SegmentGridIntersections[Sequence @@ Flatten@#1, Sequence @@ #2] &, {Partition[vertices, 2, 1], lines}] // Flatten[#, 1] & // Append[#, #[[1]]] &
   ];
```

This main function finally process a whole MeshRegion.

```
AdjustMeshToGrid[meshRegion_, grids_, sameTest_] :=
 Module[{polygons, vertices, map},
  polygons = meshRegion["BoundaryPolygons"][[All, 1]];
  polygons = AdjustPolygonToGrid[#, grids, sameTest] & /@ polygons;

  vertices = DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ polygons];
  map = AssociationThread[vertices, Range@Length@vertices];

  (* Restituisce la mesh adattata *)
  BoundaryMeshRegion[vertices, 
   Sequence @@ Line /@ Map[map, polygons, {2}]]
  ]
```

With thid code there are the results compared to the routine proposed by @Michael E2 on a *uniform* grid.

```
timeAvg = 
  Function[func, 
   Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 
     15}], HoldFirst];

\[CapitalOmega] = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   2 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 2 x y - 2 <= 0 \[And] x^2 + y^2 > .1, {x, y}];
\[CapitalOmega]b = RegionBounds[\[CapitalOmega]];

data = Table[Module[{grids, mesh, n},
    grids = 
     N@Map[range \[Function] 
        Range @@ 
         Append[range, -Subtract @@ range/20/2^k], \[CapitalOmega]b];
    (*grids=Union/@Map[g\[Function]{g[[1]],
    Sequence@@(g[[2;;-2]]RandomReal[{1-.02,1+.02},Length[g]-2]),
    g[[-1]]},grids];*)
    n = Length@First@grids;
    mesh = 
     BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[\[CapitalOmega], 
      MaxCellMeasure -> Mean@Flatten[Differences /@ grids]];
    <|
     "Gridlines Count" -> n,
     "AdjustMeshToGrid" -> (AdjustMeshToGrid[mesh, grids, 
         Abs[#1 - #2] <= 10.^-10 &] // timeAvg),
     "snaptogrid" -> (snaptogrid[mesh, Sequence @@ grids] // timeAvg)
     |>
    ], {k, 0, 10}] // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[
 Values@*Normal /@ {data[
    All, {"Gridlines Count", "AdjustMeshToGrid"}], 
   data[All, {"Gridlines Count", "snaptogrid"}]},
 Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"AdjustMeshToGrid", "snaptogrid"}, 
 Frame -> True, Mesh -> Full, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 FrameTicks -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### FIRST ANSWER

I finally found a relatively short way to do. Not perfect, many special cases should be handled. Michael E2 routine permorms better on small uniform grids. I don't know why but on small random grids the rating is reversed.

I can do:

```
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[\[CapitalOmega]];
polygons = mesh["BoundaryPolygons"][[All, 1]];
polygons = 
  AdjustPolygonToGrid[#, {xg, yg}, Abs[#1 - #2] <= 10^-6 &] & /@ 
   polygons;
vertices = DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ polygons];
verticesMap = AssociationThread[vertices, Range@Length@vertices];
adjustedMesh = BoundaryMeshRegion[vertices, 
 Sequence @@ Line /@ Map[verticesMap, polygons, {2}]];

Graphics[{Opacity[.7], HighlightMesh[adjustedMesh, 0]["Show"][[1]]}, 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> {xg, yg}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Darker[LightGray]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with the main helper's function:

```
AdjustPolygonToGrid[vertices_, grids_, sameTest_] :=
 Module[{positions, v1, p1},
  positions = 
   MapThread[
     BinPositions[#1, #2, 
       SameTest -> sameTest] &, {vertices\[Transpose], 
      grids}]\[Transpose];
  {v1, p1} = {vertices[[1]], positions[[1]]};
  Apply[{v2, p2} \[Function] Module[{lines, vlnew},
         If[AnyTrue[p2, IntegerQ], Sow[v2],
          lines = MapThread[NearestIntegersBetween, {p1, p2}];
          If[lines =!= {{}, {}},
           lines = MapThread[#1[[#2]] &, {grids, lines}];

           lines = 
            RegionUnion @@ 
             Flatten@{InfiniteLine[{#, 0}, {0, 1}] & /@ lines[[1]], 
               InfiniteLine[{0, #}, {1, 0}] & /@ lines[[2]]};

           vlnew = 
            Block[{x, y}, {x, y} /. 
              NSolve[{x, y} \[Element] 
                 Line[{v1, v2}] \[And] {x, y} \[Element] lines, {x, 
                y}, Reals]];

           vlnew = 
            If[OrderedQ[{v1, v2}], Sort[vlnew], Reverse@Sort[vlnew]];
           Sow /@ vlnew;
           ];
          ];
         {v1, p1} = {v2, p2}
         ], RotateLeft@Transpose@{vertices, positions}, {1}] //
      Reap // Last // Last // Append[#, #[[1]]] &
  ]
```

and two simple helper's function:

```
BinPositions[vals_, brakes_, sameTest_] :=
 Map[val \[Function] 
   Catch@Module[{lo = 1, mid, hi = Length[brakes], el, res},
     While[lo <= hi, Which[
       TrueQ@sameTest[val, el = brakes[[mid = Floor[(lo + hi)/2]]]], 
       Throw[mid],
       el > val, hi = mid - 1,
       True, lo = mid + 1]];
     lo - 1/2],
  vals]

NearestIntegersBetween = {m, n} \[Function] 
   Which[#1 < #2, {##}, #1 == #2, {#1}, 
      True, {}] & @@ ({Floor[#1] + 1, Ceiling[#2 - 1]} & @@ 
      Sort[{m, n}]);
```

For example original and ajusted small polygon:

```
polygon = mesh["BoundaryPolygons"][[1, 1]];
AdjustPolygonToGrid[polygon, {xg, yg}, Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-6 &];
Graphics[{
  Opacity[.5], LightGray, Polygon@polygon, Opacity[1],
  Orange, AbsolutePointSize[Large], Point@polygon,
  Blue, Line@%,
  Red, AbsolutePointSize[Medium], Point@%,
  Green, Point@polygon[[1]],
  Yellow, Point@polygon[[2]]},
 PlotRange -> RegionBounds@Line@polygon, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {xg, yg}, GridLinesStyle -> Darker[LightGray]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The overall procedure is a bit slow, also with this simple mesh. Some special cases are not handled (for example if two or more vertices of the original mesh are on the same cell edge).

Comment: I think you may be interested to know that `ToBoundaryMesh` and `ToElementMesh` have an option "BoundaryMeshGenerator" that you can define yourself. So you could use your boundary mesh generator for FEM, for example. If you try that, I'd be very interested to hear about the results. This approach would also allow you to get a quadratic (boundary)mesh. If you try this let me know.

Comment: @user21 This would be probably the best approach, but I suppose it's not easy. Can you give me just an idea of how this is done? Maybe using the idea of kguler we can implement a "ContourPlot" generator, more or less like the builtin "RegionPlot" generator?

Comment: This should not be too hard. In the ref page of `ToBoundaryMesh` in the options section there is a `BoundaryMeshGenerator` section. Have a look there. Your function will get a `NumericalRegion` (also documented) from that you can extract the "Predicates" compute your boundary mesh and package that with `ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates"->coords, "BoundaryElements" ->{...}]` let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @user21 You're right, it's not so hard. Indeed, I previously skipped some part of the documentation of the `"BoundaryMeshGenerator"` option. I used the simplest trick of kguler but with `RegionPlot` instead of `ContourPlot`. If someone interested, I can post another self-answer. I'm concerned about the accuracy of this trick. About builtin `"RegionPlot"` method for `"BoundaryMeshGenerator"` it's stated that "improve" the `RegionPlot` output. Can you give me an idea of what this means?

Comment: I'd very much appreciate  if you could post that! The improvement is two fold: 1) the boundary points are moved back onto the symbolic boundary if possible and the mesh can be second order.

Comment: @user21 ok, I'll do, but please don't expect so much...

Answer (score 4):

Building on the trick of kguler and on the @user21 recommendations I ends up with the following approach.

For many reason my actual interest is on first-order meshes and on a `MeshRegion`-type output. However, I used the some services of FEM toolbox and particularly of `NumericalRegion`.

- Its `"BoundaryFunction"` property with `FindRoot` is useful to "improve" `RegionPlot` output. I don't know if we can easily build this compiled function directly from a generic `Region`.
- For some misterious (for me) reason, the output of `RegionPlot[numericalRegion["Predicates"], ...]` appears more accurate than `RegionPlot[symbolicRegion, ...]`. This turns out to be very important to get a valid `MeshRegion` with the actual implementation because...

In the `RegionPlot` output improvement phase boundary vertices are moved, and a boundary vertex can cross a mesh line. So, at some times we need to reorder the vertices on a boundary, otherwise we can get an invalid / self-crossing boundary. This becomes a problem for fine meshes (in the following samples for `Mesh` option >= 50. A more accurate `RegionPlot` output is helpful to reduce the need of reordering.

I'd appreciate any suggestion to detect and fix this problem and to improve the whole implementation.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`

Options[ConstrainedRegionPlotMeshGenerator] = {Mesh -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> Automatic};
ConstrainedRegionPlotMeshGenerator[region_NumericalRegion, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ConstrainedRegionPlotMeshGeneratorCore[region, opts] // ToBoundaryMesh
ConstrainedRegionPlotMeshGenerator[region_ /; ConstantRegionQ[region],
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ConstrainedRegionPlotMeshGeneratorCore[ToNumericalRegion@region, opts]

ConstrainedRegionPlotMeshGeneratorCore[region_NumericalRegion, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{g, mptsx, mptsy, mpts, blns, mptq, grids, xg, yg, \[Delta], 
    pts, ptsx, ptsy, x, y},

   (* draw region with RegionPlot and extract the GraphicsComplex *)
   g = First@RegionPlot[
      (*region["SymbolicRegion"],*)
      region["Predicates"],
      Evaluate[
       Sequence @@ 
        MapThread[
         Prepend, {region["Bounds"], region["PredicateVariables"]}]],
      Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Red, 
      MeshStyle -> Blue,
      Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, {Mesh, PlotPoints, MaxRecursion}]];

   (* get mesh lines endpoints and boundary lines *) 
   {mptsx, mptsy} = 
    Union @@@ 
     Cases[g, {Blue, lines___Line} :> {lines}, \[Infinity]][[All, All,
        1, {1, -1}]];
   If[Intersection[mptsx, mptsy] =!= {}, Return[$Failed]]; (* 
   Unsupported at present *)
   mpts = DeleteDuplicates@Join[mptsx, mptsy];
   blns = 
    Cases[g, {Directive[___, Red, ___], lines___Line} :> 
      lines, \[Infinity]];

   (* build closed boundary lines selecting boundary lines vertices \
that are also on mesh lines *)
   mptq = AssociationThread[mpts, Range@Length@mpts];
   blns = Map[DeleteMissing[mptq /@ #] &, blns, {2}];
   blns = 
    Map[If[Last@# == First@#, #, Append[#, First@#]] &, blns, {2}];

   (* improve  boundary vertices position *)
   \[Delta] = region["BoundaryFunction"];
   ptsx = {#[[1]], 
       y /. FindRoot[\[Delta][{#[[1]], y}], {y, #[[2]]}]} & /@ 
     g[[1, mptsx]];
   ptsy = {x /. 
        FindRoot[\[Delta][{x, #[[2]]}], {x, #[[1]]}], #[[2]]} & /@ 
     g[[1, mptsy]];
   pts = Join[ptsx, ptsy];

   (* build result*)
   BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, Sequence @@ blns]
   ];
```

For example, with a uniform mesh, and a `MeshRegion` output:

```
ConstrainedRegionPlotMeshGenerator[\[CapitalOmega], Mesh -> {5, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With an explicit, non-uniform grid, and a `MeshRegion` output:

```
Show[
 ConstrainedRegionPlotMeshGenerator[\[CapitalOmega], Mesh -> grids],
 GridLines -> grids, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With an explicit, non-uniform grid, and an `ElementMesh` output:

```
mesh = ToBoundaryMesh[\[CapitalOmega], 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {ConstrainedRegionPlotMeshGenerator, 
    Mesh -> grids}]

Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"],
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements"]],
 GridLines -> grids, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very cool! Thanks for sharing. That's very helpful for me to understand what and if the functionality in the FEM context get's used. If you have suggestions for improving functionality / documentation in the FEM context let me know