# Pick elements from list "separately"

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list I want to pick elements from:

```
mylist = {1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 9, 1, 10, 12, 2, 64, 34, 64}
```

I have another list with 0's and 1's which is my selector:

```
selector = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
```

I want to select all the entries from `mylist` where `selector` has a 1. I know I can do this via:

```
Pick[mylist,selector,1]
```

BUT: Pick gives me all the selected elements from `mylist` together like this:

```
{1, 5, 7, 7, 2, 9, 1, 10, 34, 64}
```

I want the elements which are separated in `selector` by a 0 to be separate lists. That is, as a result I want to have a list of lists like this:

```
{{1,5,7},{7,2},{9,1,10},{34,64}}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
mylist = {1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 9, 1, 10, 12, 2, 64, 34, 64};
selector = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};

pick = Pick[mylist, selector, 1];

split = Length /@ Cases[Split[selector], {1 ...}]
```

> {3, 2, 3, 2}

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[pick, split]
```

> {{1, 5, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 1, 10}, {34, 64}}

Comment: Interesting solution, never would have thought of that :). Thanks very much!

Answer (score 20):

You can combine [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`Take`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html), and [`SequencePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html):

```
Map[Take[mylist, #] &,
 SequencePosition[selector, {1 ..}, Overlaps -> False]]

(* {{1, 5, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 1, 10}, {34, 64}} *)
```

Comment: I should upgrade :)

Answer (score 18):

Because your selector is 0 or 1, `SplitBy` can be used as follows.

```
Select[SplitBy[mylist*selector, Positive], #[[1]] > 0 &]
```

Comment: `Select[SplitBy[mylist*selector, # != 0 &], #[[1]] != 0 &]` would also work for negative numbers - +1 anyway

Answer (score 13):

You can find positions where differences of `selector` is nonzero. Then you can take corresponding sublists. This straightforward solution is relatively fast (two times faster then eldo's solution, which is already very efficient)

```
list = {1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 9, 1, 10, 12, 2, 64, 34, 64};
selector = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};

pick[list_, sel_] := 
  Take[list, #] & /@ Transpose@{#[[;; ;; 2]], #[[2 ;; ;; 2]] - 1} &@
     Pick[Range@Length@#, #, 1] &@Abs@Differences@Join[{0}, sel, {0}];

pick[list, selector]
(* {{1, 5, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 1, 10}, {34, 64}} *)

n = 1000000;
list = RandomInteger[100, n];
selector = RandomInteger[1, n];

pick[list, selector]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.706, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Map[Take[mylist, #] &, 
 Map[Flatten[#] &, 
   FindClusters[Position[selector, 1]]] //. {w___, {q_, __, x_}, 
    k___} :> {w, {q, x}, k}]

{{1, 5, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 1, 10}, {34, 64}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 SequenceSplit[mylist selector,{0}]

 (* {{1, 5, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 1, 10}, {34, 64}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Lots of nice answers already but coming to this question late here are my ideas.

Application of Szabolcs's [How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/121#21344) with adaptations:

```
fn1[a_, b_] :=
  a[[#]] & /@ SplitBy[Range@Length@a, b[[#]] &][[2 - b[[1]] ;; ;; 2]]
```

Application of my `intervals` from [Find continuous sequences inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121#23623) (load it first)

```
fn2[a_, b_] :=
  Take[a, #] & /@ intervals @ SparseArray[b]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

Test:

```
fn1[mylist, selector]

fn2[mylist, selector]
```

> ```
> {{1, 5, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 1, 10}, {34, 64}}
>
> {{1, 5, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 1, 10}, {34, 64}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mylist = {1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 9, 1, 10, 12, 2, 64, 34, 64};
selector = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};

lens = Map[Length]@Split[selector];
pos = Position[Split[selector], {1 ..}];
Extract[TakeList[mylist, lens], pos]
```

> {{1, 5, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 1, 10}, {34, 64}}

Answer (score 3):

```
f = Internal`CopyListStructure[Split @ #2, #][[2 - First @ #2 ;; ;; 2]] &;


f[mylist, selector]
```

> ```
> {{1, 5, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 1, 10}, {34, 64}}
> ```