# Interpolating four-dimensional data

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

In this case it is not easy to work with a MWE, so I shall use the actual [data](http://www.mediafire.com/file/wwxt5crdzb2605b/4D_3200.dat) which contain initial conditions $(x,y,p_x,p_y)$.

Let's see how the data look on the $(x,y)$ plane

```
data = Import["4D_3200.dat", "Table"];
d0 = data[[All, {1, 2}]];
L0 = ListPlot[d0, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.001]}]
```

[image]

It is seen that the data are not random but they fill an oval region. The data file contains about 21000 initial conditions.

**Question #1:** How can I generate, let's say 100000, random $(x,y)$ initial conditions inside the oval region of the above plot?

**Question #2:** Assuming that we have generated 100000 $(x,y)$ initial conditions, inside the oval region, how can we exploit the original data in order to interpolate the momenta $p_x$ and $p_y$ of the additional initial conditions?

In other words, we have an initial distribution of $N$ four-dimensional initial conditions and we want to generate more $N'$.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are px and py dependent variables? What is the relationship between them?

Comment: @MikeY There is no known relationship between the momenta. The values of the initial data file should be used for the interpolation.

Comment: OK, but is it px = px(x,y) and py = py(x,y)?

Comment: @MikeY Perhaps, but I am not sure!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before doing anything, you have to remove any duplicate $(x,y)$ pairs from your data.  Interpolating functions don't like double-valued functions.  10 of your points are like these two:

```
data[[{3197, 3250}]]
(* {{10.20913`, -0.18115`, -0.15105`, 50.42686`}, 
    {10.20913`, -0.18115`, -0.15105`, 50.42685`}} *)
```

So just throw out the duplicates via

```
data = DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, #[[;; 2]] &];
xy = data[[All, ;; 2]];
```

> How can I generate, let's say 100000, random (x,y) initial conditions inside the oval region of the above plot?

You can define the oval region using `ConvexHullMesh`, and then use `RandomPoint` to generate your points.

```
xy = data[[All, ;; 2]];
pts = RandomPoint[ConvexHullMesh[xy], 100000];
Graphics[{Point[pts], Red, Point[xy]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Assuming that we have generated 100000 (x,y) initial conditions, inside the oval region, how can we exploit the original data in order to interpolate the momenta $p_x$ and $p_y$ of the additional initial conditions?

Now just make your interpolation functions. You need to set the `InterpolationOrder` to 1 because the $(x,y)$ points don't lie on a rectangular grid.  Check the documentation for [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) to see why you have to rearrange the list structure.

```
px = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ data, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
py = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #4} & @@@ data, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

and generate the new data via

```
newData = {#1, #2, px[##], py[##]} & @@@ pts;
```

Here is the new data (in blue) along with the old data (in red) for the px variable

```
Graphics3D[{
  Red, PointSize@Medium, Point[data[[All, ;; 3]]],
  Blue, PointSize@Small, Point[
   newData[[All, ;; 3]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit** If you are working in an older version of *Mathematica*, before there was a `ConvexHullMesh` or `RandomPoint`, you can still make this work, but the only way I could think was to use rejection sampling to get the new data points.

```
positionDuplicates[list_] := 
    Flatten[Rest /@ GatherBy[Range@Length[list], list[[#]] &]]; 
data = ReplacePart[data, 
    Thread[positionDuplicates[data[[All, ;; 2]]] -> Sequence[]]]; 
xy = data[[All, ;; 2]]; 
px = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ data, InterpolationOrder -> 1]; 
py = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #4} & @@@ data, InterpolationOrder -> 1]; 
range = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ Transpose[xy]; 
pointsBeta = Transpose[{ 
    RandomReal[First@range, 100000], 
    RandomReal[Last@range, 100000] 
    } 
]; 
pgon = Polygon[ 
    data[[Graphics`Mesh`ConvexHull[xy], ;; 2]] 
]; 
pts = Select[pointsBeta, Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[pgon, #] &];
newData = {#1, #2, px[##], py[##]} & @@@ pts; 

Graphics3D[{ 
    Red, PointSize@Medium, Point[data[[All, ;; 3]]], 
    Blue, PointSize@Small, Point[ newData[[All, ;; 3]]]
    }, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

should give the same result, but only giving 80,000 points instead of 100,000.  Code borrowed and adapted from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9408/9490) and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/9490).

Comment: It works like a charm! Many thanks! Just out of curiosity, is this task doable using v9?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z - the first thing I notice is that you need to use the **much** slower `DeleteDuplicates[data, #1[[;; 2]] === #2[[;; 2]] &]` since you don't have `DeleteDuplicatesBy`

Comment: Is this the only change in v9?

Comment: checking now - to be honest, using that form of `DeleteDuplicates` on a list this big was taking so long I abandoned it.

Comment: `RandomPoint` and `ConvexHullMesh` are not recognized in v9.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z - you can get rid of the duplicates efficiently using `positionDuplicates[list_] := 
  Flatten[Rest /@ GatherBy[Range@Length[list], list[[#]] &]];
data = ReplacePart[data, 
   Thread[positionDuplicates[data[[All, ;; 2]]] -> Sequence[]]];` - and the interpolating functions generate just fine.  But you don't have access to `RandomPoint` or `ConvexHullMesh`, so you need another way to generate the points.

Comment: Any alternative for `RandomPoint`  and `ConvexHullMesh`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57645/discussion-between-jason-b-and-vaggelis-z).

Comment: @Vaggelis, you're already two versions behind; next time, please mention at the outset that you're using an older version.

Answer (score 2):

For the random generation part, once you have an interpolation function you can actually just let the interpolation function tell you when points are out of the region:

```
points = Select[ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {200, 3}], 
                Norm[#[[1 ;; 2]]] < 1 &];
int = Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
random = DeleteCases[
   Quiet@Check[Append[#, int @@ #], "Fail"] & /@
    RandomReal[{Min@Flatten[points], Max@Flatten[points]}, {2000, 2}],
     "Fail"];
Show[{
  ConvexHullMesh[points[[All, 1 ;; 2]]],
  Graphics@Point[random[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]}]
```

[image]

note I used `ConvexHullMesh` here only for the illustration graphic.