# Determining lists with equal elements in the same position

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to define a function with the following properties:
Given a list of equal length sub-lists

```
ls={{a,a,a},{a,b,a},{a,b,c}};
```

Define a function

```
Slort[ls,1]
```

to return

```
{{1,2,3}} (* all three sub-lists have the same first element *)

Slort[ls,2]
{{1},{2,3}} (* sub-lists 2 and 3 have the same second element, sub-list 1 is unique *)

Slort[ls,3]
{{1,2},{3}} (* sub-list 1 and 2 have the same third element, sub-list 3 is unique *)
```

and etc.

With your help I should then be able to extend the number of sub-lists and the number of elements in each sub-list myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is a generalized version of the question [How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/125). The following is a generalization of [this answer by Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/125):

```
ClearAll[Slort]
Slort[lst_, pos_] := GatherBy[Range@Length@lst, lst[[#, pos]] &]
```

**Examples:**

```
ls = {{a, a, a}, {a, b, a}, {a, b, c}};

Slort[ls, #]& /@ Range[3]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}}, {{1}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {3}}}

```
SeedRandom[1]
ls2 = RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d}, {10, 5}];

Slort[ls2, #] & /@ Range[5] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Phillip, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

A late alternative to `kglr`s elegant solution:

```
list = {{a, a, a}, {a, b, a}, {a, b, c}};

Slort[lst_, pos_] :=
   Flatten /@ GroupBy[First -> Last] @ MapIndexed[List] @ Transpose[lst][[pos]]

Slort[list, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3} // TableForm
```

[image]

We can use `Values` to get the desired output form:

```
Values @ Slort[list, 2]
```

> {{1}, {2, 3}}

**Update**

Since V10 we can use `PositionIndex`:

```
Slort2[lst_, pos_] := Map[Values@*PositionIndex][Transpose@lst][[pos]]
```

Comment: Nice.  A slight variant on Slort2 (which I hope I have got right on this third attempt): `slort2[lst_, pos_] := (PositionIndex@(Transpose@lst)[[pos]] // Values)`.