# How to get a description of the positions of similar elements in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I want to find a function `F` to represent the positions of identical elements in a list, which means, for example:

- `F[{5,6,5,7}]={{1,3},{2},{4}}`
- `F[{5,6,6,5}]={{1,4},{2,3}}`
- `F[{5,7,5,5}]={{1,3,4},{2}}`
- `F[{5,6,7,8}]={{1},{2},{3},{4}}`
- `F[{5,5,5,5}]={{1,2,3,4}}`

etc. Is there any function or implementation?

Moreover, I want to use this into an $\underbrace{n\times n\times\cdots\times n}_m$ Table `t[n_,m_]` (so the dimension $m$ is also an input of `t`), such that

- `t[[i_1,...,i_m]]=Subscript[x,F[{i_1,...,i_m}]]`

where $1\le i_1,\cdots,i_m\le n$. How can I implement it?

Thanks :)

Comment: What is a "partition situation of a list"?  Your example is unclear.  Give an *explanation* as well as examples.

Comment: Ohhh.... *position* situation (not *partition* situation)!  Got it!

Comment: Thanks for your edit! Indeed I don't know how to describe it accurately.

Comment: The first part of this question is a duplicate of [How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/125)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the positions of the same elements in a list you can use [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html)

```
f[x_] := Values@PositionIndex[x]
```

Test:

```
f[{5,6,5,7}]
f[{5,6,6,5}]
```

> {{1,3},{2},{4}}
>
> {{1,4},{2,3}}

Comment: To make it more simple, try `f=Values@*PositionIndex`

Comment: @Wjx Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
F[list_]:=Values @ GroupBy[
    AssociationThread[Range@Length@list, list],
    Identity,
    Keys
]
```

Your examples:

```
F[{5,6,5,7}]
F[{5,6,6,5}]
F[{5,7,5,5}]
F[{5,6,7,8}]
F[{5,5,5,5}]
```

> {{1, 3}, {2}, {4}}
>
> {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}
>
> {{1, 3, 4}, {2}}
>
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}
>
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[lst_] := GatherBy[Range @ Length @ lst, lst[[#]]&]
(* or  f[lst_] := Values @ GroupBy[Range @ Length @ lst, lst[[#]]&] *)

mat = {{5, 6, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 6, 5}, {5, 7, 5, 5}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 5, 5, 5}};
Grid[Prepend[{#, f@#} & /@ mat, {"list", "f[list]"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
Subscript[x, f@#] & /@ mat
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Values @ Merge[Flatten] @ MapIndexed[Rule[##] &] @ {5, 7, 5, 5}
```

{{1, 3, 4}, {2}}

Answer (score 1):

```
f[k_List] := 
 Flatten[#, 1] &@Position[k, #] & /@ (k // DeleteDuplicates)

mat = {{5, 6, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 6, 5}, {5, 7, 5, 5}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 5, 
    5, 5}}; (* borrowed *)

{#, f@#} & /@ mat // Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]