# Position of intersection of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the two lists:

```
s1 ={0.,0.00333333,0.00666667,0.01,0.0133333,0.0166667,0.02,0.0233333,0.0266667,0.03,0.0333333,0.0366667,0.04,0.0433333,0.0466667,0.05,0.0533333,0.0566667,0.06,0.0633333,0.0666667,0.07,0.0733333,0.0766667,0.08,0.0833333,0.0866667,0.09,0.0933333,0.0966667,0.1,0.103333,0.106667,0.11,0.113333,0.116667,0.12,0.123333,0.126667,0.13,0.133333,0.136667,0.14,0.143333,0.146667,0.15,0.153333,0.156667,0.16,0.163333,0.166667,0.17,0.173333,0.176667,0.18,0.183333,0.186667,0.19,0.193333,0.196667,0.2,0.203333,0.206667,0.21,0.213333,0.216667,0.22,0.223333,0.226667,0.23,0.233333,0.236667,0.24,0.243333,0.246667,0.25,0.253333,0.256667,0.26,0.263333,0.266667,0.27,0.273333,0.276667,0.28,0.283333,0.286667,0.29,0.293333,0.296667,0.3,0.303333,0.306667,0.31,0.313333,0.316667,0.32,0.323333,0.326667,0.33,0.333333,0.336667,0.34,0.343333,0.346667,0.35,0.353333,0.356667,0.36,0.363333,0.366667,0.37,0.373333,0.376667,0.38,0.383333,0.386667,0.39,0.393333,0.396667,0.4,0.403333,0.406667,0.41,0.413333,0.416667,0.42,0.423333,0.426667,0.43,0.433333,0.436667,0.44,0.443333,0.446667,0.45,0.453333,0.456667,0.46,0.463333,0.466667,0.47,0.473333,0.476667,0.48,0.483333,0.486667,0.49,0.493333,0.496667,0.5,0.503333,0.506667,0.51,0.513333,0.516667,0.52,0.523333,0.526667,0.53,0.533333,0.536667,0.54,0.543333,0.546667,0.55,0.553333,0.556667,0.56,0.563333,0.566667,0.57,0.573333,0.576667,0.58,0.583333,0.586667,0.59,0.593333,0.596667,0.6,0.603333,0.606667,0.61,0.613333,0.616667,0.62,0.623333,0.626667,0.63,0.633333,0.636667,0.64,0.643333,0.646667,0.65,0.653333,0.656667,0.66,0.663333};
```

and

```
s2={0.,0.00222222,0.00444444,0.00666667,0.00888889,0.0111111,0.0133333,0.0155556,0.0177778,0.02,0.0222222,0.0244444,0.0266667,0.0288889,0.0311111,0.0333333,0.0355556,0.0377778,0.04,0.0422222,0.0444444,0.0466667,0.0488889,0.0511111,0.0533333,0.0555556,0.0577778,0.06,0.0622222,0.0644444,0.0666667,0.0688889,0.0711111,0.0733333,0.0755556,0.0777778,0.08,0.0822222,0.0844444,0.0866667,0.0888889,0.0911111,0.0933333,0.0955556,0.0977778,0.1,0.102222,0.104444,0.106667,0.108889,0.111111,0.113333,0.115556,0.117778,0.12,0.122222,0.124444,0.126667,0.128889,0.131111,0.133333,0.135556,0.137778,0.14,0.142222,0.144444,0.146667,0.148889,0.151111,0.153333,0.155556,0.157778,0.16,0.162222,0.164444,0.166667,0.168889,0.171111,0.173333,0.175556,0.177778,0.18,0.182222,0.184444,0.186667,0.188889,0.191111,0.193333,0.195556,0.197778,0.2,0.202222,0.204444,0.206667,0.208889,0.211111,0.213333,0.215556,0.217778,0.22,0.222222,0.224444,0.226667,0.228889,0.231111,0.233333,0.235556,0.237778,0.24,0.242222,0.244444,0.246667,0.248889,0.251111,0.253333,0.255556,0.257778,0.26,0.262222,0.264444,0.266667,0.268889,0.271111,0.273333,0.275556,0.277778,0.28,0.282222,0.284444,0.286667,0.288889,0.291111,0.293333,0.295556,0.297778,0.3,0.302222,0.304444,0.306667,0.308889,0.311111,0.313333,0.315556,0.317778,0.32,0.322222,0.324444,0.326667,0.328889,0.331111,0.333333,0.335556,0.337778,0.34,0.342222,0.344444,0.346667,0.348889,0.351111,0.353333,0.355556,0.357778,0.36,0.362222,0.364444,0.366667,0.368889,0.371111,0.373333,0.375556,0.377778,0.38,0.382222,0.384444,0.386667,0.388889,0.391111,0.393333,0.395556,0.397778,0.4,0.402222,0.404444,0.406667,0.408889,0.411111,0.413333,0.415556,0.417778,0.42,0.422222,0.424444,0.426667,0.428889,0.431111,0.433333,0.435556,0.437778,0.44,0.442222};
```

I want to find the intersection of the two lists and the position of the elements of intersection in each list, something like this:

{{p1 (element of intersection), g1 (position of p1 in s1), h1 (position of p1 in s2), {.....}, {......}......} 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can `s1` and `s2` have repeated entries?

Comment: @J.M.  NO. Elements are distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{#, Position[s1, #][[1, 1]], Position[s2, #][[1, 1]]} & /@ Intersection[s1, s2]
```

This finds the set of elements in the Intersection, and then makes a list with 1) each such element, 2) that element's location in list s1, and 3) that element's location in s2.

If there are repeated entries of an intersection element, use this:

```
{#, Position[s1, #], Position[s2, #]} & /@ Intersection[s1, s2]
```

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using a modification of @Szabolcs's [`positionDuplicates`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/125) in [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/125)

```
ClearAll[intersectionAndPositions]
intersectionAndPositions = Module[{l = Length@#, s = Join[##], g}, 
  g = Mod[Select[GatherBy[Range[Length@s], s[[#]] &], Length@# >= 2 &], l, 1]; 
  {s[[#[[1]]]], #} & /@ g] &;

intersectionAndPositions [s1, s2] // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] & // TeXForm
```

> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
>  0. & \{1,1\} \\
> \hline
>  0.00666667 & \{3,4\} \\
> \hline
>  0.0133333 & \{5,7\} \\
> \hline
>  0.02 & \{7,10\} \\
> \hline
>  0.0266667 & \{9,13\} \\
> \hline
>  0.0333333 & \{11,16\} \\
> \hline
>  0.04 & \{13,19\} \\
> \hline
>  0.0466667 & \{15,22\} \\
> \hline
>  0.0533333 & \{17,25\} \\
> \hline
>  0.06 & \{19,28\} \\
> \hline
>  0.0666667 & \{21,31\} \\
> \hline
>  0.0733333 & \{23,34\} \\
> \hline
>  0.08 & \{25,37\} \\
> \hline
>  0.0866667 & \{27,40\} \\
> \hline
>  0.0933333 & \{29,43\} \\
> \hline
>  0.1 & \{31,46\} \\
> \hline
>  0.106667 & \{33,49\} \\
> \hline
>  0.113333 & \{35,52\} \\
> \hline
>  0.12 & \{37,55\} \\
> \hline
>  0.126667 & \{39,58\} \\
> \hline
>  0.133333 & \{41,61\} \\
> \hline
>  0.14 & \{43,64\} \\
> \hline
>  0.146667 & \{45,67\} \\
> \hline
>  0.153333 & \{47,70\} \\
> \hline
>  0.16 & \{49,73\} \\
> \hline
>  0.166667 & \{51,76\} \\
> \hline
>  0.173333 & \{53,79\} \\
> \hline
>  0.18 & \{55,82\} \\
> \hline
>  0.186667 & \{57,85\} \\
> \hline
>  0.193333 & \{59,88\} \\
> \hline
>  0.2 & \{61,91\} \\
> \hline
>  0.206667 & \{63,94\} \\
> \hline
>  0.213333 & \{65,97\} \\
> \hline
>  0.22 & \{67,100\} \\
> \hline
>  0.226667 & \{69,103\} \\
> \hline
>  0.233333 & \{71,106\} \\
> \hline
>  0.24 & \{73,109\} \\
> \hline
>  0.246667 & \{75,112\} \\
> \hline
>  0.253333 & \{77,115\} \\
> \hline
>  0.26 & \{79,118\} \\
> \hline
>  0.266667 & \{81,121\} \\
> \hline
>  0.273333 & \{83,124\} \\
> \hline
>  0.28 & \{85,127\} \\
> \hline
>  0.286667 & \{87,130\} \\
> \hline
>  0.293333 & \{89,133\} \\
> \hline
>  0.3 & \{91,136\} \\
> \hline
>  0.306667 & \{93,139\} \\
> \hline
>  0.313333 & \{95,142\} \\
> \hline
>  0.32 & \{97,145\} \\
> \hline
>  0.326667 & \{99,148\} \\
> \hline
>  0.333333 & \{101,151\} \\
> \hline
>  0.34 & \{103,154\} \\
> \hline
>  0.346667 & \{105,157\} \\
> \hline
>  0.353333 & \{107,160\} \\
> \hline
>  0.36 & \{109,163\} \\
> \hline
>  0.366667 & \{111,166\} \\
> \hline
>  0.373333 & \{113,169\} \\
> \hline
>  0.38 & \{115,172\} \\
> \hline
>  0.386667 & \{117,175\} \\
> \hline
>  0.393333 & \{119,178\} \\
> \hline
>  0.4 & \{121,181\} \\
> \hline
>  0.406667 & \{123,184\} \\
> \hline
>  0.413333 & \{125,187\} \\
> \hline
>  0.42 & \{127,190\} \\
> \hline
>  0.426667 & \{129,193\} \\
> \hline
>  0.433333 & \{131,196\} \\
> \hline
>  0.44 & \{133,199\} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$$

Comment: Excellent (+1) but this code gives ambiguous output when a list contains repeated entries in the intersection.  (Admittedly, the OP precludes such cases.)

Comment: @kglr Thanks for your input.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, thank you for the vote. For the repeated entries case, you can `SplitBy` the index set  before applying `Mod`.

Comment: @qahtah, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

```
Merge[Apply @ Join] @ KeyIntersection[PositionIndex /@ {s1, s2}];

Dataset[%, MaxItems -> 6]
```

[image]

Convert to list (if wanted)

```
KeyValueMap[List][%%][[1 ;; 6]]
```

{{0., {1, 1}}, {0.00666667, {3, 4}}, {0.0133333, {5, 7}}, {0.02, {7,
10}}, {0.0266667, {9, 13}}, {0.0333333, {11, 16}}}

Answer (score 1):

FWIW:

```
dm = DistanceMatrix[s1, s2];
pos = Position[dm, 0.];
Grid[{s1[[#[[1]]]], #} & /@ pos, Frame -> All]
```

[image]