# Randomly distribute numbers to lists

Tags: list-manipulation, random, education

I have 4 empty lists. I would like to randomly distribute numbers from 1 to 10 to these 4 empty lists. How can I add integers to lists randomly?

For example:

```
m = {};
n = {};
p = {};
r = {};
listz = Range[10];
```

1->m , 2->n , 3->p , 4->m , 5->r , 6->r, 7->n , 8->m, 9->p , 10->n (Randomly distributed)

Here is the code I tried:

```
m = {};
n = {};
p = {};
r = {};
listz = Range[10];
s = RandomChoice[{m, n, p, r}, 4];
Do[listm = AppendTo[s, listz[i]];, {i, 1, 10}]
listm
```

Wanted Solution:(Randomly distributed)

```
m = {1, 5, 8}
n = {4, 6, 9}
p = {7, 10}
r = {2, 3}
```

Comment: Why not just generate four random lists in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on Mathematica 11.3

```
(R=RandomSample)[Range@10,10]~TakeList~R@RandomChoice[Select[IntegerPartitions@10,Length@#==4&]]
```

Also I tried to fix **your** code

```
a = {};
b = {};
c = {};
d = {};
Listz = {a, b, c, d};
Do[t=RandomChoice@Range@4;Listz[[t]]=AppendTo[Listz[[t]],i],{i,1,10}]
Listz
```

Comment: Have you tried that with a list of 100 elements?

Comment: how about 10^100?

Comment: @J42161217 Because `Select[IntegerPartitions@10, Length@# == 4 &] `sorted, you cannot get Lenght=1or 2 set for m.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci fixed!

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 100;
m = 4;
list = Range[n];
s = RandomChoice[Range[m], n];

SparseArray[Transpose[{s, list}] -> _, {m, n}]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

Or slower, but easier to understand:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[Transpose[{s, list}], First -> Last], Range[m]]
```

Comment: Is this supposed to spew errors in 11.3?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Please try again.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what sparsearray function does here. But thanks this code is working.

Comment: Well, you might inspect `MatrixForm@Normal[SparseArray[Transpose[{s, listz}] -> _, {mm, nn}]]` to find that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
listz = CharacterRange["A", "K"];
k = 4;

SeedRandom[1]
rc = RandomChoice[Range @ k, Length @ listz];
{m, n, p, r} = Pick[listz, rc, #]& /@ Range[k]
```

> {{"C", "F", "G", "H", "K"}, {"B", "D", "E", "I"}, {}, {"A", "J"}}

Also

```
Lookup[GroupBy[Transpose[{rc, listz}], First -> Last], #, {}]& /@ Range[k] 
AdjacencyList[Graph[Range[k], Thread[rc -> listz]], # ] & /@ Range[k]
```

both give the same result. Also, using Carl Woll's [`GatherByList`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163056/125):

```
RandomSample[PadRight[GatherByList[listz, rc], {k, Automatic}, {}]]
```

> {{"A", "J"}, {}, {"C", "F", "G", "H", "K"}, {"B", "D", "E", "I"}}

**Update:** To get `k` non-empty sublists:

```
SeedRandom[1]
rc = Module[{r}, While[Length[Counts[r = RandomChoice[Range@k, Length @ listz]]] < k]; r];

Pick[listz , rc, # ] & /@ Range[k]
Lookup[GroupBy[Transpose[{rc , listz}], First -> Last], #, {}] & /@ Range[k] 
AdjacencyList[Graph[Range[k], Thread[rc -> listz]], # ] & /@ Range[k]
```

all give

> {{"A", "B", "C", "E", "H", "I"}, {"F"}, {"D", "G"}, {"J", "K"}}

```
GatherByList[listz, rc]
```

> {{"A", "B", "C", "E", "H", "I"}, {"D", "G"}, {"F"}, {"J", "K"}}

**Update 2:**

You can  also use the function `RandomKSetPartition` from the `Combinatorica` package:

```
Quiet @ Needs["Combinatorica`"]
SeedRandom[1] 
RandomKSetPartition[listz, 4]
```

> {{"A", "D", "H"}, {"B"}, {"C", "F", "J", "K"}, {"E", "G", "I"}}

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`MultinomialDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultinomialDistribution) of a random sample? For example:

```
rand[n_, s_] := TakeList[
    RandomSample[Range[n]],
    RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[n, ConstantArray[1/s, s]]]
]

rand[10, 4]
```

> {{4, 6, 1}, {2}, {5, 9, 8, 7, 3}, {10}}

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**  I realized that my previous solution doesn't produce the same length partitions. Here is the desired solution.

```
s = RandomSample[Range@10, 10];
t = RandomSample@RandomChoice@IntegerPartitions[10, {4}]
{m, n, p, r} = TakeList[s, t]

(*or {m, n, p, r} = FoldPairList[TakeDrop, s, t]*)
```

> {{1, 5, 10}, {3, 7}, {2, 9, 6, 8}, {4}}

**Original answer:**

```
s = RandomSample[Range@10, 10];
t = RandomSample[Range@4, 4];
{m, n, p, r} = FoldPairList[TakeDrop, s, t]
```

> {{6, 2}, {9}, {5, 1, 7}, {10, 3, 8, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

A fast and short way is to utilize `Pick`. For this, we will need two commands:

```
ClearAll[distribute];
distribute[list_, partNum_] := RandomInteger[partNum - 1, Length@list]
```

creates a number sequence which will assign each element to a list. And we do this with

```
ClearAll[splitList];
splitList[list_, partitionNumber_] := With[
     {selection = distribute[list, partitionNumber]}, 
     Table[Pick[list, selection, i], {i, 0, partitionNumber - 1}]
]
```

That's it. The code is fast enough; on my laptop, it takes less than half a second to split a list of $10^7$ elements into 3 lists:

```
splitList[Range[10^7], 3] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.42,...} *)
```

It becomes slower if the number of list increases, as it is not optimized in that direction. Still, it should be fast enough, for example:

```
splitList[Range[10^7], 10^3] // RepeatedTiming
(* {8.3,...} *)
```