# Find the identical rows in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
M = 
 {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}; 

TableForm[M, TableHeadings -> {{S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8}}]
```

[image: matrix]

In this case, it turns out that rows (S1, S8), (S2, S3, S4), (S5, S6, S7) have equal element values in identical column positions. I have a 1000 x 1000 matrix to examine and would appreciate any assistance in coding this problem.

Comment: Try `Values[PositionIndex[M]]`

Comment: @Coolwater If there is a unique row, your method will fail. At least one needs to delete if list has length 1

Comment: @Coolwater IMHO, the best answer is lacking so far. Please consider posting `PositionIndex` as possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `GroupBy`.

First the names of the rows: can be anything you like, for example

```
rownames = Array[ToExpression["S" <> ToString[#]] &, Length[M]]
```

> {S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8}

Next the grouping:

```
groups = GroupBy[Thread[rownames -> M], Last -> First]
```

> <|{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} -> {S1, S8},
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0} -> {S2, S3, S4},
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0} -> {S5, S6, S7}|>

If all you need are the names:

```
Values[groups]
```

> {{S1, S8}, {S2, S3, S4}, {S5, S6, S7}}

Answer (score 8):

```
idx = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Nearest[M -> Automatic, M, {∞, 0}]]
```

> {{1, 8}, {2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}}

In order to obtain the labels of the rows, you may use the following:

```
labels = {S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8};
Map[labels[[#]] &, idx, {2}]
```

> {{S1, S8}, {S2, S3, S4}, {S5, S6, S7}}

Comment: Henrik: Can I add the S in front of the result; e.g.,  (S1,S8),(S3,S4),(S5,S6,S7)?

Comment: MANY THANKS, HENRIK!

Comment: YOU'RE WELCOME, PRG! =D

Answer (score 6):

The function `positionDuplicates []` from [How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-to-efficiently-find-positions-of-duplicates) does the job, faster than `Nearest`.

```
(* Henrik's method *)
posDupes[M_] := DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Nearest[M -> Automatic, M, {∞, 0}]]

SeedRandom[0];  (* to make a reproducible 1000 x 1000 matrix *)
foo = Nest[RandomInteger[1, {1000, 1000}] # &, 1, 9];

d1 = Cases[positionDuplicates[foo], dupe_ /; Length[dupe] > 1]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.017, Null}  *)

d2 = Cases[posDupes[foo], dupe_ /; Length[dupe] > 1]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.060, Null}  *)

d1 == d2
(*  True  *)

d1
(*
  {{25, 75, 291, 355, 356, 425, 475, 518, 547, 668, 670, 750, 777},
   {173, 516}, {544, 816}, {610, 720}}
*)
```

Comment: `Cases[Values[PositionIndex[M]], dupe_ /; Length[dupe] > 1]` is faster than `positionDuplicates []`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Yes, it is for me, too, in V12.  My main point is that the solution to this question has been given in another Q&A.  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54852/4999) for the `PositionIndex[]` solutoin.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci It's interesting that `PositionIndex[]` outperforms `positionDuplicates[]` on a list of lists, because it is still much slower on a list of integers.

Answer (score 3):

While this question repeats a [previous query](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-to-efficiently-find-positions-of-duplicates) about finding `DuplicatePositions`, the duplicates here are amongst a list of binary vectors in contrast to the original duplicates occurring amongst a list of numbers. As illustrated [in an answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197975/2249) to the original query however, the  type, depth and distribution of inputs can significantly impact efficiency so there may well be further optimizations  specific to this case of finding duplicates amongst binary vectors. The following summarises timings of the "superfunction" `DuplicatePositions` ([collected and defined](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197975/2249) from answers to the original question - in particular *Szabolcs*, *Carl Woll* and *Mr.Wizard*), `postionDuplicates` (the fastest solutions for numbers from *Szabolcs*) and a tweeking in the `"UseGatherByLocalMap"` `Method` option (from *Carl Woll*), the  accepted `groupBy` answer (by *Roman*) and the `nearest` answer (by *Henrik Schumacher*) for various types of binary vectors. I've contributed the `"UseOrdering"` `Method` in `DuplicatePositions`.

```
duplicatePositionsByOrdering[ls_]:= SplitBy[Ordering@ls, ls[[#]] &] // SortBy[First]
```

which seems to do well for sparse vectors (a more succinct version of similar ideas used by *Mr.Wizard* and *Leonid Shifrin* in their anwers). Note that a *random* 1000x1000 binary matrix is very likely to be sparse to the point of no (row) duplicates occurring so presumably in the OP's situation the authentic data is not randomly generated and instead includes manufactured repeats. To the timings (the tag function just puts in the S1, S2 ... tags as originally requested and the tick indicates identical output):

[image]

Obviously timings aren't everything as short-clear functions can often be preferable (as well as potentially being more efficient for different inputs) but it can also sometimes be illuminating--here for example, indicating that `GroupBy` seems to recognize order for ragged vectors unlike `GatherBy`.

The code for the above output is below

```
SetAttributes[benchmark, HoldAll];

benchmark[functions_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Function[input, benchmark[functions, input, opts], HoldAll];

benchmark[functions_, input_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
    tm = Function[fn, 
      Function[x, <|ToString[fn] -> RepeatedTiming@fn@x|>]],
    timesOutputs, times},
   SeedRandom@0;
   timesOutputs = Through[(tm /@ functions)@input];
   times = 
    SortBy[Query[All, All, First]@timesOutputs, Last] // Dataset;
   If[OptionValue@"CheckOutputs", 
    Labeled[times, 
     Row[{ToString@Unevaluated@input, Spacer@80, 
       If[SameQ @@ (Query[All, Last, 2]@timesOutputs), 
        Style["\[Checkmark]", Green, 20], Style["x", Red, 20]]}], 
     Top], times]
   ];

Options[benchmark] = {"CheckOutputs" -> True};

Options[DuplicatePositions] = {Method -> Automatic};

DuplicatePositions[ls_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  With[{method = OptionValue[Method]},
   Switch[method,
    "UseGatherBy", GatherBy[Range@Length@ls, ls[[#]] &],
    "UsePositionIndex", Values@PositionIndex@ls,
    "UseOrdering", SplitBy[Ordering@ls, ls[[#]] &] // SortBy[First],
    "UseGatherByLocalMap", Module[{func}, func /: Map[func, _] := ls;
     GatherBy[Range@Length@ls, func]],
    Automatic, Which[
     ArrayQ[ls, 1, NumericQ], 
     DuplicatePositions[ls, "Method" -> "UseGatherBy" ],
     ArrayQ[ls, 2, NumericQ], DuplicatePositionsBy[ls, FromDigits],
     MatchQ[{{_?IntegerQ ..} ..}]@ls, 
     DuplicatePositionsBy[ls, FromDigits],
     True, DuplicatePositions[ls, Method -> "UsePositionIndex" ]
     ]]];

DuplicatePositionsBy[ls_, fn_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  DuplicatePositions[fn /@ ls, opts];

tag = Map["S" <> ToString@# &, #, {-1}] &;
positionDuplicates[ls_] := GatherBy[Range@Length@ls, ls[[#]] &];
groupBy[M_] := With[
   {rownames = Array["S" <> ToString[#] &, Length[M]]},
   Values@GroupBy[Thread[rownames -> M], Last -> First]];
nearest[M_] := 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Sort /@ Nearest[M -> Automatic, M, {\[Infinity], 0}]];
n = 10^4;
binaryVectors50k = 
  IntegerDigits[#, 2, 13] & /@ RandomInteger[n, 5*n];
fns = {
   groupBy,
   (nearest@# // tag) &,
   (DuplicatePositions@# // tag) &,
   (DuplicatePositionsBy[#, FromDigits[#, 2] &, 
       Method -> "UseGatherByLocalMap"] // tag) &,
   (positionDuplicates@# // tag) &
   };
benchmark[fns]@binaryVectors50k
n = 10^3;
binaryVectorsRagged5k = IntegerDigits[#, 2] & /@ RandomInteger[n, 5*n];
fns = {
   groupBy,
   (DuplicatePositions@# // tag) &,
   (DuplicatePositionsBy[#, FromDigits[#, 2] &, 
       Method -> "UseGatherByLocalMap"] // tag) &,
   (positionDuplicates@# // tag) &
   };
benchmark[fns]@binaryVectorsRagged5k

n = 10^4;
binaryVectorsSparse10k := RandomInteger[1, {n, n}];
fns = {
   (DuplicatePositions@# // tag) &,
   (positionDuplicates@# // tag) &,
   (DuplicatePositions[#, Method -> "UseOrdering"] // tag) &,
   groupBy};
benchmark[fns]@binaryVectorsSparse10k
```