# Position of first element in list which is repeated

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the list

```
t1 = {{-1, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-3, 0}, {0, 0}, {-2, 0}, {1, 1}}
```

How do I find the position where an element repeats? In this case it would be element `{-2, 0}` at position 5, because `{-2, 0}` first came up at postion 2. So the answer would be 5.

I made it to comparisons with the first element but don't know how to procede.

Comment: How to efficiently find position of duplicates 
 (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-to-efficiently-find-positions-of-duplicates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
firstDup = Min @* Map[Rest] @* Values @* PositionIndex;;

firstDup @ {{-1, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-3, 0}, {0, 0}, {-2, 0}, {1, 1}}
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

```
firstDup @ {{-1, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-3, 0}, {0, 0}, {-2, 0}, {1, 1}, {-2, 0}, {-2, 0}}
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

```
firstDup @ {{-1, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-3, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {-2, 0}, {1, 1}}
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the position of the first duplicate element you could use something like this,

```
firstDuplicatePosition[list_]:=With[{ds = CreateDataStructure @ "HashSet"},
    Catch[
        MapIndexed[If[!ds["Insert",#1],Throw[#2]]&, list];
        {}
    ]
];
firstDuplicatePosition @ {{-1, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-3, 0}, {0, 0}, {-2, 0}, {1, 1}}
(* {5} *)
```