# DeleteDuplicates without destroying SparseArray

Tags: sparse-arrays

When I use `DeleteDuplicates` to delete equal rows of a sparse array, the output is not a sparse array anymore. In my application, the sparse arrays are huge but very sparse, so converting back and forth is quite annoying.

Is there a version of, or alternative to, `DeleteDuplicates` that always preserves sparse arrays? (i.e. without converting back and forth between dense and sparse representations)

Comment: You mean, you want to delete duplicate rows?

Comment: Yes. But preferably still with the possibility to use a test function of choice (e.g. when two rows are equal up to sign)

Comment: You can avoid unsparsifying rows by doing `SparseArray @ DeleteDuplicates[List @@ sparse]`

Comment: Deleting duplicate rows would change the dimensions of the array. That in turn would change the coordinate->value rules. You won't be preserving much of anything. So, if DeleteDuplicates did return a sparse array, you'd just have a whole other set of annoyances to deal with. Are you sure DeleteDuplicates is the operation you want? Maybe there is a more algebraic operation that you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It often helps when the OP provides their own test case.  But here goes, assuming any test case sufficiently illustrates the problem as we are implicitly invited to do:

```
Quit[]

SeedRandom[0];
sparse = SparseArray[
  Thread[RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {100, 2}] -> 1], {1000, 1000}]
```

> [image]

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> (*  150671984  *)
> ```

```
sparse[[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Range@Length@sparse, sparse[[#]] &]]]
```

> [image]

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> (*  150671984  *)
> ```

Or per the OP's comment under the OP:

```
SeedRandom[0];
sparse = SparseArray[
  Thread[RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {100, 2}] -> 
    RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 100]], {1000, 1000}]
```

> [image]

```
sparse[[
 DeleteDuplicatesBy[Range@Length@sparse, Abs[sparse[[#]]] &]]]
```

> [image]

(Same dimensions since `Abs[-1] == 1`.

Comment: Somewhat inspired by [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/4999) to a question of mine. Which I guess I still remember.