# Ordering function with recognition of duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Fairly often I have a need to get the `Ordering` of an expression but with recognition of duplicates.  For example:

```
Ordering[{0, 4, 1, 1, 2}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 4, 5, 2}
> ```

but with duplicates such as `3, 4` marked, i.e.:

> ```
> {{1}, {3, 4}, {5}, {2}}
> ```

I have been using a decorate-and-sort followed by `GatherBy` and `Part`:

```
{0, 4, 1, 1, 2} //
  GatherBy[Sort[{#, Range@Length@#}\[Transpose]], First][[All, All, 2]] &
```

> ```
> {{1}, {3, 4}, {5}, {2}}
> ```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there is!

Szabolcs [showed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/121) a use of `GatherBy` in an inverted fashion as a substitute for a conventional decorate-and-sort.  It proved both syntactically and computationally efficient.

By using that method in place of the decorate-and-sort in this application we can use `Ordering` directly, and also eliminate `Part` which was needed to strip the decoration:

```
myOrdering[a_] := GatherBy[Ordering @ a, a[[#]] &]

{0, 4, 1, 1, 2} // myOrdering
```

> ```
> {{1}, {3, 4}, {5}, {2}}
> ```

This is nearly twice as fast as my old method in the question, and much shorter.

I hope this function proves to be as useful to others as I know it will be to me.

Related posts: [(21453)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21453/121), [(29551)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29551/121)

---

Applying Carl Woll's revealing method from [`GatherByList`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158637/121) to this problem we get:

```
myOrdering2[a_] :=
  Module[{f, o = Ordering @ a},
    f /: f /@ _ = a[[o]];
    GatherBy[o, f]
  ]
```

This can be significantly faster in cases with heavy duplication:

```
big = RandomInteger[100, 1*^6];

r1 = myOrdering[big];  // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = myOrdering2[big]; // RepeatedTiming // First

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> 0.13
>
> 0.0930
>
> True
> ```

Comment: So, looks like you've set the goal to get the most out of this method :-). +1, of course.

Comment: @Leonid As soon as I saw that it was fast I realized it was going to impact a number of applications.  This is an operation for which I've been carting old code around without much thought.  It's nice to finally get a clean *and* fast function for it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just wondering why I did not discover that myself, since I had lots of similar problems too. I think that somehow I was sure the performance would be much worse, so I did not even bother trying. A big mistake, it turns out.

Comment: @Leonid Likewise, as I explained [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-to-efficiently-find-positions-of-duplicates/21344#comment66089_21344).

Comment: If I ever become a dairy farmer, I'm hiring you to milk my cows :P

Comment: @rm-rf *Now* I get it.  lol :-)

Comment: *And* burning the candle at both ends, too (+2) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Association` - related functions (which were not available at the time the question was posted):

```
list = {0, 4, 1, 1, 2};

Values @ KeySort @ PositionIndex @ list
```

{{1}, {3, 4}, {5}, {2}}