# Efficiently finding the positions of a large list of targets in another, even larger list

Tags: performance-tuning, index

I have a big list. It contains nearly 60,000 sub-lists. It's structured like

```
bigList = {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3},.....,{x60000,y60000,z60000}};
```

I have picked 1200 elements from the `bigList` at random.

```
smallList = {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},......,{x1200,y1200,z1200}};
```

I want to find the positions of the `smallList` elements in the `bigList`. To that end I wrote the following code.

```
Flatten[Map[Position[bigList, #]&, smallList]]
```

It's working fine, but it takes **30 seconds** to evaluate.

```
Timing[Flatten[Map[Position[bigList, #]&, smallList]]]
```

How can I reduce that evaluation time?

Comment: Since you know the number of elements in your list (60k) and its sublist structure (3 elements), why don't you just pick the _positions_ at random from a list of possible positions, instead of picking the elements and then using `Position` (which is very slow)? It's the same and should be very fast. Even if you need to construct `smallList`, you can use these randomly generated positions and extract the elements using `Part`, which would still be faster. Also, your [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) construction in `Map` is incorrect...

Comment: @rm-rf I can imagine that he is just describing how to get test data, but the question is phrased rather ambiguous indeed.

Comment: I think the problem should be rephrased as something like : With `bigList = RandomInteger[{1, 255}, {60000, 3}]; smallList = RandomChoice[bigList, 1200];` try to decrease : `First[Timing[Flatten[Map[Position[bigList, #] &, smallList]]]]`. If the OP confirms this is what he wants, I can do it myself.

Comment: Are all sublists unique or do you want to find all occurences of a given sublist?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries all my `sublists` have different values,but structure was unique like {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},....}.

Comment: The last information from @subbu implies that my last rephrasing suggestion ({`bigList=RandomInteger[...];...`) doesn't work

Comment: But bigList = 
  RandomSample[DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[{1, 255}, {70000, 3}]], 
   60000]; should fix it, right?

Comment: @subbu Your added comment is rather confusing. You say all sublists have different values BUT are unique. The BUT implies a contrast where I see none. To solve this: Could you try and report the result of the following code: `Length[Union[bigList]]` with bigList your own list, not that of the guys below?

Comment: Please add the result of `Length[bigList]` as well.

Comment: I didn't say `Unique`, but `Union`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will use `big` and `small` rather than `bigList` and `smallList`, for brevity.

As stated by others if you can select the *positions* at random in the first place this will be faster, e.g.:

```
pos = RandomSample[Range @ Length @ big, 1200];
```

You can then get the small list with: `small = big[[pos]]`.

To carry out the specific operation you describe the key detail will be to *not* scan the `big` list again for every element of `small` but rather find a way to scan it only *once*.

One of the simplest methods is to use `MapIndexed` to build a list of replacement rules that yield positions from elements.  `MapIndexed` is easily extendable to array and tensor elements as well.  `Dispatch` can be used to optimize this list of replacement rules.

Example data:

```
big = Array[{"x", "y", "z"} # &, 60000];

small = RandomSample[big, 1200];
```

Build the dispatch table:

```
rls = MapIndexed[Rule, big] // Dispatch;
```

Find the positions:

```
pos = small /. rls;
```

Together both operations take less than a tenth of a second on my machine:

```
First @ Timing[small /. Dispatch @ MapIndexed[Rule, big];]
```

> 0.0966

Confirmation of accuracy:

```
Extract[big, pos] === small
```

> True

---

#### Lists with duplicates

The method above assumes that your `big` list does not have any duplicate elements; that is, there is a one-to-one mapping of element and position.  If there are duplicates you will need an additional `GatherBy` step as follows.

Data with duplicates:

```
big = Array[{"x", "y", "z"} Mod[#, 5000] &, 60000];
small = RandomSample[big, 1200];
```

Build rules, Gather them, and build the Dispatch table:

```
rls2 =
 Dispatch[
   #[[1, 1]] -> #[[All, 2, 1]] & /@
     Rule ~MapIndexed~ big ~GatherBy~ First
 ];
```

Find the positions in `big` at which the first element of `small` appears:

```
First @ small /. rls2
```

> ```
> {2659, 7659, 12659, 17659, 22659, 27659, 32659, 37659, 42659, 47659, 52659, 57659}
> ```

Instead of `GatherBy` you could also use `Sow` and `Reap`, e.g.:

```
rls2 = Dispatch @ Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#2, #] &, big], _, # -> Flatten@#2 &][[2]];
```

#### Alternative method

To provide an alternative approach you can use DownValues definitions in place of the Dispatch table.  I shall illustrate the method for a list with duplicates as that is more interesting.

Data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
big = RandomInteger[9, 50];
small = {6, 3, 9, 7, 2};
```

Build the definitions:

```
Clear[posfn]

posfn[_] = {};

AppendTo[posfn[#], #2[[1]]] & ~MapIndexed~ big;
```

Test the function:

```
posfn /@ small
```

> ```
> {{8, 20, 23}, {17, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36, 42}, {37, 43}, {4}, {18, 22, 35, 41, 50}}
> ```

Confirmation:

```
big[[ posfn[3] ]]
```

> ```
> {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
> ```

Comment: Thank you.really it's awesome.working fine.really you done good job...Really thanks Wizard.Thanks,Thanks,Thanks

Comment: @subbu You're welcome.  You see that I am not unwilling to help, I just want you to put some effort into reading and understanding the *Mathematica* documentation.  If you do not you will end up with ["cargo cult programming."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Answer (score 7):

Prompted by comments conversation with Mr. Wizard, a routine I use:

```
findMultiPosXX[list_, find_, allowBits_: False, skipCands_: True] := 
 Module[{f = DeleteDuplicates[find], o, l, oo, bitmax = 20, cands, dims},

  If[allowBits && Length@f <= bitmax,
   With[{r = If[Length@(dims = Dimensions@list) == 1, Range@Length@list, 
                Array[List, dims]]}, Pick[r, BitXor[list, #], 0] & /@ f],

   If[skipCands,

    (* This is the core explained below *)

    (l = Length@f;
     oo = Ordering[o = Ordering[Join[f, list, f]]]; 
     Inner[o[[# ;; #2]] &, oo[[;; l]], oo[[-l ;;]], List][[All, 2 ;; -2]] - l),

    (* end of core method *)

    (cands = 
      SparseArray[
        BitAnd[UnitStep[list - Min@f], UnitStep[Max@f - list]]]["NonzeroPositions"];

     cands[[#]] & /@ (l = Length@f;
       oo = Ordering[o = Ordering[Join[f, Extract[list, cands], f]]]; 
       Inner[o[[# ;; #2]] &, oo[[;; l]], oo[[-l ;;]], List][[All, 2 ;; -2]] - l))]]];
```

Use:

```
test = RandomInteger[10, 20]

findMultiPosXX[test, {5, 10, 8}]

(*

{10, 0, 1, 4, 10, 5, 7, 2, 7, 7, 1, 4, 9, 3, 3, 7, 7, 8, 2, 5}

{{6, 20}, {1, 5}, {18}}

*)
```

With default argument (just the target and searches), can beat `GatherBy` by order of magnitude, and `Position` with `Alternatives` (which leaves you with only positions but no mapping to values) by a factor of 5 or more.

When searching for *scalar* values at the top level, setting the third argument to `True` will use bit-map search for 20 or fewer search terms, upping the performance typically by 4-10X. Also for *scalar* searches, if one knows the search space spans a small range of the data range, setting the fourth argument to `False` causes the search space to be narrowed, boosting performance from 2X to over an order of magnitude.

E.g., testing against several of the answers and `Position` with `Alternatives`, using the OP specified sizes with `test = RandomInteger[1000000, {60000, 3}]` and 
`finds = RandomSample[test, 1200]`, the speed advantage results expressed as time/mytime were `{7.4286, 6.1429, 20.857, 21.143, 419.71}`.

An explanation of the core method (when no optional arguments are set):

Let's take an example list:

```
test = RandomInteger[5, 20]

(* {5, 3, 2, 5, 0, 4, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 5, 5, 5, 4, 0, 2} *)
```

Say we want to look for threes and fives. We'll call that `lookfor`, and prepend/append that to the target list:

```
lookfor = {3, 5}
work = Join[lookfor, test, lookfor]

(*
   {3, 5}

   {3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 0, 4, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 5, 5, 5, 4, 0, 2, 3,5}
*)
```

Now, let's use `Ordering` to get the positions from `work` in its sorted incarnation, along with the ordering *of that order*. That is just the permutation of the range of the length of work by a permutation list of the order (you can do it that way, but somewhat surprisingly, using `Ordering` on an order is faster):

```
Column[{order = Ordering[work],orderOforder = Ordering[order]}, Left, 2]

(* 
  {7,12,13,16,21,5,22,1,4,9,23,8,10,11,15,20,2,3,6,14,17,18,19,24}

  {8,17,18,9,6,19,1,12,10,13,14,2,3,20,15,4,21,22,23,16,5,7,11,24}
*)
```

Now, here's the "magic". Take note of the first and last two entries of the permutation (two being the length of our `lookfor` list):

```
lengthOflookfor = Length@lookfor;

transposed = Transpose[{orderOforder[[;; lengthOflookfor]], 
                        orderOforder[[-lengthOflookfor ;;]]}]

(* {{8, 11}, {17, 24}} *)
```

These pairs are in essence nothing more than spans, corresponding to the positions, for each of our `lookfor` elements, in the *first* ordering, mapping us the corresponding position(s) if any in the work list:

```
Column[{span = Span @@@ transposed, places = order[[#]] & /@ span, 
         work[[#]] & /@ places}, Left, 2]
(* 

{8;;11,17;;24}
{{1,4,9,23},{2,3,6,14,17,18,19,24}}
{{3,3,3,3},{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5}}

*)
```

So we see that following the order from positions 8 to 11 and 17 to 24, we recover the positions of the elements we're interested in from the work list.

All that's left to do is to trim our padded element entries from the result and adjust the positions to get the actual positions from the original list:

```
Column[{recovered = ArrayPad[#, -1] & /@ places - lengthOflookfor,
         test[[#]] & /@ recovered}, Left, 2]

(*
{{2,7},{1,4,12,15,16,17}}
{{3,3},{5,5,5,5,5,5}}
*)
```

Because `Ordering` is, in general, very fast, this trick allows us to recover the positions of a large subset of elements (or show non-existence) from the target list very quickly.

Comment: I fault you for not posting the general core method by itself, as the superfunction makes it look a lot more hairy than it is, but this is great!  Big +1 from me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: LOL, I was just pondering adding an explanation of the core - as the Cylons would say "by your command..."

Comment: It seems to me that the `Inner` part can be simplified with: `Inner[o[[# ;; #2]] &, oo[[;; l]] + 1, oo[[-l ;;]] - 1, List] - l`.  Also, while I'm still excited about this method, and it is applicable where mine is not, I am finding it somewhat slower than `GatherBy` as used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21459/121) (which is what the link lead to).  This may be a version difference.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'd expect it to be slower in that case: `GatherBy` is still the go-to if you want *all* the positions (multipos was not targeted there, mostly for up to 30-50% of the target at most). Sleep well!

Answer (score 5):

An approach like @Rolf-Merting's using a nearest function. First create the lists:

```
bigList = RandomSample[DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[{1, 255}, {70000, 3}]], 60000];
smallList = RandomSample[bigList, 1200];
```

then create a nearest function mapping to list indices:

```
nf = Nearest[Thread[bigList -> Range@Length@bigList]];
```

then map `nf` to the small list and get back the positions:

```
AbsoluteTiming[nf /@ smallList;]
```

overall (together with the creation of the nearest function) it is slightly faster.

Comment: This is a fine solution that even works (i.e., is speedy) if bigList has duplicates which seems to be subbu's problem. One has to guarantee that smallList is sampled from bigList, but that seems to be a given here.

Comment: @Sjoerd At least with version 7 this does not work on my non-numeric test set.  How about in v9?

Comment: This wouldn't work on symbolic ones - I didn't realise that was part of the question. One could convert them to strings and then find the nearest function but I that would take forever I think.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I suppose it will work for lists with elements on which a distance function yields a definite value. Your demo list is probably not what the OP is working with, he only provided the list symbolically to show the structure.

Answer (score 4):

```
bigList = RandomSample[DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[{1, 255}, {70000, 3}]], 60000];
smallList = RandomSample[bigList, 1200];
First@AbsoluteTiming[Map[Position[bigList, #] &, smallList]]
```

needs less than a second on my machine.

Comment: Really I didn't understood.specifically you are not use any `function`.but computation takes only `less than a second`.just for example purpose we are using `RandomIntegers`,I have `60000`point,each point is different.know How can I implement your logic in my code.
can you tell me ?

Comment: @subbu: just read the documentations of RandomSample, etc. Then you will understand. And please, take some time for it. Learning takes time. Really. You need about 5 years to master Mathematica. A PhD also helps.

Comment: I think subbu means: your code is the same as his (apart from `Flatten`), so how can it be that much faster?

Comment: The difference lies in the uniqueness of the values of `bigList`. If it has duplicates, running time of the code goes through the roof.

Answer (score 1):

I think a mention of the **Mathematica 10** method should now be added:

```
bigList = Array[{"x", "y", "z"} # &, 60000];
smallList = RandomSample[bigList, 1200];

pi = PositionIndex[bigList];
pos = Lookup[pi, smallList][[All, 1]];
bigList[[pos]] == smallList
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether this helps. `Union` removes duplicates and sorts:

```
bigList = Union@RandomInteger[{1, 255}, {60000, 3}]; 
smallList = RandomChoice[bigList, 1200];
First@AbsoluteTiming[ Map[Position[bigList, #] &, smallList]]
```

and it's therefore much quicker.

> 0.833301

Comment: I have a `bigList`,each sublist is different.so in my case `union` is not usefull.