# Returning all positions for all different occurences of elements in a list

Tags: function-construction

Is there way to construct oneliner as pure function(s), so that I enter `mylist` only on one place - on the end of line. And that function return the same result as last line bellow but paired with `mylist`. So the result should look like this:

> ```
> {{1, {8}}, {2, {2, 4, 6}}, {4, {1}}, {5, {5}}, {7, {3, 7}}}
> ```

```
mylist = {4, 2, 7, 2, 5, 2, 7, 1};    
alldiffelem = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@mylist    
(* {1, 2, 4, 5, 7} *)
(Flatten@Position[mylist, #]) & /@ alldiffelem    
(* {{8}, {2, 4, 6}, {1}, {5}, {3, 7}} *)
```

Comment: Do you specifically want a "one-liner" constructed from anonymous functions?  I can do that, but I think my present two-definition form is more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an approach using `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
Last@Reap[MapThread[Sow, {Range[Length[mylist]], mylist}], _, List]
```

yielding

```
{{4, {1}}, {2, {2, 4, 6}}, {7, {3, 7}}, {5, {5}}, {1, {8}}}
```

if you wish to sort:

```
SortBy[Last@Reap[MapThread[Sow, {Range[Length[mylist]],mylist}], _, List], First]
```

yielding:

```
{{1, {8}}, {2, {2, 4, 6}}, {4, {1}}, {5, {5}}, {7, {3, 7}}}
```

Comment: Nice. `Reap` and `Sow` seem more intuitive tools for this sort of task. Would be interested in timings on large lists. This is a bit more concise: `Last@Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[First[#2], #1] &, mylist], _, {#1, #2} &]`

Comment: An alternative to the `SortBy` method that appears to be twice as fast is: `Last @ Reap[MapThread[Sow, {Range @ Length @ mylist, mylist}], Union @ mylist, List]`

Answer (score 5):

This is *almost* a duplicate of [Ordering function with recognition of duplicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21458/121).  It is related to [Efficiently finding the positions of a large list of targets in another, even larger list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21820/121) but since you apparently want *all* unique elements I believe it is closer to the first.

Using `myOrdering` from the first referenced question:

```
myOrdering[a_List] := GatherBy[Ordering @ a, a[[#]] &]

fn[a_List] := {Union @ a, myOrdering @ a}\[Transpose]

fn @ mylist
```

> ```
> {{1, {8}}, {2, {2, 4, 6}}, {4, {1}}, {5, {5}}, {7, {3, 7}}}
> ```

---

#### Version 10 update

The new-in-v10 [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GroupBy.html) can combine the two lines of code in my original answer:

```
fn2[a_] := GroupBy[Ordering @ a, a[[#]] &]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {8}, 2 -> {2, 4, 6}, 4 -> {1}, 5 -> {5}, 7 -> {3, 7}|>
> ```

The result is an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html) which has value in itself.  However `fn2` is not as fast as my original `fn`.

---

### Timings

Responding to Mike Honeychurch's implicit request for timings, here is my function (in its current version) versus both ubpdqn and his `Sow`/`Reap` method, performed in version 10.0.1.

```
mylist = RandomInteger[2*^5, 5*^5];

fn @ mylist  // Timing // First
fn2 @ mylist // Timing // First
Last@Reap[MapThread[Sow, {Range[Length[mylist]], mylist}], _, List] // Timing // First
Last@Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[First[#2], #1] &, mylist], _, List]        // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.265202
>
> 0.702005
>
> 3.619223
>
> 4.118426
> ```

Note that both `Sow`/`Reap` methods are the un-sorted variation; adding a sort would incur an additional overhead.

Comment: this is neat...these methods always seem much faster than sowing and reaping but I just like playing with `Reap` and `Sow`

Comment: @ubpdqn I like Sow and Reap too. +1 on your answer.  By the way I just fixed my code which was broken due to confusing myself re: sorting.

Answer (score 4):

Competitive with fastest so far in general, and often *considerably* faster (e.g., when duplication of elements is higher, as in `RandomInteger[5000, 1000000]` about 3 to 4X faster):

```
Module[{o, d = DeleteDuplicates@mylist, r = Range@Length@mylist},
 o = Ordering@d; 
 Transpose[{d, GatherBy[r, mylist[[#]] &]}][[o]]]
```

As a pure function:

```
With[{d = DeleteDuplicates@#, l = #, r = Range@Length@#},
      Transpose[{d, GatherBy[r, l[[#]] &]}][[Ordering@d]]] &[mylist]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `SparseArray` and changing the setting of `TreatRepeatedEntries` suboption (of `SparseArrayOptions` in `SystemOptions`:

```
System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"->{"TreatRepeatedEntries"->(ToString[{##}]&)}];
xx = SparseArray[mylist -> Range[Length[mylist]]]["NonzeroValues"] // ToExpression;
System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First}];
yy = SparseArray[mylist -> mylist]["NonzeroValues"];
Transpose[{yy, xx}]
(* {{4, 1}, {2, {2, 4, 6}}, {7, {3, 7}}, {5, 5}, {1, 8}}  *)
```

(See O. Rubenko's answer [Fast 2D binning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203344/990168) for this undocumented suboption. See also [Optimizing 2D binning code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17742/125))

**Note:** this approach works in the current form for "target lists of positive integers of limited range" (e.g., on my machine, it works for a list of length 50,000, but 100 000 does not) .  (thanks: @rasher).

Comment: I think it is worth to add a [link to the post where undocumented `"TreatRepeatedEntries"` suboption is explained](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17742/280).

Comment: Thank you @Alexey; added the links.

Comment: You should note this is only usable in this form with target lists of positive integers of limited range.

Comment: @rasher, thanks; just updated with the suggested note.

Answer (score 1):

`mylist` only on one place - on the end of line

```
Sort@(Function[{x, y}, 
  Thread[List[y, Flatten@Position[x, #] & /@ y]]] @@ {#,DeleteDuplicates@#}) &@mylist
```

{{1, {8}}, {2, {2, 4, 6}}, {4, {1}}, {5, {5}}, {7, {3, 7}}}

Answer (score 1):

Via `PositionIndex`

```
mylist = {4, 2, 7, 2, 5, 2, 7, 1};

foo = KeyValueMap[List] @ KeySort @ PositionIndex @ #&;

foo @ mylist
```

{{1, {8}}, {2, {2, 4, 6}}, {4, {1}}, {5, {5}}, {7, {3, 7}}}

Answer (score 0):

Using `MapIndexed` and the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
lst = {4, 2, 7, 2, 5, 2, 7, 1};

Values@GroupBy[Sort@MapIndexed[List, lst], First, 
{#[[1, 1]], #[[2, All, 1]]} &@Transpose@# &]

(*{{1, {8}}, {2, {2, 4, 6}}, {4, {1}}, {5, {5}}, {7, {3, 7}}}*)
```