# Gather list elements by labels

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, gathering

The following list has some elements that are labeled. For example `{1, 2} -> 1, {-1, 3} -> 3`, etc:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {-1, 3}, {5, 6}, {-3, 4}, {7, 8}, {-9, 1}, {0, 1}};
labels = {1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3};
```

What is a good way to gather `list`'s elements clustered according to their labels?

```
clusters = {{{1 ,2}, {-3, 4}, {-9, 1}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 1}}}
```

Comment: I think there was a question like this in the past but I can't recall it. `Extract[list, Position[labels, #]] & /@ Union@labels`

Comment: @Kuba. Please write up your solution as an answer so we can get this question off the unanswered list.

Comment: After 5 days i will run a benchmark for all answers (with reasonable data) and post here the results.

Comment: @tchronis More than five days have passed, and you've got two new answers.  I chose to add timings to my own.  I'll be interested to see your own timings when you get around to it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you and I am sorry I didn't fulfill my promise on publishing timing results. By the way you are too fast for me and sure your evaluations are more reliable than mine.

Comment: [similar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130131/106)

Comment: @tomd That looks like a duplicate to me.  If you agree would you please cast a vote to close that question as a duplicate of this one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the best way is to use an [Ordering function with recognition of duplicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21458/121).
Please see that (self) Q&A for an explanation.

```
myOrdering[a_List] := GatherBy[Ordering@a, a[[#]] &]

list[[#]] & /@ myOrdering[labels]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {-3, 4}, {-9, 1}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 1}}}
> ```

---

### Benchmarking

And updated benchmark for recent versions, performed in 10.1.0.

Note: in version 7 `Pick` was orders of magnitude slower in this test.  Now it is competitive but it still falls behind as the number of unique labels increases.

```
myOrdering[a_List] := GatherBy[Ordering@a, a[[#]] &]

f1[{list_, labels_}] :=
  Extract[list, Position[labels, #]] & /@ Union@labels

f2[{list_, labels_}] :=
  Pick[list, labels, #] & /@ Union@labels

f3[{list_, labels_}] :=
  GatherBy[Sort[Transpose@{labels, list}, OrderedQ[{#1[[1]], #2[[1]]}] &], 
   First][[All, All, 2]]

f4[{list_, labels_}] :=
  Reap[MapThread[Sow, {list, labels}], Union@labels][[2, All, 1]]

f5[{list_, labels_}] :=
  list[[#]] & /@ myOrdering[labels]

g[n_] := RandomInteger[⌈n/4⌉, #] & /@ {{n, 2}, n}


Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}, g, 10]
```

[image]

Comment: Performance depends of `labels` variety. Try `labels = RandomInteger[10, 3000]`, `Pick` should show it's strength :)

Comment: @Kuba It's still nearly an order of magnitude slower than `myOrdering` on my system.  I know `Pick` was improved on Packed Arrays in version 8 (I use v7).  What timings do you get?  Nevertheless I think the multiple-pass `Pick`/`Position` method has a higher complexity by nature.

Comment: `0.000625001` for `Pick` and `0.00057500` for `myOrdering` :)

Comment: @Kuba I added a note to my answer; I hope you approve.

Comment: I fully agree :) I was aware of not efficient nature of this approach, I should have described it but I forgot :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for the comparisons and discussion re: Ordering and Pick.

Answer (score 8):

I'm always afraid in case of [list-manipulation](/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) that there was a duplicate in the past. But I do not remember.

You can try this:

```
Extract[list, Position[labels, #]] & /@ Union@labels
```

> {{{1 ,2}, {-3, 4}, {-9, 1}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 1}}}

and this:

```
Pick[list, labels, #] & /@ Union@labels
```

> {{{1, 2}, {-3, 4}, {-9, 1}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 1}}}

`GatherBy` variation

```
GatherBy[Sort@Thread[Rule[labels, list]], First][[ ;; , ;; , 2]]
```

> {{{-9, 1}, {-3, 4}, {1, 2}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 1}}}

Answer (score 7):

My `GatherBy` variation:

```
GatherBy[Transpose@{labels, list}, First][[All, All, 2]]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {-3, 4}, {-9, 1}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 1}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}

A possible drawback is that the result is not sorted by label. This is easy to change by doing

```
GatherBy[Sort@Transpose@{labels, list}, First][[All, All, 2]]
```

> {{{-9, 1}, {-3, 4}, {1, 2}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 1}}}

which sorts by label but destroys the initial intra-label ordering or by

```
GatherBy[Sort[Transpose@{labels, list}, OrderedQ[{#1[[1]], #2[[1]]}] &], First][[All, All, 2]]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {-3, 4}, {-9, 1}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 1}}}

which keeps the initial order.

Comment: Thank you @sebhofer. Yes the non sorted drawback matters in my case.

Comment: @tchronis I realised this is easy to change, see my edit.

Comment: Another idea for the sorting might be: `Sort[GatherBy[Transpose[{labels, list}], First], 
  First@#1[[1]] < First@#2[[1]] &][[All, All, 2]]` (possibly slower than your ideas, but at least it's rather short :) )

Comment: @PinguinDirk Sure that also works, I would contest it's shorter though. You can do `Sort[GatherBy[Transpose[{labels, list}], 
   First], #1[[1, 1]] < #2[[1, 1]] &][[All, All, 2]]` then it is shorter, but only by 7 keystrokes :)

Comment: ok :) it's not code golfing, and I'd have chosen the same approach! +1

Answer (score 5):

This also works:

```
Reap[MapThread[Sow, {list, labels}]][[2]]
```

or an alternatively ordering by tags:

```
Reap[MapThread[Sow, {list, labels}], Union @ labels][[2, All, 1]]
```

Comment: I really like `Sow` and `Reap`. (+1)  I hope you don't mind, but I'm taking the liberty to streamline your code; you can revert the edit if you disapprove.

Comment: Value your comment and edit. I always learn something.

Comment: Thanks: Reap/Sow seemed a useful approach. I just failed to understand it well enough, My ignorance, I hope, is now further reduced.

Comment: What you had was perfectly valid.  It is simply that the default values work in this case so we aren't required to specify them.  Regarding using `Sow[#, #2]&` rather than simply `Sow`, I've seen *many* people do that so you're in good company. :-)