# Summing elements in a list by groups indicated by a list of indices

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, one containing values, the other indices. Now I want to accumulate the values that have the same corresponding index. So for example:

```
values  = {2, 6, 3, 8, 3, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 5}

indices = {1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1}
```

should give

> `result = {2 + 3 + 1 + 3 + 5, 8 + 7 + 3, 6 + 3 + 1}`

I need to do this for very large lists, so it should be efficient.

Any ideas?

Comment: `GatherBy[Transpose[{values, indices}], Last][[All, All, 1]]`

Comment: What's "very large lists"? Thousands of elements? Millions of elements? Billions? And how many distinct indices would be expected? 50% of elements? 10%? 1%? There will be very different ways of doing this depending on such things.

Answer (score 7):

`Pick` is usually fast, and parallel processing may help, depending on your computer.

```
ParallelTable[Total[Pick[values, indices, k]], {k, Union[indices]}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility which is certainly quick for large sets:

```
GroupBy[Transpose[{values, indices}], Last -> First, Total]
```

This returns an association which can be converted back to a list ordered by index for no overhead with the frustratingly verbose

```
Normal@*SparseArray@*Normal@GroupBy[...]
```

Comment: +1 `Values@GroupBy[...]` will also do the trick.

Comment: It will, but it won't guarantee that the values will be in the order dictated by `indices`. `SparseArray` is useful as it takes care of that.

Comment: Yes, you are right... the implicit ordering of various association-related operations is unreliable as it has changed over the past few releases.  `Values@KeySort@GroupBy[...]` is another possibility.

Answer (score 5):

Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/121) or [Gather list elements by labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28606/121)

e.g.

```
positionDuplicates[list_] := GatherBy[Range@Length[list], list[[#]] &]

values[[#]] & /@ positionDuplicates[indices]

Total[%, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 1, 3, 5}, {6, 3, 1}, {8, 7, 3}}
>
> {14, 10, 18}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

A [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)/[`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) variant:

```
Reap[MapThread[Sow[#1, #2] &, {values, indices}], _, {#2, Total@#2} &][[-1]]
```

yields:

```
{{{2, 3, 1, 3, 5}, 14}, {{6, 3, 1}, 10}, {{8, 7, 3}, 18}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
values = {2, 6, 3, 8, 3, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 5};

indices = {1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1};
```

Requested result

```
result = {2 + 3 + 1 + 3 + 5, 8 + 7 + 3, 6 + 3 + 1}
```

{14, 18, 10}

Using `Merge`

```
KeySort @ Merge[Total] @ Thread[indices -> values]
```

<|1 -> 14, 2 -> 18, 3 -> 10|>

```
Values[%]
```

{14, 18, 10}

Answer (score 2):

```
groupMap = Extract[#, Map[List]@Values@PositionIndex@#2, #3] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
values = {2, 6, 3, 8, 3, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 5};

indices = {1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1};

groupMap[values, indices, Total]
```

> ```
> {14, 10, 18}
> ```

```
groupMap[Array[x, Length@indices], indices, Apply[Times]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `SplitBy`:

```
values = {2, 6, 3, 8, 3, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 5};
indices = {1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1};

Total /@ Values@SplitBy[Sort@Thread[indices -> values], First]

(*{14, 18, 10}*)
```