# How to drop the identical rows and columns of a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I'm currently trying to find a way to eliminate from a square matrix of
generic dimension the duplicate (up to sign) rows and columns, obtaining
a smaller dimensional matrix. I searched around here but I couldn't find
an answer, neither I managed to combine methods for list manipulation in
order to arrive at my result.

I'll make an example in order to clarify.
Suppose I have a matrix of this form:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
x_1 & w_2 & -x_1 & -w_1 & -w_2 & w_1\\
z_2 & x_2 & -z_2 & z_1 & -x_2 & -z_1 \\
-x_1 & -w_2 & x_1 & w_1 & w_2 & -w_1\\
-y_2 & y_1 & y_2 & x_3 & -y_1 & -x_3\\
z_2 & x_2 & -z_2 & z_1 & -x_2 & -z_1\\
y_2 & -y_1 & -y_2 & -x_3 & y_1 & x_3\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I want to eliminate rows and columns 3,5,6, (copies of 1,2,4) ending up
with the matrix

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 & w_2 & -w_1\\
z_2 & x_2 & z_1\\
-y_2 & y_1 & x_3\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I would like to implement this operation so that it can act on matrices
of arbitrary dimension.

Thank you very much!

Stefano

Comment: Can you post the matrix in Mathematica syntax as well please?  People won't want to re-type it.  `DeleteDuplicates` with a custom comparison function might work.

Comment: @Szabolcs: the matrices I am using are generated by a custom antisymmetrized tensor product, it's quite long to write down. Anyway, the elements can be whatever, the matrix I used is just an example.
The problem with `DeleteDuplicates` is that, even if I can tell him to eliminate both equal and opposite elements, it eliminates the elements, while I'd like to eliminate rows and columns. For example my matrix might contain a lot of zeroes and not all of them should be eliminated.

Comment: To those who voted to close: it is not *too* difficult to copy the array into *Mathematica*; right click and select **Show Math As** > **MathML Code**, copy and paste into *Mathematica*, and let it interpret the input.  Evaluate the cell and let it read TraditionalForm data.  Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the core of `myOrdering` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21459/121):

```
fn =
  Module[{first, abs = Abs[#]},
    first[a_] := First /@ GatherBy[Ordering@a, a[[#]] &] // Sort;
    #[[first @ abs, first[abs\[Transpose]]]]
  ] &;

fn @ a // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x_1 & w_2 & -w_1 \\
 z_2 & x_2 & z_1 \\
 -y_2 & y_1 & x_3
\end{array}
\right)$

For an explanation of why this is superior to `DeleteDuplicates` see: [How to represent a list as a cycle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17041/how-to-represent-a-list-as-a-cycle/17042#17042)

Comment: Thank you! It really works wonder.

I have only one question more, I noticed that this method only works if the entries of the matrix are monomials. It might happen that my matrix contains polynomials, such as $\frac{1}{2}(x_1+z_2)$, for example. Is it possible to do something about it?

Comment: @Stefano Glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept.  So you want `-(1/2) (x1 + z2)` and `(1/2) (x1 + z2)` to be equivalent, correct?  Please try using `abs = # /. -x_ :> x` instead.  (Depending on your expressions you might need more than this; let me know.)

Comment: I tried the substitution and it works perfectly! It only seems to have problems when both letters and numerical factors appear together, but this is not an issue, as I can easily eliminate the numerical factors.
Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 4):

```
dd = DeleteDuplicates[#, SameQ[Abs[#1], Abs[#2]] &] &

Transpose@dd@Transpose@dd@
    {{x1, w2, -x1, -w1, -w2, w1}, 
     {z2, x2, -z2, z1, -x2, -z1}, 
     {-x1, -w2, x1, w1, w2, -w1}, 
     {-y2, y1, y2,  x3, -y1, -x3}, 
     {z2, x2, -z2, z1, -x2, -z1}, 
     {y2, -y1, -y2, -x3, y1, x3}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]