# GatherBy/SplitBy and Sort a list

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, partitions

So let's say I want to group a list of points based on their distance from the origin. I would do something like:

```
list = {{1, 20}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}};
gathered = GatherBy[list, Norm[#]&]
```

and that would give me what I need, but that would not necessarily respect the ordering. I can apply `SortBy[]` first and then `GatherBy[]` the result:

```
sorted = SortBy[list, Norm[#] &]
partitionedBy = GatherBy[sorted, Norm[#] &]
```

But that is not very efficient. Is there any more efficient way of doing this using *Mathematica*'s built-in functions. If not, What would be the most efficient way of achieving this?

update: if list is set to be a reduced accuracy version of an exact numerical expression, some of the methods suggested below will yield incorrect results. That is investigated in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106345/role-of-accuracy-in-numerical-evaluations-splitby-vs-gatherby).

Comment: What would be your expected output for your example?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "efficient"? You want the fewest operations? Fastest code? Shortest code?

Comment: @march The result given by Gatherby[Sortedby[ ]].

Comment: It can be written more succinctly as `GatherBy[SortBy[list, Norm], Norm]`

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Yeah I guess I should have made that more clear. I meant fastest code.

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes that would do it, but this way I am making Mathematica evaulate the sorting function twice. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: `SplitBy[SortBy[list, Norm], Norm]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Could you explain the difference please?

Comment: Regarding the update, you have a misplaced bracket. `N[Norm[#] &]` should be `N[Norm[#]] &`

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks. that was a typo. It still doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Well `GatherBy[SortBy[list2, N[Norm[#]] &], Norm]` gives the correct answer unlike the typo version.

Comment: For the first one you need to take into account that `GatherBy` returns *lists* of points, so you need to apply `Norm` to the first element not the whole list, e.g. `SortBy[GatherBy[list2, Norm], N[Norm[#[[1]]]] &]`

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks. Both your new suggestions return the same answer for me, but that answer is not: {{{0.*10^-2, 0.*10^-2}}, {{0.6, 0.*10^-2}, {-0.5, -0.4}, {-0.5, 
   0.4}, {0.2, -0.6}, {0.2, 0.6}}, {{-1.6, 
   0.*10^-2}, {1.3, -1.}, {1.3, 1.}, {-0.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, -1.5}}} which is what I am expecting.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's what you expect. For example {-0.5, 0.4} and {0.2, -0.6} have different norms, so why are you expecting them in the same sublist?

Comment: Oops. While testing, I accidentally altered the list2 values. So the values that I have typed in the question need updating. It should be: {{0.*10^-2, 0.*10^-2}, {1.3, 1.}, {0.2, 
  0.6}, {0.2, -0.6}, {1.3, -1.}, {-0.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, 0.4}, {0.6, 
  0.*10^-2}, {-1.6, 0.*10^-2}, {-0.5, -0.4}, {-0.5, -1.5}} which should have 0, 0.6 and 1.6 as their norms.

Comment: No, the norms are `{0., 1.64012, 0.632456, 0.632456, 1.64012, 1.58114, 0.640312, 0.6, 1.6, 0.640312, 1.58114}`

Comment: I am using: Map[Norm, lis2] and it returns {0, 1.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.6, 1.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.6, 0.6, 1.6} for me. what expression are you using?

Comment: Check those results with a calculator, they are wrong!

Comment: Ha I apologise. These were the results of a solve routine which was outputting SetAccuracy[N[sln],2] as the return expression and I was expecting the results to be on three circles hence confusion. So, Obviously it seems that using N[] in the solutions are somehow problematic. Can you tell me why?

Comment: The issue of how `N` affects `Accuracy` is a quite different problem to the original question regarding efficient sort & gather algorithms. It should be a separate question. People took time and trouble to answer the original question, and it's rather unfair to claim that their (perfectly good) answers don't work because of special features in your data that you didn't reveal until several hours later. It will also be more useful to future visitors looking for efficient sort & gather algorithms if the question is unencumbered by the requirement to avoid using `N`.

Comment: IMO the best thing would be to remove both updates from the question, and accept an answer which best addresses the problem *as originally asked*. Then create a new question about why two low-accuracy numbers can give True for `a==b` but False for `N[a]==N[b]`.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks. I agree. I did as you suggested. Here is the question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106345/role-of-accuracy-in-numerical-evaluations-splitby-vs-gatherby

Comment: Somewhat related: [(21458)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21458/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted by @SimonWoods in the comments, using `#.#&` instead of `Norm` gives a huge speed up.

```
ClearAll[f1, f1b, f2, f2b, f3, f3b, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8]
f1 = GatherBy[SortBy[#, N@Norm@# &], N@Norm@# &] &;
f2 = SplitBy[SortBy[#, N@Norm@# &], N@Norm@# &] &;
f3 = SortBy[GatherBy[#, N[Norm@#] &], N[Norm[#[[1]]]] &] &;
f1b = GatherBy[SortBy[#, #.# &], #.# &] &;
f2b = SplitBy[SortBy[#, #.# &], #.# &] &;
f3b = SortBy[GatherBy[#, #.# &], #[[1]].#[[1]] &] &;
f4 = With[{norms = #.# & /@ #, lst = #}, 
    lst[[#]] & /@ SplitBy[Ordering[norms], norms[[#]] &]] &;
f5 = With[{norms = #.# & /@ #, lst = #}, 
    lst[[#]] & /@ GatherBy[Ordering[norms], norms[[#]] &]] &;
f6 = With[{gathered = GatherBy[#, #.# &]}, 
    gathered[[Ordering[#.# & /@ (First /@ gathered)]]]] &;
f7 = With[{gathered = GatherBy[#, #.# &]}, 
    With[{norms = #.# & /@ (First /@ gathered)}, 
     gathered[[Ordering[norms]]]]] &;

list0 = RandomInteger[{0, 20}, {100000, 2}];
timings = 
  First[AbsoluteTiming[# = #2@list0;]] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{{l1, l1b, l2, l2b, l3, l3b, l4, l5, l6, l7}, {f1, f1b, 
      f2, f2b, f3, f3b, f4, f5, f6, f7}}];
functions = {"f1", "f1b", "f2", "f2b", "f3", "f3b", "f4", "f5", "f6", 
   "f7"};
TableForm[Transpose[{functions, timings}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"functions", "timings"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Equal @@ ((Norm /@ (First /@ #) & /@ {l1, l1b, l2, l2b, l3, l3b, l4, l5, l6, l7}))
(* True *)
```

Additional timings:

```
list0 = RandomInteger[{0, 500}, {100000, 2}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
list0 = RandomInteger[{0, 20}, {100000, 5}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. FYI, I just tested these with {{0.*10^-2, 0.*10^-2}, {1.3, 1.}, {0.2, 
  0.6}, {0.2, -0.6}, {1.3, -1.}, {-0.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, 0.4}, {0.6, 
  0.*10^-2}, {-1.6, 0.*10^-2}, {-0.5, -0.4}, {-0.5, -1.5}}  and only f2 and f4 are giving me the results I am expecting.

Comment: The difference between using `Norm` and `#.#&` accounts for a lot of the speed differences. It would be interesting to compare the different approaches using the same norm function throughout.

Comment: f7 too returns the wrong results for the example list in the updated question.

Comment: Thank you @Simon, I updated the post with your suggestions.

Comment: @Shb, the only difference between the outputs of the 10 functions is the ordering within each group; groups are ordered correctly.

Comment: `f7` is lovely. One of those bits of code that seems obvious, once someone else has thought of it...

Comment: again, f1[intersections] == f2[intersections] == f3[intersections] == 
 f4[intersections] == f5[intersections] == f6[intersections] == 
 f7[intersections] == f1b[intersections] == f2b[intersections] == 
 f3b[intersections] returns false for me.

Comment: Feel free to check out the second update.

Comment: On my system `f3b` is as fast as `f6` and `f7` in your test.  Using instead `RandomInteger[{0, 500}, {100000, 2}]` your function `f1b` is the fastest.  (*Mathematica* 10.1.0 under Windows 7.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I added timings for a few more input structures.

Answer (score 6):

This is more than 50% faster, since it evaluates only one `Norm` for each sublist:

```
AbsoluteTiming[list3 = SortBy[GatherBy[list, Norm], N[Norm[#[[1]]]] &];]
```

Comment: I had `result = With[{n = #.# &}, list~GatherBy~n~SortBy~n@*First]` - same principle but faster if `list` is integers.

Comment: @SimonWoods Can't try it as it is, because V9 still here, but `Norm` is usually a slow thing, so I guess you're right :)

Comment: see updated question.

Comment: @Shb The only difference is the order into the sublists `list2 = {{0.*10^-2, 0.*10^-2}, {1.3, 1.}, {0.2, 
   0.6}, {0.2, -0.6}, {1.3, -1.}, {-0.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, 0.4}, {0.6, 
   0.*10^-2}, {-1.6, 0.*10^-2}, {-0.5, -0.4}, {-0.5, -1.5}}; 
Sort /@ SplitBy[SortBy[list2, Norm], Norm] == 
 Sort /@ SortBy[GatherBy[list2, Norm], N[Norm[#[[1]]] &]]`

Comment: I don;t understand why you have an additional sort in there, but no your new suggestion too returns the old wrong answer.

Comment: @SimonWoods See updated question.

Comment: @Shb It returns `{{{0., 0.}}, {{0.6, 0.}}, {{0.2, -0.6}, {0.2, 
   0.6}}, {{-0.5, -0.4}, {-0.5, 0.4}}, {{-0.5, -1.5}, {-0.5, 
   1.5}}, {{-1.6, 0.}}, {{1.3, -1.}, {1.3, 1.}}}` which is good, AFAIK

Comment: is it? I am expecting: {{{0.*10^-2, 0.*10^-2}}, {{0.6, 0.*10^-2}, {-0.5, -0.4}, {-0.5, 
   0.4}, {0.2, -0.6}, {0.2, 0.6}}, {{-1.6, 
   0.*10^-2}, {1.3, -1.}, {1.3, 1.}, {-0.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, -1.5}}} which is what I am getting with that new solution.

Comment: @Shb That's a completely different problem related with the way Mathematica evaluates and formats the output. Not related with your current question as it is (and there are a sleuth of questions about that ind of things in this site)

Comment: Yes I understand, but it is a related question. I described my problem and received a few possible solutions. I am highlighting the fact that some of these solutions don't work and I would like to know why. But yes, it can get its own question if it ends up not being so obvious.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 20}, {10000, 2}];

AbsoluteTiming[list2 = GatherBy[SortBy[list, N[Norm[#]] &], Norm];]

(*  {0.149292, Null}  *)
```

[SplitBy](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html) will partition without additional sorting; however, it is nonetheless slower.

```
AbsoluteTiming[list3 = SplitBy[SortBy[list, N[Norm[#]] &], Norm];]

(*  {0.212032, Null}  *)
```

Verifiying that the two results are identical

```
list2 === list3

(*  True  *)
```

`Sort` and `SortBy` sort by canonical order. This is only equivalent to numeric order for numbers rather than numeric expressions.  See `Possible Issues` under [Sort](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html): "Numeric expressions are sorted by structure as well as numerical value"

EDIT: To address the revised question

```
list4 = {{0.*10^-2, 0.*10^-2}, {1.3, 1.}, {0.2, 
    0.6}, {0.2, -0.6}, {1.3, -1.}, {-0.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, 0.4}, {0.6, 
    0.*10^-2}, {-1.6, 0.*10^-2}, {-0.5, -0.4}, {-0.5, -1.5}};

ans1 = GatherBy[SortBy[list4, N[Norm[#] &]], Norm];
```

Since you are using machine numbers in this case, use of `N` is not required

```
ans2 = GatherBy[SortBy[list4, Norm], Norm];

ans3 = SplitBy[SortBy[list4, N[Norm[#]] &], Norm];
```

Again, since you are using machine numbers, use of `N` is not required

```
ans4 = SplitBy[SortBy[list4, N[Norm[#]] &], Norm];
```

These are all identical

```
ans1 === ans2 === ans3 === ans4

(*  True  *)
```

These are in the correct numeric order

```
OrderedQ[Norm[#[[1]]] & /@ ans1]

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: I just noticed that GatherBy[SortBy[list, Norm], Norm] does not give the answer I was expecting. 
it gives me: {{{1, 7}}, {{1, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{1, 6}}, {{1, 20}}}
I was expecting {{1,3},{3,1}} to come first. Also there is extra parenthesis.

Comment: I initially had: SortBy[GatherBy[list, Norm], Norm] but I realized that while it was giving me the right answer, it was only working because Norm[list]==Norm[{list}] which doesn't necessarily hold for a given function.

Comment: hmmm why is SortBy[list, Norm] giving me: {{1, 7}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 6}, {1, 20}}

Comment: SortBy[list, N[Norm[#]] &] works though.

Comment: I suggest using `#.#&` in place of `N@*Norm` for integers - it omits the square root step but that doesn't change the ordering.

Comment: see updated question.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Mathematica 10.0.0.0 and I have ans1==ans2 but not equal to (ans3==ans4)

Comment: btw, there was a typo in the list I was doing my tests with. It is corrected now, but my statement about ans1,ans2, ans3, ans4 remains valid. They are not equal on my machine.

Comment: Feel free to check out the second update.

Comment: I am finished chasing a moving target.

Comment: @BobHanlon knowledge is a moving target! :) I have edited the question text to make it more readable and reproducible. Basically some of the provided solutions give the incorrect answer for a given input list. I would like to know why. Would be great if you could have another look.