# Role of Accuracy in numerical evaluations, SplitBy vs GatherBy

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, numerical-value, gathering

This is a follow-up question to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106299/gatherby-splitby-and-sort-a-list).

I generated a list by substituting the results of a solve[] routine and set:

```
sln=expression /.Solve[...];
list= SetAccuracy[N[sln],2]]
```

You can find the FullForm[list] further down. I was trying to parition this list into sublists with equal norms.

If you evaluate `Map[Norm, list]` you get `{0, 1.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.6, 1.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.6, 0.6, 1.6}` There are three sets of values for the norms.

I tried

```
GatherBy[SortBy[list, Norm], Norm]
```

and

```
SplitBy[SortBy[list, Norm], Norm]
```

**And they give me different results**. However, if my list2 was a list of numbers inputted by hands without any explicit accuracy, the two expressions yield equal results.

- What is different about `SplitBy[]` and `Gatherby[]` that causes this?
- How do **accuracy** and **precision** interplay in numerical results?

For reproduciblity purposes, I am quoting `FullForm` version of `list` variable that I performed the tests with:

```
FullForm[list]=     \!\(
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"0``2.", ",", "0``2."}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"0.5`1.6989700043360187", ",", 
        "0.86602540378443859658830206171842291951`1.93753063169585"}],
        "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"0.5`1.6989700043360187", ",", 
RowBox[{"-", 
         "0.86602540378443859658830206171842291951`1.93753063169585"}]\
}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1.`2."}], ",", "0``2."}], "]"}]}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\)
```

and

```
GatherBy[SortBy[a, Norm], Norm] == SplitBy[SortBy[a, Norm], Norm]
```

returns False.

Comment: A simpler formulation of the same fundamental question: Given `list = SetAccuracy[{1, 1, 1.01, 1.01, 1.02, 1.02}, 2]` why does `Gather[list]` give a different result from `Split[list]`

Comment: A related question of mine from Stack Overflow, with a valuable answer from WReach: [Instability in DeleteDuplicates and Tally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6166895/618728)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In the words of WReach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6166895/618728): **SameQ Is *Not* An Equivalence Relation**

I shall take Simon Woods's concise example as a starting point:

```
list = SetAccuracy[{1, 1, 1.01, 1.01, 1.02, 1.02}, 2];

Gather[list]
Split[list]

{{1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}}

{{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}}
```

`Split` compares elements that are side-by-side, and in that measure they are all [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) true:

```
SameQ @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True}
> ```

However this *does not* mean that the first and last elements are `SameQ` true!

```
SameQ @@ list[[{1, -1}]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

`SameQ` is not a complete explanation for this behavior because it is possible to set an `` Internal`$SameQTolerance `` that sees the first and last elements as identical, yet have `Gather` return three lists:

```
Internal`$SameQTolerance = 3;

SameQ @@ list[[{1, -1}]]

Gather[list]
```

> ```
> True
>
> {{1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}}
> ```

With a sufficiently high value a single list is returned, so this is having an effect on `Gather`:

```
Internal`$SameQTolerance = 15;

Gather[list]
```

> ```
> {{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = SetAccuracy[{1, 1, 1.01, 1.01, 1.02, 1.02}, 2] // Partition[#, 2] &

(*  {{1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}}  *)
```

To get what appears to be his desired behaviour, I think the OP should be using [Round](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html)

```
GatherBy[SortBy[list, Norm], Norm[Round[#, .1]] &]

(*  {{{1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}}}  *)

SplitBy[SortBy[list, Norm], Norm]

(*  {{{1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}}}  *)

% === %%

True
```