# Reproducing a ranking function that behaves like Excel's RANK

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I tried to find a function or expression in *Mathematica* that produces the same output as the `RANK` function in Excel (see [its description](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANK-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723) here), but unfortunately I could not find an existing one.

For example consider the following list:

```
{29400., 28200., 22300., 20900., 20300., 19800., 17400., 16600., 16300., 16100., 15500., 15300., 15300., 15200., 15100., 14900.,14700., 14700., 14400., 13900.}
```

The `RANK` function in Excel will produce:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20}
                                     (* *)               (* *)
```

Notice that **ties are given the same rank** and an appropriate number of ranks is skipped after that. I would like to reproduce that behavior.

In *Mathematica*, I used the following expression :

```
m = q /. Thread[# -> Ordering[#, All, Greater]] & @ Union@q
```

However, the output is different:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 20}
```

Any suggestions on how to implement the desired behavior?

Comment: I have to go now but after first look it seems that you are reimplementing `ArrayComponents`.

Comment: @Kuba, what OP wants is **almost** the same as `ArrayComponents`, but subtly different

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
arr = {29400., 28200., 22300., 20900., 20300., 19800., 17400., 16600.,
 16300., 16100., 15500., 15300., 15300., 15200., 15100., 14900., 
 14700., 14700., 14400., 13900.}
```

From [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANK-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723)

> RANK gives duplicate numbers the same rank. However, the presence of duplicate numbers affects the ranks of subsequent numbers. For example, in a list of integers sorted in ascending order, if the number 10 appears twice and has a rank of 5, then 11 would have a rank of 7 (no number would have a rank of 6).

```
# /. Thread[Reverse@Sort@# -> Range[Length@#] ] &@arr
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20}

Comment: This is nice and simple, you should get the [cake](http://images.psxextreme.com/wallpapers/psp/the_cake_is_a_lie_515.jpg)

Comment: Great use of `ReplaceAll`'s first rule behaviour. Was totally out of the box for me.

Answer (score 7):

It feels clunky, but this gets you there,

```
q /. (Thread[# -> 
      First@First@Position[Reverse@Sort@q, #]] & /@ q)
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
f[1, _] = 1;
f[n_, l1_] := If[l1[[n]] == l1[[n - 1]], f[n - 1, l1], n]
f[#, Sort[-l]] & /@ Range@Length@l

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20}*)
```

Comment: Apparently OP wants ties to have the same rank.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I've  misread. Posted a different approach now.

Answer (score 5):

```
dat = {29400., 28200., 22300., 20900., 20300., 19800., 17400., 16600., 16300., 
   16100., 15500., 15300., 15300., 15200., 15100., 14900., 14700., 14700., 14400., 
   13900.};
```

Similar to other answers already posted:

```
dat /. First /@ PositionIndex @ Reverse @ Sort @ dat
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20}
> ```

However for best performance consider using `cleanPosIdx` from [Why is the new PositionIndex horribly slow?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54853/why-is-the-new-positionindex-horribly-slow/55967#55967)

Also this question is closely related to [Ordering function with recognition of duplicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21458/121).  Using `myOrdering` as a foundation:

```
Min[#] 1^# & /@ myOrdering[dat] // Reverse // Catenate
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
xlRanks = 1 + Length @ # - Ceiling @ Statistics`Library`GetDataRankings @ # &;
```

***Examples:***

```
list1 = {29400., 28200., 22300., 20900., 20300., 19800., 17400., 16600., 
 16300., 16100., 15500., 15300., 15300., 15200., 15100., 14900., 
 14700., 14700., 14400., 13900.};

xlRanks @ list1
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20}
> ```

```
list2 = {3, 100, 3, 100, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1};

xlRanks @ list2
```

> ```
> {9, 1, 9, 1, 3, 4, 9, 4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 13, 14}
> ```

```
xlRanks @ ReverseSort @ list2
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 13, 14}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
list =
  {29400., 28200., 22300., 20900., 20300., 19800., 17400., 16600., 
   16300., 16100., 15500., 15300., 15300., 15200., 15100., 14900., 
   14700., 14700., 14400., 13900.};

Flatten @ ReplaceAll[{a_, _} :> {a, a}] @ Values @ PositionIndex[list]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20}

**Update**
following kglr's comment

If there are more than 2 duplicates:

```
list = 
 {30000, 30000, 30000, 29400., 28200., 22300., 20900., 20300., 
  19800., 17400., 16600., 16300., 16100., 15500., 15300., 15300., 
  15200., 15100., 14900., 14700., 14700., 14400., 13900.};
```

we can do:

```
Flatten @ ReplaceAll[p : {a_?NumberQ, __} :> Table[a, Length @ p]] @
  Values @ PositionIndex[list]
```

{1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 20, 22, 23}

Comment: Is this doing the right thing when the list isn't sorted? I had thought this might be what is wanted: `Flatten@Map[ReplaceAll[#, (_Integer :> Min[#])] &,  PositionLargest[list, Length[list]]]`

Comment: Good point, but I think that your question concerns all answers given and can easily be solved by sorting the initial list.

Comment: You need something like `ReplaceAll[p : {a_Integer, __} :> Table[a, Length@p]]` for inputs with elements repeated more than twice.

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated the answer correspondingly

Comment: @eldo (1) Correct-- I was not intending to pick on your method specifically. I commented under it because, in my view, `PositionLargest` is closer to `PositionIndex` than to methods that use other functions. (2) Use of `Sort` repositions elements in a way that, unless (again) I misunderstand the question, will destroy the result. One would need to apply the reverse of the original ordering to the result for the sorted list.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {29400., 28200., 22300., 20900., 20300., 19800., 17400., 
   16600., 16300., 16100., 15500., 15300., 15300., 15200., 15100., 
   14900., 14700., 14700., 14400., 13900.};
```

---

**EDIT**

**Using `FirstPosition`:**

```
First@FirstPosition[list, #] & /@ list
```

---

**Using `PositionIndex`:**

```
v = Values@PositionIndex[list];
Sequence @@ Table[First@#1, Length@#1] & /@ v
```

---

*Result*

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 19, 
> 20}