# Give a element rank list of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

```
SeedRandom[417]
list1 = RandomChoice[Range[22, 28], 4]
```

> {22, 24, 26, 23}

We can get the rank list

```
Position[Sort[list1], #] & /@ list1 // Flatten
```

> {1, 3, 4, 2}

But when the list have a duplicated element,this method doesn't work,Such as

```
SeedRandom[416]
list2=RandomChoice[Range[22,28],4]
```

> {28, 24, 25, 24}

A list `{3,1,2,1}` be expected,Any advice can be gived?

Comment: `Ordering@Ordering[list]`?

Comment: @Xavier Wonderful solution for `list1`.But `list2`?

Comment: Something like that: `position[list_List] := Module[{n = 1, f}, f[x_] := f[x] = n++; f /@ Sort[list]; f /@ list]`?

Comment: @Xavier As you prompt,We can do it like this.`Position[Union[list2],#]&/@list2//Flatten`

Comment: Nice way too. In case performance matters, you might prefer `position` for large lists.

Comment: Sure, I'll post it. You could add a performance request in your question along with the `performance-tuning` tag if you are indeed interested in this aspect. If you do so, please do not accept my answer right away, others may come with faster solutions.

Comment: @TomD Wow,Thanks for your link.:)

Comment: @yoda. Why do you not expect {4,1,3,1} for the rank list of list2? This may be obtained by # /. Thread[# -> Ordering@Ordering@#] &@list2, which also gives the expected answer for list1 (A variant on [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108320/106) answer).

Comment: `# /. Thread[(# -> Ordering@Ordering@#) & @ DeleteDuplicates@#] & /@ {list1, list2}` gives {{1, 3, 4, 2}, {3, 1, 2, 1}}

Comment: @TomD So concise.I think you'd better post that as an answer.:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your lists are positive integers as in OP, this should be quite fast, particularly if duplication is high. Fiddle with using `Union` vs `Sort@DeleteDuplicates` - each will have an advantage depending on data.

```
Normal[SparseArray[
   With[{us = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@#}, us -> Range@Length@us]][[#]]]&@yourlist
```

For any kind of data, this s/b quick also:

```
Replace[#, PositionIndex[Sort@DeleteDuplicates@#][[All, 1]], 1] &@yourlist
```

or probably a bit quicker yet for general data:

```
Replace[#, 
   With[{s = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@#}, 
    AssociationThread[s, Range@Length@s]], 1] &@yourlist
```

Answer (score 10):

A possible approach:

```
position[list_List] := Module[{n = 1, f}, 
   f[x_] := f[x] = n++; 
   f /@ Union[list]; 
   f /@ list
];
```

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[417];
list1 = RandomChoice[Range[22, 28], 4];

position[list1]
(* {1, 3, 4, 2} *)

SeedRandom[416];
list2 = RandomChoice[Range[22, 28], 4];

position[list2]
(* {3, 1, 2, 1} *)
```

A few timings:

```
SeedRandom[416];
list3 = RandomChoice[Range[22, 28], 10^6];

position[list3]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.672818, Null} *)

SeedRandom[417];
list4 = RandomChoice[Range[10^5], 10^5];

position[list4]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.379642, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 10):

A replacement-`Rule`-based approach:

```
rankList[lst_List] := lst /. Dispatch[Thread[# -> Range@Length@#] &@ Union@lst]
```

It's a *little* bit of speed-up over Xavier's [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112607/29734) (`position`):

```
SeedRandom[416];
list3 = RandomChoice[Range[22, 28], 10^6];
rankList[list3]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
position[list3]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
rankList[list3] === position[list3]
(* 0.287793 *)
(* 0.584785 *)
(* True *)

SeedRandom[417];
list4 = RandomChoice[Range[10^5], 10^5];
rankList[list4]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
position[list4]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
rankList[list4] === position[list4]
(* 0.108716 *)
(* 0.281810 *)
(* True *)
```

---

Note: `Dispatch` is absolutely crucial here. Without it, the second example runs for a *long* time. Alternatively, use `Association`s (suggested by Xavier in a comment), which serve the same purpose:

```
rankList1[lst_List] := lst /. (AssociationThread[# -> Range@Length@#] &@Union@lst)
```

Comment: A slightly faster solution: `rankList1[lst_List] := lst /. (AssociationThread[# -> Range@Length@#] &@Union@lst)`.

Comment: @Xavier. Of course! Somehow, this didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this simplification helps:

```
ordinalScale[list_] := AssociationThread[Sort@list, Range@Length@list] /@ list
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mathematica S.E. Please edit your answer, select the code you shared and using the options that you have on top set it in a code environment. Alternatively, you can select the code and then do `Command` and `K`