# Max element of a list with a custom ordering function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, sorting

I need a function to find max element of a list according to some custom ordering function, assuming that the function implements a total order (elements being compared might not even be numbers). Unlike [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html), the predefined [`Max`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html) function does not accept a custom ordering function. A naïve solution would be to use `Sort[list, p]〚1〛`, but this would unnecessarily sort the whole list, while I only need to find the first element.

I ended up defining

```
max[list_, p_] := list[[Ordering[list, 1, p][[1]] ]];
```

and it works fine from performance point of view. But I wonder if there is a more simple or natural way to do this task. Is there a predefined function solving this problem that I missed?

Comment: [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) is intended to do this. It is new in version 10.

Comment: @Pickett Indeed, but it may not be applicable.  See my just-posted answer.

Comment: `MaximalBy` requires a mapping from elements of the list to some expressions that can be compared canonically. It's not always easy to construct such a mapping if I only have a function that can compare 2 elements.

Comment: Somewhat related: [(19300)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19300/121)

Comment: By the way `list ~Extract~ Ordering[list, 1, p]` is a bit cleaner than your present formulation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your operation can be converted to a canonical ranking rather than a pairwise comparison then you can use [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) introduced in version 10.

If not a good approach to a single pass through a list is `Fold`.  Here is a function using that:

```
foldMax[list_, p_] := Fold[If[p[##], ##] &, list]
```

This proves to be faster in some cases than using `Ordering` (in your function):

```
x = RandomReal[9, 5000000];

max[x, Less]     // AbsoluteTiming
foldMax[x, Less] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.209069, 4.32482*10^-6}
>
> {0.430025, 4.32482*10^-6}
> ```

Comment: Search for the max element requires 1 pass thru the list, that is $O(n)$, while sorting is $O(n\ln n)$.

Comment: @Vladimir Okay, I think I understand what you are saying.

Comment: I think the first sentence also isn't quite right: just because you have a pairwise ordering function doesn't mean that there is a significant $O(n^2)$ or $O(n\log n)$ performance penalty, as that would only be the case when you want to construct the entire total ordering of the list. In the case of a max element search, constructing the entire total ordering is not necessary, and instead the max search is $O(n)$, so there is no performance penalty. Still, I don't know of a built-in way to find the max... maybe you could make your own custom `$Max` function, if performance really was crucial?

Comment: @Dumpster Thanks.  I'll abolish that nonsense entirely now.

Comment: That's a cool use of `Fold`!(+1)

Comment: I like the ## as the second argument of If.  It took a few seconds before it dawned on me that this usage made them actually the second and third arguments of If.

Comment: `Ordering` with second argument `1` proves to be O(n) and I'm finding is consistently faster with user constructed pairwise functions.  ( i.e. the best answer is the one in your comment.. ).

Comment: @george2079 I haven't tested this but I imagine that if `Fold` is to have a chance of being faster the `p` function must be compilable, and input list must be packed or packable.  I would have stated this in the question except that I'd like to actually attempt to confirm this first.

Comment: @Sjoerd Sorry if you found `##` confusing; I use it so much it feels quite natural now.  By the way I would not write `p[##] ~If~ ## &` because that goes against my (visual) interpretation of infix as a binary function.