# stable sort for association?

Tags: core-language, associations, sorting

Should I be able to use the "list of functions" approach to getting a stable sort of an association?  In 11.1 I see,

```
assoc01 = <|10 -> 1, 8 -> 3, 9 -> 2, 7 -> 4|>;
SortBy[assoc01, Mod[#, 3] &]    (* <|8->3,7->4,10->1,9->2|> *)
SortBy[assoc01, {Mod[#, 3] &}]  (* <|10->1,9->2,8->3,7->4|> *)
```

Comment: I get the same result in 11.3

Comment: I think this is a bug that should be reported to support.

Comment: @CarlWoll OK thanks; reported.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed I think you should, and I agree with Carl Woll that this should be reported.

In the meantime here is a work-around using a variation of my `orderingBy` from [Retaining and reusing a one-to-one mapping from a sort](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19300/121#21453):

```
aSortBy[a_Association, sfuns_List] :=
  a[[ SortBy[Range @ Length @ a, Cases[sfuns, f_ :> (f@a[[#]] &)]] ]]

aSortBy[a_, sfn_] := SortBy[a, sfn]

aSortBy[fns_][a_] := aSortBy[a, fns]
```

Test:

```
assoc01 = <|10 -> 1, 8 -> 3, 9 -> 2, 7 -> 4|>;

aSortBy[assoc01, Mod[#, 3] &]

aSortBy[assoc01, {Mod[#, 3] &}]
```

> ```
> <|8 -> 3, 7 -> 4, 10 -> 1, 9 -> 2|>
>
> <|8 -> 3, 10 -> 1, 7 -> 4, 9 -> 2|>
> ```